# Ability to ignore questions from low rep users

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, reputation

I hereby retreat from this feature request. [This post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253351/allow-users-to-optionally-filter-out-low-quality-questions) handles the same idea, but it is much better.

**IMPORTANT**: This does NOT mean that all new users should be ignored by everyone or something in this line.

This site is for the experts and this suggestion is to increase the joy of them to use it.

## Suggestion

Implement a reputation threshold for each user that then filters the questions seen by the user.

A selectbox where I can choose to not see questions of users below a given reputation threshold, say 2/7/10/15/100/1000.

## Does the ignore all the new users

Only for those users who chose to ignore them, which I expect not to be the majority. So most people still see all the questions.

## Then how do new users get reputation points

By answering questions. Or by getting upvotes from other yet-low-rep users.

## Reasoning

As has been stated in some Questions here recently the amount of low-quality question that drive away experts, but flock in newbies is increasing.

For the sake of this suggestion I will categorize the userbase of the answerers into two:

1. There are users who willingly handle all questions and are fine with them often being junk, handle them and don't care.
2. Then there are people who get bored/frustrated by all this stupid "has already been asked" stuff and don't want to point out over and over again the same mistakes by beginners.

So, while the former wouldn't need the limit they do need the company of the latter because in this second group are a lot of experts that do answer with all their expertise if they want to. So, this solution would allow the first group to take care of the newcomers while the second group can stay with the difficult problems and are not annoyed by the noise.

## Personal

Personally I count myself into the first group on Stack Overflow. I don't mind the stupid questions and look for duplicates before I answer and the like. But I begin to get the subjective impression that the amount of good answers is decreasing. After having read the various questions, answers and comments here I started thinking about how to overcome this.

My personal experience in a different community (a game, where I fall into the second category) is that after we blocked out the steady income of newbies into our group, created a stable amount of regulars and only accepted a new one into our ranks once in a while the frustration went away.

The impression I got there is that while the newbies complained about not being let into the upper-ranks-groups they do form new groups that themselves then become elitist. And I think that it is just fine that way, as long as it is possible to raise from the bottom up.

Also I do note that I'm not a very regular answerer myself currently, I do my part on this by working the close vote queue when time permits.

### Side notes

This could and most likely will increase the amount of unanswered questions that linger around, unseen. A great place to gain the first reputation for new users.

This doesn't solve the problem that we should stop giving incentive to answer bad questions, but that is its own problem.

## Data

This data here: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/185130/closed-questions-by-user-rep shows that most closed ("bad") questions come from low rep users.

Comment: While I wouldn't mind Stack Overflow becoming a bit more exclusive, I don't think this would work - reputation doesn't equal expertise, and vice versa. There are people who have gained 10k rep just by asking mediocre questions and getting away with it.

Comment: I find that most questions asked by high rep users are of below average quality.  Since upvotes give so much more rep than downvotes, even users getting way more downvotes still increase in rep over time, and even there, too many people are willing to upvote marginally low quality questions.  Most of the really amazing questions I see are from very low rep users; some fairly advanced user who's asking an SO question for the first time, because up until then they've been able to solve their own problems.

Comment: @Servy Data suggests not, most of the closed questions come from users with 1 or 6 points of reputation, I'll edit the data in.

Comment: So all new users should get ignored?

Comment: @JoeW No, of course not! Did you even read the Question?

Comment: Well if this option was available what else do you expect to happen as more people decide that they only want to see questions from people with x or higher reputation?

Comment: @JoeW I expect all the teacher types of person (like me) and all the rep whores (lots and lots and lots of them) to not set that filter. Because why should they?

Comment: "IMPORTANT: This does NOT mean that all new users should be ignored or something in this line." But the title is, "Ability to Ignore Questions from low rep users". Do you realize that new users are low rep?

Comment: @djechlin Yes of course. Obviously I have worded my suggestion totally wrong or you wouldn't come to such conclusions. The intend is to enhance the overall experience by keeping the experts on site and still be able to serve the new / low rep users.

Comment: @djechlin I tried to address some thoughts that may have not come through clearly yet in the latest edit. Is it clearer now?

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer Of course most closed questions come from low rep users.  Most questions *by a very significant margin*, come from low rep users.  All questions from high rep users make up just a drop in the bucket.  Most of those high rep questions tend to be of below average quality, from my experience.  Not completely terribly awful, but fairly poor.  Low rep users also make up the majority of utter garbage, the best of the best, and everything in between.  By volume they generate much more crap, but they also generate the best content, so I'd never want to filter it all out.

Comment: @Servy Then the feature would be of no use to you, but does it make this a bad feature?

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer I'm just describing why it won't be helpful, as it in no way helps people see just the best questions.  Everyone else has contributed with all sorts of drawbacks, which I see no need to repeat.  My comments are merely explaining why your benefits are in fact false, and therefore are unable to compensate for all of those other drawbacks.

Comment: @Pekka웃, I do not know over how long they gathered the 10k rep. However, I look at it this way: it is a given that there are more noobs than experts.  Those 10k users, whether noob, mid, or expert, planted noob-mid questions for either of the following reasons: an honest question, or to seed the site with easy questions so that noobs can get comfortable with it (I will not talk about rep-farmers).  Since there are more noobs than experts, upvotes should easily accumulate for 10k rep. If a question is a genuine problem shared by many, why would it not be upvoted by many?

Comment: @Angelo - I see no difference at all between this question and the one you linked to.  What gives?  Note too that **rather than points you could just go by account age** .. simply allow both of those.  Just have two trivial filters at the top, account days age and account rep. So simple.

Comment: I recommend just throwing two filters at the top, account-age and account-rep ... http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255894/294884

Comment: TEN THOUSAND ?  Don't be absurd, the cut off would be say 20 or 50 points. The only "problem low quality questions" come from brand new users (age under 3 days) or with rep under a few dozen.

Comment: @Servy: _"I find that most questions asked by high rep users are of below average quality."_ Huh, really? At _best_ I'm hoping you concede that's tag-specific, since [tag:language-lawyer] is really excellent.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I have no problem making that concession, as I rarely visit that tag.  That said, I imagine that to be a very rare exception.

Comment: @Servy: I can't for the life of me think why high rep users would ask below average quality questions except for "very rare exceptions", and I've never seen any particular evidence of this.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, most of them don't do it very much, so they just haven't built up the appropriate skills, perhaps.  Regardless, it's what I've observed, I don't have concrete explanations to explain that observation.

Comment: Some of the worst questions I have ever encountered came from 10K+ users. There appears to be a double standard. We are all very quick to correct new users, but more established users (with bad habits) seem to be able to get away with a lot more. No one wants to call them out.

Comment: It is better to ignore by not see the newcomers instead of put energy to piss them down. Leave them alone and they help each other at least.

Comment: If a question is "low quality question" why do you not contribute?

Comment: If a "low quality question" is much visited it is useful. If you put energy on put them down it is better to filter them out and you put energy on your level and skills. Find metrics to get it work instead of look at things that doesn't work. Try improve the post, be creative. Is it because it is not a destruction tool that it is not appealing? If you not want the filter you can turn it off. How bad is that?

Comment: How about the ability to ignore HIGH REP users? There's far more of them I wish I could summarily ignore than low rep ones.

Answer (score 52):

This doesn't work. Perfectly amazing developers who are either young and promising, or seasoned but just don't hang out on Q&A sites, now must go through the service of dealing with really crappy "DEBUG MY NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION" questions before they can either receive or offer legitimate help. Who would do that? 5 years later, SO is dead.

Comment: No, this would only be true if the rep barrier would count for ALL users on SO, but it doesn't. If a new user asks a good question it gets upvoted and thus becomes more visible.

Comment: Also, SO is dying currently. In 5 years its dead if we don't act.

Comment: ... and ignoring a large part of the community is preventing that how exactly? [Also...](http://www.bubblews.com/assets/images/news/2059860511_1395402159.gif)

Comment: And giving the people this site caters most preferred the ability to enjoy their stay more does help a lot.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer we could just not allow new users for that matter? it meets your requirements.

Comment: @djechlin No, it doesn't because I like new users. My problem are not the new users, my problem is that the experts go away.

Comment: Also, this does not in any way hamper anyone from offering legitimate help This suggestion is only for questions, not answers. Which is a totally great way of gaining rep.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer SO has been dying for the past 4 years, give or take a few, depending on who you ask.  Everything always appears to be getting worse and worse, and yet it's still here.

Comment: This answer is remarkably low value, DJ.  The whole point of the proposal is it would make the site **more appealing to experts**.  (Many excellent and indeed obvious reasons given.) You're just asserting it would make it less appealing to experts.  Doesn't make much sense.

Comment: "My problem are not the new users, my problem is that the experts go away" an excellent turn of phrase!  Quite true.

Comment: Of course it would work. Some people don't click on questions with minus votes, and some don't click on questions with users with less than X rep. The only difference is that SO would allow you to filter it out.

Answer (score 18):

Personally I completely understand this will never be a thing on Stack Exchange. I think this would absolutely be a form of discrimination. If this was available in settings, it would automatically imply that low-rep users are worse kind of users. We have bad experience with this kind of stigmatization from offline life (some people prefer the term *real life*. I do not, everything that happens to you is real).

But I also think you have the right to make the choice for yourself, which is why I present the userscript below. It's up to you now:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Ignore low rep user questions
// @namespace   607407
// @include     /https?:\/\/(meta\.)?(stackoverflow|askubuntu|[a-z]+\.stackexchange)\.[a-z]{1,3}/.*?/
// @version     2015.12.18.17.54
// @author      http://stackoverflow.com/users/607407
// @grant       none
// @run-at      document-end
// ==/UserScript==

// Question will be completely hidden if the user reputation is smaller or equal to...
var HIDE_REP = 5;   // hiding using CSS class tagged-ignored-hidden
// Question will be de-emphasized if the user reputation is smaller or equal to...
var IGNORE_REP = 30;// Hiding using CSS class tagged-ignored
// Question is not penalized based on reputation if the vote score is greater or equal to...
var SHOW_VOTES = 1;
// What to do with questions tagged as interesting
//  Options:
//     "KEEP AS IS" - skip the question and take no actions on it
//     "TAG IGNORED" - never hide the question completely, just make it semi-transparent
//     "TREAT AS OTHERS" - do not check whether the question is or isn't interesting
var INTERESTING_QUESTIONS = "TAG IGNORED";

// Some pesudoclass to simplify the code

function QuestionSummary(html) {
    if(html instanceof jQuery) {
      this.$ = html;
      this.elm = html[0];
    }
    else {
      this.$ = $(html);
      this.elm = html;
    }
}
defineHtmlGetterSetter(QuestionSummary.prototype, "reputation", ".reputation-score", {get: function(x) {return x.replace("k", "000").replace(/[^0-9]/g, "")*1;}});
defineHtmlGetterSetter(QuestionSummary.prototype, "score", ".vote-count-post strong");
defineHtmlGetterSetter(QuestionSummary.prototype, "title", ".question-hyperlink");

// Get a list of questions
var questions = document.querySelectorAll(".question-summary");
console.log("Score for ",questions.length," questions.");
//console.log(questions);

// This is deferred, so it runs AFTER the official script that marks the questions
function hideLowRepQuestions(questions) {
    for(const questionDiv of questions) {
        //console.log(summary);
        var question = new QuestionSummary(questionDiv);
        //question.elm.className = "question-summary";

        var is_interesting = INTERESTING_QUESTIONS=="TREAT AS OTHERS"?false:question.elm.classList.contains("tagged-interesting");
        if( question.score>=SHOW_VOTES || ( is_interesting && INTERESTING_QUESTIONS=="KEEP AS IS" ) ) {
          console.log("Question ", question.title, " has high score (or otherwise interesting) and thus is never ignored.");
          return;
        }
        if(question.elm.classList.contains("tagged-ignored-hidden")) {
          console.log("Question ", question.title, " already hidden.");
          return;
        }

        const rep = question.reputation;
        console.log("[QUESTION_HIDER:loop]",question.score, question.title, question.reputation);

        // Second part of the condition is there to prevent accidental showing of a question

        if( rep <= HIDE_REP ) {
            if(is_interesting && INTERESTING_QUESTIONS=="TAG IGNORED") {
                if(!question.elm.classList.contains("tagged-ignored")) {
                    question.elm.classList.add("tagged-ignored");
                    console.log("Not hiding question ",question.title," because it's interesting.", question.elm);
                }
            }
            else {
                if(!question.elm.classList.contains("tagged-ignored-hidden")) {
                    question.elm.classList.add("tagged-ignored-hidden");
                    console.log("Hiding question ",question.title,".", question.elm);
                }
            }
        }
        else if( rep <= IGNORE_REP ) {
            if(!question.elm.classList.contains("tagged-ignored")) {
                question.elm.classList.add("tagged-ignored");
                console.log("Ignoring question ",question.title,".", question.elm);
            }
        }
    }
}


// Wait till official stackexchange script starts modifying the class attributes:

// Shamelessly copied from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver
// I never use this anywhere else than userscripts, so I don't remember that
// select the target node

// You might think that this will only work when
// the first question summary is affected by tag filters
// but the truth is the class attribute is allways being set, even when the value would not change
// So this code allways triggers
var target = document.querySelector('#questions');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
     if(mutation.type == "attributes") {
         if(mutation.attributeName == "class" && mutation.target.classList.contains("question-summary")) {
             hideLowRepQuestions([mutation.target]);
         }
     }
     else if(mutation.type == "childList") {
         if(mutation.target.id == "questions") {
             hideLowRepQuestions(Array.from(mutation.addedNodes).filter((node)=>{return node.classList.contains("question-summary");}))
         }
     }
     //console.log(mutation.type, mutation.attributeName);
  });
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: false, subtree: true, attributeFilter: ["class"] };
// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);

// Run at start
hideLowRepQuestions(questions);




/**
 * Creates getter and setter for innerHTML of HTML node got by selector disguised under property name.
 * this assumes `this.$` property (jQuery object of the actual HTML) and CACHES all selector results!
 * */
function defineHtmlGetterSetter(objectProto, name, selector, descriptor) {
    if(typeof descriptor=="undefined")
        descriptor = {};
    if(typeof descriptor.get!="function") {
        descriptor.get = function(x){return x;};
    }
    if(typeof descriptor.set!="function") {
        descriptor.set = function(x){return x;};
    }
    if(descriptor.nocache) {
        Object.defineProperty(objectProto, name, {
          get: function() {
            return descriptor.get(this.$.find(selector).html());
          },
          set: function(html) {
            return descriptor.set(cachedNode(this).html(html));
          },
        });
    }
    else {
        Object.defineProperty(objectProto, name, {
          get: function() {
            return descriptor.get(cachedNode(this).html());
          },
          set: function(html) {
            return descriptor.set(cachedNode(this).html(html));
          },
        });
        function cachedNode(instance) {
          return instance["_"+name+"_cached"] instanceof jQuery? instance["_"+name+"_cached"] : instance["_"+name+"_cached"]=instance.$.find(selector);
        }
    }
}
```

### Documentation

In the beginning of the script, few variables can be set to alternate script behavior:

1. **`HIDE_REP`** - reputation threshold. Questions by users with lower or equal reputation than this will be hidden
2. **`IGNORE_REP`** - reputation threshold. Questions by users with lower or equal reputation than this will be appear translucent, just as questions with ignored tags
3. **`SHOW_VOTES`** - amount of votes needed to show the question even if the users reputation is below threshold
4. **`INTERESTING_QUESTIONS`** - switches what shall be done with questions tagged by favourite tags. This has three options:

   - `KEEP AS IS` - will not do anything to these questions, regardless of user's reputation
   - `TAG IGNORED` - shall the question be hidden, it will be made translucent instead, not hidden completely
   - `TREAT AS OTHERS` - with this switch, interesting questions will not be treated specially

Comment: Can you add some short description or maybe a link for how to actually install the script? What is the scope (does it only work in certain browsers, on mobile/desktop, etc.)? On what platform did you test it on (OS, browser + version, etc.)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen At this point in time, userscripts are so widely used that I forgot to include explanation. To instal an userscript, you need GreaseMonkey (Firefox) or Tampermonkey (Google Chrome) plugin. Those plugins have compatible way of handling userscripts.

Comment: @TomášZato just made SO usable again for answering questions!

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica please update your script; I already gave up looking at questions in PHP, now other areas get infested, too. Maybe add an empty array for users to be ignored by name/ID (i.e. for someone having a 4000+ rep but still asking ridiculous questions).

Answer (score 2):

6 years later. This post makes more sense I believe.
We've now gotten the tools to create custom filters *(that aren't default)*.

I have three modes when I'm on stack overflow.

1. Lets just help some people today
2. Lets help some people with my favorite tags *(`python`, `pyglet` etc)*
3. Lets do something challenging and solve a problem that has high votes/has bounties

Currently, I can do three, but I can't do three on recent posts. I'll have to wait *(some times a day or more)* depending on my niche for people to find and up-vote a question before I can sort it with the "most votes" filter.

There's some truth to the fact that this might make people miss certain newcomers that post good questions if it's put in a default configuration. But as a custom filter on the right hand side it makes sense, as it doesn't automatically exclude peoples posts from the standard view. This will just give people some breathing room and the option to do something challenging for a bit, to not just be stuck in "bad post hell" where you feel like the only thing you do is down-vote and close meaningless questions like [how to make this structure data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61933404/how-to-make-this-structure-data) or [How do you solve this non utf-8 code error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61933334/how-do-you-solve-this-non-utf-8-code-error), which just happens to be one of many in succession.

Comment: Tough luck getting this to any relevant attention anymore. The current direction of SO is inclusive for everybody except the people it originally catered (actual experts). This here was my personal last attempt to become part of the SO community and it went slowly down from here. The ****up with Monica and the immense exodus since then have closed the coffin altogether. Whatever will be here in the future will not be the site I once joined or cared for.

Answer (score -2):

The comments about not helping legitimate new users by filtering them are not thought out.

You can allow only filtering for users with some higher reputation, say 1000.

You can also add probabilistic filtering as well, the lower the user's rep then the less likely you will see a message.

You should also add filtering by the ratio of questions asked to answers accepted.

Really, the problem is there is a 100 to 1 ratio of nonsense posts to meaningful posts. It's not just posts about questions that could be easily researched or are obvious duplicates. It's more about questions that seems like it's just a bunch of bots posting random pseudo questions and the "poster" doesn't care about the answer anyway.

Answer (score -4):

I would love this feature, but then everyone would use it and new-users would never get their questions answered.

New users have the highest tendency to ask spammy questions. They rarely understand the rules of the site, usually ask questions that are duplicates, vague, needy, etc. And of course they rarely accept answers or upvote.

Really they are the worst users, and I hate slogging to through their questions only to realize its a duplicate, is nonsense, or has no real answer from the information given.

But like others have said. If we could filter them out, SO would be dead very fast. We already have enough problems staying on good terms with newbies.

Answer (score -12):

Both my cousin who is one of the greatest software engineers in my country and who owns a startup and the software engineer who I worked for during my internship and who is one of the best software engineers on planet earth and who worked for huge banks and won many competitions worldwide. Both of them don't use SO and the reason is, they always find an answer, never needed to ask.

If they were to sign up today, the new system would treat them and would give me an advantage because I have some rep. It's unfair, rep is nothing, I am nothing compared to these guys, I don't have a right to correct their bugs, they're legends. I used to be glad of my rep and put it on my CV, but after my internship I learnt that it's nothing really.

A friend of mine who has the highest GPA in the history of CS of my uni doesn't use SO, and many more people. I don't really care if I had 1m rep, I'll always be newbie compared to them.

Answer (score -14):

This seems like an obvious and excellent idea.

"Information wants to be free."

If, upon occasion, when you are visiting SO, you happen to want to only look at questions "from users with rep over X" ....

what's the big deal?

If your view point (one possible viewpoint) is: *"oh, we shouldn't 'allow' people to do that, it's 'not right' ..."* ...  if that's your viewpoint, that's somewhat bizarre social engineering. It would be like saying for example *"oh let's not let people search on the disciplines we don't like, such as android..."*.

As they say, "Information wants to be free," i.e., social engineering is useless.

Comment: How can you support this on one hand, and [want to abolish the points system on the other](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255366/contention-should-points-be-completely-eliminated-on-so)?

Comment: Please don't operate heavy machinery like overflowed stacks while drunk ;)