# Filter questions by asker's reputation?

Tags: feature-request, reputation

Can we filter questions by the asker's reputation?

A lot of SO newbies are asking very trivial questions, or asking us to do their work for them. I'd like to weed those out to get to the more interesting questions that higher ranked users usually ask.

Comment: But newby question != not interesting question.

Comment: Never, ever, generalize.  Users with 5 digit rep also ask RTFM sort of questions.

Comment: Train your eyes to filter the unwanted stuff at a glance instead.

Comment: Pretty much the same goal as this other request: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252607/ability-to-ignore-questions-from-low-rep-users

Comment: and it was also discussed on SE before: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152353/filter-questions-by-user-reputation

Comment: I actually like your idea.

Comment: @Larme and [@]devnull Of course not. But I'm willing to bet the ratio is tilted in favour of higher rep users. And why on earth would I want to "filter with my eyes" when it could be done programmatically? We might as well use paper and pen instead of computers -- pretty much everything can be done manually, no?

Comment: Anyway, djechlin provides a pretty good [counter-argument](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252608/65387). I might be able to do it with the SO API anyway...

Comment: Actually, if we added a single filter that's like "above 100 rep" it would take a new user like a day or two to hit that rep, so we're not really disadvantaging anyone except the 1-rep users that stumble in here looking for a quick fix.

Comment: Please don't delete this stub, it has a unique title, and so will help in searching to find the canonical post.

Comment: This question should be reopened mainly due to the meaning behind the title. I am a user of 150 reputation, and my programming knowledge is not that good, so I sometime want to see only questions from users close to my rank, which gives me a chance to answer and build up my reputation - therefore I think there is a flipside to this feature - not only will it allow high ranked users to answer  "high quality" questions, but it will also allow low ranked users like me to answer "low quality" questions - so I vote for a reopen.