# Is my question on topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

I [recently asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27915877/finding-the-shortest-string-containing-keywords) which some people said my not be on topic for Stack Overflow.

The short version is that I wrote some code that was producing incorrect results under some inputs but I was unable to see what those inputs were (because my code was run remotely on a machine I didn't have access to), so couldn't easily debug it. In my question I provided -

- The problem to solve
- Example input and output
- My code (which was short)

And asked if anyone could determine what inputs this would fail under.

Some people suggested this be posted on Code Review, but its clearly [off-topic](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/my-question-was-closed-as-being-off-topic-what-are-my-options/3650#3650) there. Others suggested that Stack Overflow does not help with debugging, but I find that silly since many questions do ask for debugging help in *similar* ways. Moreover, I thought my question was clear, well structured and thought out.

But the question is, was it on topic?

Comment: [This might answer some doubts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253787/are-there-legitimate-fix-my-code-questions). You could for example show some of the inputs you have given and what you received, why you think  that it's wrong and what would be right

Comment: Your example input and output does not apply to your question, as that doesn't reproduce the issue you're describing. Ask your friend for what input this code fails, not us.

Answer (score 9):

One person voted to close your question with the reason:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

That absolutely applies to your question.  You have failed to explain what problems you have found with your code.  Without knowing what's wrong, it cannot be reasonably answered.

Others in comments have also mentioned problems that they have with the question.  If there is some specific comment that confuses you or that you don't understand, you can either reply to it so the author can expand on it, or you'll need to be more specific here as to what comment(s) you would like us to elaborate on or discuss.