# Posting A Question About A Security Exploit For Academic Purposes

Tags: discussion

I am giving a lecture on web security at a university and I am working on a demo. I am having some issues with my cross site scripting and injection demo and would like input from people who know more than I do. (Yes it is probably bad that I need help making a demo and I am supposed to be giving a lecture)

Would it be a violation of terms of service to post the code for my demo and ask or help? I am trying to do a demo that would actually be meaningful.

Comment: Outside of that code, what would your question be like?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267699/how-do-we-handle-questions-that-are-potentially-or-blatantly-illegal-or-maliciou  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3528/dealing-with-questions-of-nefarious-intent

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I have the xss code and a page written I honestly just want to know if there is a way I can make the demo work

Comment: Then stop right there. At the very least, you have to take the time to reduce your problem to the smallest amount of code that reproduces it. *Please make my XSS demo work* will be closed with extreme prejudice I'm afraid. Fire up your debugger and try to pinpoint the problem before posting anything.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I want to know if it is chromium preventing xss or my scripting fail

Comment: Then desist -- there is no way anyone will expose a Chrome browser to your exploit to verify it's blocked. (Yes, we have VMs, and yes, we still don't do that.)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Fair enough

Comment: If all else fails, perhaps someone over at Security.SE might be willing to lend a hand if you ask in chat. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends a lot on your actual question and how you write it.

Generally speaking, asking for general help, such as "can you help me write this" is not going to be well received.  Asking a specific question, such as "I am trying to do this and I am having a problem with `x`.  This is my code so far and this is the error/issue/problem that I am getting", will be much better.

Now with the specific subject matter, that is another possible issue.  Based on similar questions in the past ([How do we handle questions that are potentially or blatantly illegal or malicious?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267699/how-do-we-handle-questions-that-are-potentially-or-blatantly-illegal-or-maliciou)), there is nothing specifically against the terms of service to ask such questions.  But I have seen otherwise good questions that seem to have a malicious intent get downvoted just because of the nature of the question.  There's not much you can do to ward off those users who will downvote those types of questions, so if you ask, you have to be prepared to receive some downvotes.

Comment: I have the code so far I am just trying to figure out what the issue is

Comment: @inquisitiveIdiot take a look at [Are there legitimate “fix my code” questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253787/are-there-legitimate-fix-my-code-questions/253788#253788).  If you think you can hit all of the points, then you have the makings of a good debug question.  If not, then you are basically asking someone to help find the bug in your code and those do not usually fare well.

Comment: It is more of a question of a conceptual issue with how xss works and it chromium is preventing my actions or if it is bad scripting

Comment: It's strange, but almost every SO question about security/exploits is 'for academic purposes'.  I always believe everything I see on the internet, so I never automatically down/close vote such questions, (yes, I can lie too:).