# Are questions about bugs on topic (when no code is presented)?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

[Atom Editor - Can´t write the ':' character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35864477/3935089)

This question asks about an Atom package (autoclose-html). It asks about a bug in the package and how to resolve it.

The user looks to have filed an [Issue](https://github.com/mattberkowitz/autoclose-html/issues/138) on the repo.

I don't think that this is a *bad* question, but I don't think it is a good one either.

Is it on topic? Should it be closed as too broad?

**EDIT**

I judged it to be not a good question based on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

- *Search, and research* - User has determined which package is causing the problem
- *Write a title that summarizes the specific problem* - more or less, could mention the package
- *Introduce the problem before you post any code* - done
- *Help others reproduce the problem* - not done
- *Include all relevant tags* - done
- *Proof-read before posting!* - not an issue
- *Post the question and respond to feedback* - not an issue

I suppose I am asking if this is some type of fix my code question.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/3935089

Comment: Why would questions about bugs *not* be on topic? *"It asks about a bug in the package and how to resolve it."* Yeah, that's totally cool, assuming that "the package" would otherwise be on-topic here. I'm not really understanding why you're wanting to close questions like this.

Comment: Why do you think there is no indication how to reproduce the problem? "I cannot write the : character" seems pretty reproducable to me. What kind of "code" would you expect to be presented?

Comment: A few repro hints would not hurt this question.  Just post a comment to tell the user that he should include the package version number and describe his machine (OS, language).

Comment: Looking at the linked question, it doesn't sound like an issue that _needs_ code. It sounds like the plugin is simply overriding key inputs, and they're looking for a way to fix that.

Comment: Asked op for more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Can* you ask questions about application bugs?

Yes. As long as it's about ["software tools commonly used by programmers"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

*Should* you ask questions about application bugs?

Probably not.

Typically you'll be better off opening an issue simply because that will usually get a *faster and better* response than what you'll get on Stack Overflow.

It's not always clear what's a "bug" or what's a "problem" from the outset, though, and even if it is a bug, it may still be useful to post it on SO. Especially on the Vi and Vim site I've often seen work-arounds and even fixes being created for bugs (Vim is not known for a quick patch cycle).

Note that if you know about a bug report relating to a question you should edit that in or put it in the comments. The author may not bother coming back to tell us that it's been fixed (or may simply not keep track of the bug report) and someone may waste time trying to find a solution for a problem that's already solved.

Comment: Opening an issue will get a faster and better response for getting the bug *fixed*, but if you're just looking for a workaround, I think Stack Overflow can be just a effective, if not more so. Doing both is the best approach, linking to the official bug tracker in an answer.

Comment: @CodyGray It would depend on the issue; e.g. working around a problem or bug in Vim or Atom could get you good answers, but a "My foo segfaults when I do bar" probably not so much...

Comment: Well, I guess you are operating from an open-source, community-driven-development sort of mindset. True enough for Vim and GCC, but not so true for, *e.g.*, Visual Studio. If there's a bug in that product, I can and should report it to Microsoft and even link to the public bug tracker page, but I'm not likely to get a fix delivered until the next product release, so in the meantime I'm screwed. I need to find a way to work around the bug. That's when you turn to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @CodyGray Yeah, that sounds reasonable enough.