# How to disambiguate a question between a “fix my code” and “I politely believe the tools I am using have a bug” and what to do with it?

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes, I face the embarrassing moment when I miss a boundary, forget to initialize or something, spend quite a few hours debugging and start to blame some tool API or compiler because somehow my brain believes code is correct. I believe this may happen to others. In this configuration, I usually call a friend or colleague sufficiently proficient to help me solve my issue. Luckily, I am surrounded by talented people, which might not be the case for everyone.

I believe that sometimes the boundary between “fix my code” and “I am really stuck, I believe the Tools I am using have a bug” is a matter of appreciation.

On the other hand, the first step in reporting a bug in a tool is to illustrate an example where behavior is not as expected. The humble user of the software would then ask why his code does not behave as expected, and sometimes (maybe not that often), answer is: there is a bug in the tool, it is reported here, with a link. Is this Q&A data not valuable for stack overflow ?

So my question really is **what to do with these kinds of questions?** I understand the first kind, where the “fix my code” trait of the question is so obvious that it should get removed, since considered as noise. But doing that too harshly leads to exclusion of the second kind. Also, **what to do with the answers from people trying to help, spotting the issue in the code?**

Some answers get commented with: *this is not a good answer, and by the way, you are answering a “fix my code” question which does not help the stack overflow community and generates noise around real valuable answers.* This is a fair point. But then, what is the use of community wiki? **Does it mean Q&A pairs which don’t have enough value should be removed from Stack Overflow?** Does it mean that newcomers need to learn all of this the hard way?

**Idea of feature** Maybe it could be useful to add a flag or trait to the question making clear that the question needs to *disambiguate between fix my code and I believe tool has a bug*, and the answer could not be considered the same way as some other more valuable answers should it be the first case. Hence, some very demanding moderators would simply ignore the question, where the user asking may be interested.

Finally, there might be alternate place for such questions, do you know any?

**EDIT**: Adding another post that very well relates to the question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/6218300

Thanks to commenters for pointing out the duplicate.

Comment: There is a massive difference between _“fix my code”_ and _“I believe the Tools I am using have a bug”_ The latter one is a bug report, which is off-topic by definition. The first one can be on-topic, provided the OP shows he put some effort into trying to solve it, first. That said, is there anything in here that can't be answered by reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: TLDR: What exactly are you asking here? Is this a feature request ___or___ a discussion?

Comment: I try to understand the practices of StackOverflow in handling such questions. I flagged discussion as I believe opinions might differ. I also flagged feature-requet as I tried to propose a feature to help avoid such confusions.

Comment: The problem is that it's unclear what kind of feature you're suggesting, or _what_ the confusion even is. The feature request and discussion tags are mutually exclusive. A feature request can still be discussed without the discussion tag.

Comment: @gnat Thanks for the link. Following a few, I believe the best fitting answer is actually http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/6218300 . I will accept the duplicate though.

Answer (score 2):

People ask for an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because how can you possibly determine if something is a problem with someone's code or if it is a problem with a library/resource without a way to reproduce it?

The majority of the time it is always your own code that's the problem and, with myself at least, it's very off-putting to see a question blame the tool.

Simply just ask about the problem with your own code and if it turns out to be a problem with the tool, then that is a valid answer.

---

What should we do about it? Nothing, the system works. Carry on judging posts on their own merits.

Comment: My goodness MCVE's can be a lot of work to make. When submitting pull requests to large projects the MCVE can take longer than debugging itself! I definitely agree that you should consider it quite unlikely that your tools are broken, but would note that people who ask questions on stack overflow have likely spend a few hours trying to debug. Asking a question on stack overflow can be a great way to quickly learn about edge cases / "bugs as features" that might take you a long time to debug.