# I don't understand anything on this site

Tags: discussion, support

Firstly, I was banned from posting on Stack Overflow. I asked a question that didn't have enough content in it (I think) to be considered a high-quality question. I didn't receive any warnings in my inbox or on my questions and thought I was asking okay questions until I got banned for one of them.

On this site, I thought it was for ban appeals which just seemed like they made sense, but the appeal got taken down. I decided to look around and found out that it was like the normal Stack Overflow, but seemingly for those that were banned. I saw a few questions and they were all about Python scripting, so I assumed I could ask the same questions here as in the normal Stack Overflow, but my question got taken down *again*. The moderator that took down the question also assumed I was trying to get around a ban even though I wasn't, which just came across as rude.

Do you see where I'm going with this? This site is confusing and unforgiving. Humans make mistakes and deserve to have multiple chances instead of being outright banned without warning. At least two chances would be ideal, with the first offense being shown clearly when the user logs in, and outlining everything they did wrong and how they can improve later on.

This meta version of the normal site should also have some kind of popup or something indicating exactly what to do, because I'm still not entirely sure what it is about. I've seen people say it is about Stack Overflow, but what do they mean by that? Is it just for questions on how to use the site? It seems simple enough to me to not require an entirely new version of Stack Overflow for this.

Comment: When you draft your question on Meta, on the right it says, "Is your question about the Stack Overflow community or website?" There is also help available if you click the "?" icon in the top bar.

Comment: More specifically, in mentioned help there is a question straight in popup "What's Meta?", and if you'd read it instead of assuming what it is and what it is not, you'd not have problems with "rude" moderators.

Comment: Also, re: "I saw a few questions and they were all about Python scripting." Where? Please give some links. I searched for "python" and they were mostly about the tags on the main site.

Comment: Why would we have a site for banned users... The whole point of being banned, is that you're banned. The system determined you weren't making useful contributions, why would it assume that you would be able to do so on an oxymoronic site for banned users.

Comment: "_I'm still not entirely sure what it is about_" - I'm curious about what steps you have taken to find the answer to this question yourself. Either Googling "[What is the purpose of Stack Overflow Meta](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+the+purpose+of+stack+overflow+meta)" or checking out the [help] should be give you the answer. [We do expect you to do some research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) when asking questions (both here on Meta and on the main site).

Comment: "_Humans make mistakes and deserve to have multiple chances instead of being outright banned without warning._" A well-respected mod [commented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425435/did-not-get-a-warning#comment964302_425435) on your last post and provided a [screenshot showing you received three (3) separate warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uQFu.png).

Comment: I didn't see the text on the right when posting the question, but I do miss that stuff so that would be my fault. Though the moderator could've not assumed I had malicious intent in my question because it did come off as rude anyway. For the questions, I'll give some links in a second (if I can still find the questions). The site being gray also kinda made me think the site was for banned users. I don't know exactly why tbh. And lastly, I didn't see any mod comment with warnings. It should've been in a popup or a more noticeable spot.

Comment: "because it did come off as rude anyway" - that's why we really try not to comment on posts... (mostly failing that on meta... but we'll get better. There is generally nothing can be said to a user under q-ban that they would not interpret as "rude"... So hopefully you will not see any more comments and it should make you feel better.

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but this sounds like user error upon user error.

Meta has a lot of places where it describes what it is, and what it isn't. On top of that, the absence of any language-specific tag should be a strong hint.

Comment: *"I didn't receive any warnings in my inbox"* they don't go to your inbox, when you go to post a new question and you're close to a ban you are warned then; that you didn't read those 3 warnings means you didn't act on them. *"I thought it was for ban appeals"* bans aren't appealable; that are automated and not even a mod can revoke them. The way to get out of a ban is to improve the quality of your content, or when you post your next question (in 6~ months) make sure it's a really good quality question.

Comment: *"Humans make mistakes and deserve to have multiple chances"* you've been given *17* chances *at least*; how is that not multiple chances? You were warned 3 times as well, which is 1 more than your request for 2 chances. It was all there.

Comment: 1. I never saw the warnings as I said many times.

Comment: 2. Irreversible automated banning is REALLY not a good idea

Comment: 3. Mods can not sound rude by not saying "you're trying to evade banishment". There are many other things to say, that's not the only possible thing that can be said in that situation.

Comment: *"I never saw the warnings as I said many times"* that you didn't read them when they were displayed to you, on three occasions, isn't the system's fault. You've already admitted in this post you don't read the text on screen when posting a question. *"Irreversible automated banning is REALLY not a good idea"* it isn't; if you improve the quality of your content, and receive votes to confirm that, the ban goes away.

Comment: How are you supposed to improve the quality of your content if you're banned

Comment: "improve the quality of your content" suggests editing existing content to improve it, not asking new question.

Comment: “I asked a question that didn't have enough content in it (i think) to be considered a high-quality question.” - **You absolutely were not question banned due to a single poorly received question.** You asked 16 questions, potentially more than that, and received essentially zero upvotes. You were also told, that absolutely nobody, can manually lift your question ban. Only your positive contributions,  can lift your question ban, and you are given one question every 6 months to do that. **Your previous question on this community still exists by the way.** You were also given 16+ chances.

Comment: “Though the moderator could've not assumed I had malicious intent in my question because it did come off as rude anyway.” - They only provided proof that the warning was displayed, after you indicated, the warm wasn’t displayed. At no point, with your previous question, did anyone assume you had malicious intentions. Now with this question I would argue you have left a good amount of information about your contribution history out. Regardless if you saw the warning, you were given multiple (16) chances to submit acceptable questions, and you seem to fail to acknowledge that fact.

Comment: **At no point did anyone suggest you were evading a question ban by the way.** You and you alone can lift the question ban by submitting high quality questions once every 6 months until the rate limit is no longer required. You can still edit your existing questions, with appropriate edits, encouraging upvotes to them or use that single question once every 6 months. Entirely up to you

Comment: The moderator literally said "This is not the right way to get around the posting restriction, but it's a great way to earn another one."

Comment: That sounds like the closer to a comment I made earlier. I'm not a moderator. It wasn't a threat. It wasn't an insult. It was a statement of fact that was possibly a bit too cold-hearted. Note: You don't have the informed badge, so you have yet to take the tour and learn the bare minimum about how to use Stackoverflow. Here's another cold, hard fact: People will not take complaints about not knowing how to use a tool seriously when they can see that you have not looked at the manual.

Comment: I know there was an issue a couple of years back where the warnings genuinely *weren't* being displayed, even though the system said they were. Have we done a quick sanity check to make sure that this hasn't reoccurred, and that we're not accidentally gaslighting OP into thinking they missed a warning that they actually weren't shown?

Comment: *"The moderator literally said"* No moderator said that, it was [stated by](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425468/discord-py-async-generator-object-has-no-attribute-flatten#comment964606_425468) [user4581301](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4581301/user4581301), who is not a moderator. No one who has contributed on this question is a moderator either. Though they were correct; posting a programming on meta is not going to help you get out of your question ban.

Comment: Unfortunately we can't prove either way, @F1Krazy , however, as the OP has provided other examples of content they've not read that we *know* has been displayed by them, you can see why we've assumed the stance they were displayed and not read.

Comment: It also looks like someone has gone and upvoted all your content; note that those votes are *very* likely to be removed. If you asked a friend to perform those votes, you could easily find yourselves both suspended.

Comment: Having someone you know serially upvote your contributions can result in a suspension for voting fraud. It’s pretty obvious that someone serially upvoted your contributions, only question, was it out of a mistaken act of kindness or intentional act of voting fraud. In either case all the votes will most definitely will be reversed. The act also has been flagged for moderator intervention

Comment: Why would I get suspended for someone else's actions

Comment: @YozyOpto - You would only be suspended, if you created a new account, and upvoted your own contributions.  The other user would be suspended for voting fraud.  If you upvoted the other user's contributions, and they upvoted your contributions, that is considering to be a voting ring which obviously is not allowed. My comment was to warn you that, asking other users to upvote your contributions, will only result in those votes being reversed automatically. Depending on how often that happens you could be held responsible, but your participation would have to be fairly obvious.

Comment: More than likely you're the recipient of someone trying to help you out, but A) did it the wrong way and B) was so ham-fisted about it that the upvotes will probably be reversed. But do note the warnings about getting mixed up in voting rings. They generally end poorly.

Comment: A note about editing your way out of a ban by improving questions: It is slow going. There is no built-in incentive for a voter to return to a question after it's been edited to revise their opinion, so you're mostly counting on fresh eyes on the question to provide upvotes. This can take weeks or months depending on the final quality of the question, the amount of traffic it receives, and how many downvotes need to be offset.

Comment: I had nothing to do with this voting fraud

Comment: Also "My comment was to warn you that, asking other users to upvote your contributions, will only result in those votes being reversed automatically." is literally the same antagonization the other mod does. I'm getting tired of being falsely blamed for malice.

Comment: @YozyOpto, do you mean that any warning not to do something automatically equals to accusation of doing that? Sounds a bit unclever. Does this spread to all warnings for you? When you read "Remember, if you kill somebody, you'll go to jail" do you feel being accused of murder?

Comment: Yozy, be thankful when malice is assumed because [the flip side is often worse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor).

Answer (score 26):

> Firstly, I was banned from posting on Stack Overflow. I asked a question that didn't have enough content in it (i think) to be considered a high-quality question.

First: you are only banned from asking questions, and you can still ask one question per six months. In particular, *you are still able to edit your existing questions*, and to answer questions.

The main objection here: **no, you asked *many* questions** that failed to meet standards, and people *repeatedly* used the comments to explain to you specifically what the issues were with these questions. In some cases, they were closed as duplicates - while duplicate questions have some value to the site if you conceive of the question in a fundamentally different way, you are [expected to try to search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/) the site before asking.

The [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75973676) un-deleted question I see in your history was actually closed by me; we get this sort of question *all the time*, which is why there are [so many duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/45621722) (not even counting deleted ones) of [the reference canonical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621722). If I [copy and paste your question title into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=unindent+does+not+match+any+other+indentation+level) I can immediately get tons of useful information, even without specifying that it's for Python (it helps that this issue is particular to Python, of course).

But more importantly, you pasted hundreds of lines of code and expected others to fish around and figure out which line is "line 362". **This is not a reasonable way to approach people** for help on the Internet, even if we did offer a help desk, which we do not.

It also comes across that you are hoping to make yourself sound sympathetic and more deserving of help ("I've been staring at my code for hours looking for the problem"). There are two issues with that:

- We care about *directed* effort, and about *seeing what you learned* from that effort (did *you* know which line is line 362? Did you try looking *there*? The error told you that there is a problem with indentation; what indentation do you think that line had? Did you think that was the correct indentation? Why? Specifically what was your reasoning?). We care about these things *because they make the question better*.
- We *don't actually care* about "effort"; the reason *your question* does or does not "deserve" an answer has everything to do with the site's standards for question quality, and *nothing to do with you* as a person, your willingness to spend time on a problem etc.

Bluntly, your questions are **nowhere near meeting quality standards**, in a way that leaves me wondering what attempts you have even made to try to figure out what those standards *are*. They're explained pretty clearly in the site documentation:

- [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and additional links from there
- The site [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)
- and if you need more detail, there are [more than a hundred at least vaguely relevant Meta posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfaq%5D+ask).

Moving on...

> I didn't receive any warnings in my inbox or on my questions and thought I was asking okay questions until I got banned for one of them.

**You did, in fact, receive warnings**. "Your inbox" is not really a thing that exists on Stack Overflow, most of the time, because this is not social media nor a discussion forum, and we do not have DMs except for very specific moderator intervention situations. There is a notification system for when comments are added to your question, the question is closed or edited, etc. - but when the system warns you about this sort of thing, it is designed to be *directly in your way* when you try to post or to review your old questions.

Anyway, we know that you received warnings because a) we know how the system works generally and b) in your previous question on Meta, in the comments a moderator showed evidence that the system logged such warnings. If you didn't notice these warnings, I don't know what we can really tell you about that; if you aren't reading what the website tells you, why should we answer your questions and expect you to read and try to understand the answers?

> On this site, I thought it was for ban appeals which just seemed like they made sense, but the appeal got taken down.

What you posted **cannot in good faith be called an appeal**. "[This site] should improve its moderation to allow human beings to make mistakes instead of giving the most severe punishment to people who broke very minor rules in a very obviously accidental way." is not something I would advise anyone, *anywhere on the Internet*, to say with a straight face as part of a sincere attempt to appeal a ban. (I sincerely hope you are never prosecuted for a crime, because heaven help you if you decide to represent yourself in court and take that kind of attitude with a judge.)

Aside from that, no, that post *was not* "taken down"; it was *closed*. Like it says in the big shaded box at the top now, the question "does not appear to seek input and discussion from the community." Hard to disagree with that.

All that said, yes, meta.SO would be a place for ban appeals - among many other things - **only after** you have [**thoroughly read through the FAQ link**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/) that was given to you both in the comments for that question, and in the system message that told you about the question ban in the first place. However, ban appeals will be summarily dismissed because *moderators are not empowered* to lift this ban, which is fully automated by the Stack software, which we do not have access to.

> I decided to look around and found out that it was like the normal Stack Overflow but seemingly for those that were banned.

I can't imagine how you came to that conclusion. What you propose makes absolutely no sense; why would people who have been banned from using a site, be given an entire parallel site that works the same way to use freely? What would be the point?

> I saw a few questions and they were all about Python scripting so I assumed I could ask the same questions here as in the normal Stack Overflow, but my question got taken down AGAIN.

**This is an utterly bizarre assertion**. I can't see any questions about Python scripting on the front page here. I can *very clearly* see that the questions are all about the Stack Overflow site itself - because that is the purpose of Meta. This also follows from [what the word "meta" means](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=define+meta&ia=definition). It also follows from the fact that [if I try searching the Meta site for the text "python"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=python) I only get a few thousand results (compared to more than 2 million on the main site), and the first few results are clearly talking about stuff like proposals to rename tags on the site, proposals about how the site should do syntax highlighting, etc. It also follows from the fact that there [isn't a `python` tag here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python).

Really. **Show me even one** question that you "saw" and believed was "about Python scripting", which didn't get closed and heavily downvoted.

> The mod that took down the question also assumed I was trying to get around a ban even though I wasn't, which just came across as rude.

People coming to reasonable inferences based on the information available to them cannot be called rude. Please try to consider outside perspectives - it is not solely our responsibility to consider your perspective.

> I've seen people say it is about Stack Overflow but what do they mean by that? Is it just for questions on how to use the site?

Yes. What else could it mean? I don't see a reason to try to explain this, because I can't see a legitimate reason to be confused about it, and I can't imagine a way to make it clearer than it already is.

> It seems simple enough to me to not require an entirely new version of Stack Overflow for this.

... Okay, at this point I cannot resist pointing out the obvious.

If knowing how to use Stack Overflow is so simple, then *how have you found this many different ways to get it wrong*, to the point where you are posting in frustration with titles like "I don't understand anything on this site"?

Comment: First off, one question per six months is overkill. That's basically just not being able to ask questions at all so it's no excuse. Secondly, I never saw a single comment pointing out my mistakes. I only saw answers to my questions and no complaints, indicating that my questions were fine. The only question I saw complaints on was the question I got banned by. I don't remember asking any questions that would be deemed low-quality, as I left code snippets and clear problems on pretty much every question I asked. Whenever a question could've been interpreted as a duplicate, I made sure to

Comment: "First off, one question per six months is overkill." - Again: **we do not control this and cannot possibly do anything about it.** "Secondly, I never saw a single comment pointing out my mistakes." - On your first question, I left a comment which reads: "Please read minimal reproducible example. It is not reasonable to ask other people to examine hundreds of lines of code in order to explain why the indentation is wrong on one of them. Also, please do not use filler text to try to bypass automated system checks. We want you to make the question better, not worse."

Comment: " I don't remember asking any questions that would be deemed low-quality" - **all sixteen** of the undeleted questions I can see are ones that I would consider low quality. Bluntly, you need to understand that "I left code snippets and clear problems" is **nowhere near** the standard. "Whenever a question could've been interpreted as a duplicate, I made sure to" - and yet your very first question was one where copying and pasting your question title into a search engine immediately turns up multiple existing Stack Overflow questions about the same problem.

Comment: mention that the answers to the "duplicate" questions did not work for me. I do remember a question where I pasted my entire bot script expecting people to find the problem, but the problem was pointed out and it was fixed iirc. If the warnings were right in my way, how come I didn't see them? For the "I've been staring at my code for hours", you were right but it doesn't seem like a big enough deal to get banned because of it. Stack Overflow is also my third resort after Googling the question and asking ChatGPT. Frankly, idk how I came to the conclusion that this site was a site for banned

Comment: If you want to understand why a particular question isn't/wasn't well received, and can't figure it out after reading through the resources given to you, you can ask about that specific question here on Meta.

Comment: people, so I'll admit my fault there. I saw some questions with code in it and thought that the site was for Python questions because I couldn't think of what else it could be for.

Comment: Also I already said my first question, the one with hundreds of lines of code, was bad

Comment: For my questions, I told people my problem, what I wanted to do, what happened instead, and some code snippets and output snippets to help. I don't see what else would need to be added to the question. Everything people need to answer it would be right there.

Comment: "mention that the answers to the "duplicate" questions did not work for me." Sorry for cutting you off. But - no, you didn't. Again, for the example I selected, you didn't say anything about the reference canonical failing to help you, and you didn't say anything about other duplicates failing to help you, and in fact you didn't say anything about having found other duplicates.

Comment: "I know many have asked before, but none of the answers online worked."

Comment: "For my questions, I told people my problem, what I wanted to do, what happened instead, and some code snippets and output snippets to help. I don't see what else would need to be added to the question." - then you should **read the links I have provided you** in order to understand what else is wrong. I also recommend [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [Are there legitimate "fix my code" questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253787), particularly my answer there.

Comment: (By the way: there are *at least three* syntax problems in that first question. The first one happens because you have mixed two-space and four-space indentation, so the following line starting with `else if not` doesn't line up with anything. The second is the one you actually mentioned in the comments. The third that I see is not an indentation problem; but `else if` is not valid in Python.)

Comment: I'll check them out, thanks. As for everything, I will admit I got heated and irrational sometimes in the original post. I do think the site could do a better job at being fairer to people and being more lenient since I felt like every single thing I did put me in more trouble, even though I thought they were okay. In the meantime, what's the best way for me to become unbanned?

Comment: "In the meantime, what's the best way for me to become unbanned?" Please **read the [FAQ link about question bans](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/)**, that I already linked in this question and discussed being previously linked to you, in order to understand that.

Comment: While I agree with Yozy that a robot should not have complete and total control of the banning mechanism, I've not been able to come up with a human-intervention system that scales to the Stackoverflow userbase. Asking good questions is hard work, it takes practice, and it's kind-of depressing in the result: the better you compose the question the less likely you are to post it. A good question-asking process is also a good question-answering process. As you start crossing the 't's and dotting the 'i's the problem space gets smaller and you're more likely to solve it.

Comment: @Y Recommended reading: [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: @chivracq: "Qt" is not an abbreviation... If anything, "Question" would be abbreviated to "Q". (that "t" isn't even a logical second letter there...)

Comment: @YozyOpto - You were given feedback on multiple questions. You were given a fair chance to ask questions of acceptable quality. The problem seems to be two major things. You not actively acknowledging this feedback and addressing the issues with your existing questions. This means your existing questions will not be answered and will likely never be positively received. This of course means that your existing unanswered questions will likely eventually be automatically deleted for being abandoned. That won’t be a good, deleted questions, can’t receive upvotes.

Comment: Secondly, a single well received question, likely will be enough to lift the question ban. However, you have since been serially upvoted, which is essentially voting fraud upon the party who issued those votes. So those votes are invalid, this fact is obvious, as they were all cast within seconds of each other.

Comment: Idk how my votes went from negative to over 20, that's probably a glitch or smth since I don't see why anyone would want to make like 20 alt accounts just to get the votes of this question up

Comment: *"I can't see any questions about Python scripting on the front page here."* there actually was a brief moment of time in the past day or two where there were several lost souls asking python questions here on meta at the same time.

Comment: @YozyOpto You're misinterpreting the UI. This answer has 20 upvotes, not your question. the simpler explanation is 20 unique people upvoted it, rather than someone went through the trouble of creating 20 accounts with enough rep to upvote....

Comment: @YozyOpto between what I said and that last comment exchange, I get the impression that the common pattern here is you misinterpreting or misunderstanding things that were plainly shown or told to you, and that the best way to fix this issue is for you to *pay closer attention*.

Comment: @YozyOpto - "I don't see why anyone would want to make like 20 alt accounts just to get the votes of this question up" - Fake votes have been used before to temporally lift question bans. This answer received 20 upvotes, the question, has only received 3 upvotes.

Comment: @chivracq: But why the obfuscation? Why not just spell it out? Is it some kind of trolling?

Comment: If terseness is the point, then just use "Q", it's shorter, it's equally clear, and at least it's not something made-up :D @chivracq Also, what you contribute on a different website is completely irrelevant on SO...

Comment: @chivracq The [Cambridge dictionary disagrees](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/there-is-there-s-and-there-are) with your, frankly childish, assessment. It's perfectly valid in informal writing.

Comment: Mate... I suggested not to use _Qt_ ___once___, then mentioned that your brevity argument favors "Q"... I thought the discussion was over, but then you apparently felt the need to dig through my account to correct me about perfectly valid grammar, 3 days later.

Comment: there's an edit button on nearly every post, i don't see the point in leaving a comment asking someone else to make an edit. just do it.