# Is it unkind to invite a person to clean up his code?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, comments

Recently, a person registered for one year, submitted his thirteenth question. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23965356/240613) featured a piece of code which:

- Is badly indented (which makes it quite misleading sometimes),
- Has no consistency whatsoever (sometimes there is a space, and three lines later, there is no space in a similar context, etc.),
- Has poor naming conventions,
- Is overly complicated, especially since it contains useless code (like an empty `foreach` loop),
- Mixes HTML with PHP.

While not providing any answer, I downvoted the question, and since it may not be obvious to the author why he received the downvote, I explained it through the comment:

> -1 for unmaintainable code with ugly formatting and poor naming conventions. Why not doing a basic cleanup before posting your source code publicly?

The author seemed particularly unhappy with my comment:

> -1 for posting a code im having trouble with, that i didnt write myself .. thanks dude .. if you are not going to help then please dont post, telling me my code is "unmaintainable" or ugly is not a big help, and even so you didnt even focus at the question, but more at the code formatting.. im not good at php and still learning, so please be nice or i will find another community to ask...

For me:

- The "it's not my code" argument is irrelevant. He's working on this piece of code, so it's his professional obligation to start by re-factoring it and cleaning it up. Even if he's explicitly asked to keep the code unmaintainable, he could have cleaned it up before posting it on Stack Overflow, where the code will be read by dozens or hundreds of programmers.
- The "I'm not good at PHP" argument is irrelevant as well. Even a beginner should be able to fix indentation. The fact that he's posting the code as-is is more a sign of laziness than lack of language skills.

So:

- Am I an unlikely person (well, I know the answer to this one) and my comment was both unkind *and* useless?
- More importantly, **should I have formulated my comment differently? How?**
- **How to help users** like the original poster **to improve their questions** (on 13 questions, only one is upvoted, four being downvoted), without offending them?

Comment: You have spent far more effort in commenting to this person and writing this question than you would have by editing out the issues you have seen in the code (while preserving the question). Just saying.

Comment: Just stop commenting every time you downvote. It is a waste of your time, and causes the problems described above. People aren't as dumb as they act. They know what badly formatted code looks like.

Comment: There is a literal army of human robo-editors who submit minor edits.  You wouldn't want to deny them their 2 points, now would you?

Comment: This is not the kind of user that is likely to contribute positively to SO.  Pretty hard to get rid of them, downvoting these kind of posts help.  Posting snarky comments help too, that this is beneficial to the site is however rarely appreciated, certainly not by the OP :)  So just stick with the downvote.

Comment: Did the code get ninja-edited with better formatting? What I am looking at isn't horrible at all and there's no edit history.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel it was formatted/indented [original](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23965356/1) (maybe that revision was ninja edited, it's not awful but it's not good either).

Comment: `you didnt even focus at the question, but more at the code formatting` - users don't recognise the importance of being able to see "the problem" without all the mess. It's like visiting your slob friend's house who doesn't understand why you don't want to stay sitting on the pizza-stained sofa to watch a movie on his new TV. I think the wording of your message could have been less personal "the code is hard to read like that" v "Why not doing a basic cleanup...?" (focus on question/content not the person) but is appropriate.

Comment: @AD7six I think you should post that last comment as an answer, it raises a good and important point.

Comment: i downvote bad indentation all the time. on the "how to ask" page there is a section called "Proof-read before posting!" and everyone who ignores that deserves a downvote. one could argue that downvoting a question just for bad indentation is bad, but the truth is i cannot remember a single question with bad indentation that was otherwise really good.

Comment: If a question's code is so upsetting, with bad formatting and failure to obey variable-naming conventions, etc., that I can't get past it, I do this: Just. Walk. Away.

Comment: "if you are not going to help" That there. I go on flagging sprees with -1, CV, VLQ, and a comment "Stack Overflow is not a help site" where I look at the worst new posts for about 5 seconds each.

Comment: In some languages indentation and formatting carry a lot more weight.  E.g., even though people like to pick on Lisp's parentheses, Lisp programmers are actually reading by indentation, which should be provided by the editor/IDE, and the parentheses are just assumed to be correct.  If the formatting is inconsistent or nonstandard, it's next to impossible to tell whether code is even correctly structured, let alone semantically correct.  Calling someone's code "ugly" might not be the best way to get them to fix it, but it's still important that they do fix it.

Comment: Once OP responded as you indicate I would simply delete my comment and move on. You can lead the horse to water but you can't make him drink.

Comment: Join us in the Fortran tag and you will soon become less sensitive to weird formatting and missing indentation. People post horrible stuff and we would have to downvote.almost everything.

Comment: @VladimirF: Why don't you do so then? Or are you too desensitized / have given up on them?

Comment: @Oded: I might agree with you on the editing point, except that we can't be expected to fix every noob's poorly-formatted post.  The army of folks who post their poorly formatted code far outnumbers the smaller legion of volunteers who are diligently trying to keep the site clean.  After awhile, you get worn out.

Comment: @Deduplicator Often the guys don't know how proper code should look like, they are not CS or CE experts. Often they are taught people who don't know that either. Some of their codes com from 70s. Do they have to reformat long snippets of them just because of asking a question?

Comment: @VladimirF: Yes, they have to properly format any code they submit. If they want help, they have an obligation to ask a proper question, which includes proper formatting of the text **and** code (which they should reduce to remove irrelevant parts, see [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). If they can't be bothered, their question looses worth, and downvoting for bad questions is the proper action.

Comment: "*im not good at php and still learning, so please be nice or i will find another community to ask...*" - but if we're not nice then the OP might go away and never ask badly-punctuated, poorly formatted questions here again! ...wait, was that a promise or a threat..?

Comment: @CodyGray sorry but I have to disagree with you on "downvote and go". I have been a victim of Downvote happy people for absolutely unwarranted reasons.

Comment: @Oded Had the OP simply edited the question, this useful discussion would have never happened. And as others have pointed out, it's better to instill good posting practices than to only fix everyone's mistakes.

Comment: @logix There is no such thing as being a "victim" of downvoting. It is not victimization, votes are not against *people*, they're cast on posts. Someone just didn't think your question/answer was sufficiently clear or useful. There is no possible way that you can evaluate whether *someone else* had a good enough reason to warrant a downvote. You aren't in their head, and it isn't your prerogative. Of course you liked the post, you're the one who posted it.

Comment: @CodyGray yeah I guess you are right. I guess maybe I down vote for when its really warranted where a person has either shown no effort, or it was blatant spam. I have enough rep now on SO where it doesnt bother me, but when you are starting off and learning the down votes are very discouraging. For me I will leave comments to make recommendations to improve a post and only down vote for critically wrong answers or no effort questions.

Comment: *im not good at php and still learning,* is, in my opinion, the nowadays excuse for laziness and completely lack of every kind of effort

Comment: @Oded Fixing people's code for them is fine, but surely it's _much_ better to steer them towards the realisation that they should do it themselves? And how to? I get frustrated when regulars "fix" crappy code within moments of it being posted, before anyone has a chance to teach the OP that it is not acceptable to post it _or even write it_ like that in the first place.

Comment: @matt Well that solves the problem for you but not for the community at large, making you a non-contributor and arguably part of the problem =)

Comment: Seems rather unkind to post ugly code in the first place...

Comment: New programmers usually don't see the value in commenting, indenting, mnemonic variable names, etc. They're just happy if code works at all. Showing new programmers what a properly formatted program looks like is a start. Tone can be misinterpreted online. That's why I try to lean towards "friendly" when commenting.

Comment: You might find [this suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233564/193412) very relevant.

Comment: @VladimirF Somehow I doubt this guy was posting PHP code from the 70s. Reformatting "long snippets" (isn't "long" the opposite of "snippet"?) isn't any harder than editing it down to a minimal test case. This isn't a site for people to just dump large swaths of code for others to debug for them.

Comment: @HansPassant Wow. That is not the kind of StackOverflow I want to be a part of... and yet, your comment has a massive number of upvotes. I try not to be overly generous when I'm looking at bad work, but that's no excuse for being rude. I think the OP's comments here were rude, and when you're rude, you actually *trigger* the kind of response the OP got from the other user. Be polite, even if you think they don't "deserve" it. People tend to respond in kind to what you do.

Comment: "Is it unkind to invite a person to clean up his code?" I don't get why this question got so many upvotes. Isn't it obvious? If you do it kindly then it's not unkind, if you're not polite then it's unkind.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

First of all, you are absolutely correct in down voting a low quality question. This is crucial in making good content float to the top and to give it better visibility.

As for the comment, I think your *intention* was good, but I'd do execution a tad differently.

> Please consider revising the code sample you  posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you. Here is a [great resource](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. -1: don't take it the wrong way, but a down vote is how we indicate a content problem around here. Improve your formatting and code sample and I'll gladly revert it. Good luck with your code! Personally I think it'd be good to work on *list of question specific things that are poorly written*.

While your initial comment was equally correct, this sort of comment has a much bigger chance of motivating the OP to improve his question rather than get bitter about the comments.

That said, you can't please everyone and I wouldn't take OP's dissatisfaction too hard. "Policing" SO is a noble thing and it's how we keep a high quality site.

Comment: Is it really necessary to even mention that you downvoted? I think that's asking for trouble. [Anonymity when making comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253531/456814) would be useful in this situation though...

Comment: `don't take it the wrong way, a down vote is how we indicate a content problem around here` - Are users prompted what a downvote is when they (first) receive them? It seems ~inefficient to need to mention what a downvote means like that, if they don't know they should (via the faq PLUS whatever SE does, or should do, to tell them) if they do know it's redundant and robs space in the comment for `list of question specific things that are poorly written`.

Comment: @Cupcake My thoughts exactly.  It's not like the poster can't figure out that you downvoted anyway.  Generally I just point the user towards something more likely to get their question answered.

Comment: +1 for nice answer, once there was a king he dreamed about all his relatives, he narrated this dream to his two astrologist ,one told him that all his relatives will die before him and due to this statement astrologist was killed instantly, second astrologist was wise enough and he told king that he will be enjoying a life more than any of his relatives and this statement made king happy and he awarded the astrologist , so point is that you can conquer the world by ur words

Comment: This kind of questioner won't read such a long comment. It's a waste of time.

Comment: That is a nice comment, but I think it would be better to remove that -1 bit. There's no particular using in owning up the downvote — it would only make things worse.

Comment: Your comment idea, @Ben, is okay but it would be better if you stopped abusing commas.

Comment: @AmalMurali My experience is that OPs like this will jump on the first comment and assume they were the downvoter regardless.  IMO, if you're going to explain your downvote, best to own it (and in other cases, I've seen "I didn't downvote, but...")

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm not going to edit it again, but the commas you promoted to semicolons should, IMHO, have been promoted to full stops, and the comma you promoted to a full stop should have only been promoted to a semicolon, or include a conjunction like "but" :-)

Answer (score 71):

I think this is one of those cases where it's easier to lead with a carrot...

[image]

I usually don't bother to ask the OP to clean up their question unless I'm vaguely interested in answering it. In these cases I can leave comments more along the lines of:

> That code is hard to read... If you clean it up, I'll help you.

A gentle approach has some advantages:

- You're not being confrontational.
- You're not making any demands.
- You're not requesting a response from the OP (the comment is a statement not a question)
- You don't have to write a paragraph.
- The best reason by far... Everyone wants their questions answered.

Even the laziest [help vampire](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) wants their questions answered. If you are offering to give them what they need they are a lot more likely to fix the question and the next time around they're a lot more likely to tidy up before they post.

Comment: The "carrot approach" is also touted as one of the benefits of the [proposed high-quality content filter](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253351/456814), with the idea being that if people want experts to see and answer their questions, then they have to write and ask questions that meet a certain standard of quality first.

Comment: Exactly. No need to be prolix. I just type "You must format your code on this site" and click send.

Answer (score 32):

First things first - many people don't respond well to constructive criticism, they don't want to change, they don't care about the site, they just want their question answered. It's important to keep this in mind, and accept it, because you will get such responses occasionally, you might even become the target of revenge voting and you'll get ignored plenty - if you do choose to comment, you'll need to hold out for those that would respond well.

**When you get a response like the one you got:**

Just ignore it and forget about the question.

OP made it fairly clear that he/she isn't the type of user who will respond well.

The more time you spend on this, the more negative you get, and the less likely you'll be to just give up on posting these comments in hopes of having a few take what you say to heart.

Now **let's look at your comment**:

> -1

Admitting that you're the downvoter will likely make you the target of revenge voting, when you may just be trying to help. I personally prefer to stick to something like "Some people may be downvoting you because ...", regardless of whether I myself downvote or not - I do prefer being upfront about things, but I also prefer avoiding unnecessary conflict and unnecessarily making myself a target for revenge. It doesn't really matter who downvoted - the point is that there's a problem in the post and it's getting downvoted because of it.

> unmaintainable code with ugly formatting and poor naming conventions

Why is it unmaintainable? What's ugly about it? What's wrong with the naming conventions?

These things may seem obvious to you, but don't expect everyone to think similarly.

If possible, try to highlight specific examples, say what would look better and/or point to a resource on the topic.

Also, "unmaintainable", "ugly" and "poor" are all fairly objectively negative words - it's not entirely pleasant to have something you wrote called all those things. I'd probably go more neutral.

> Why not doing a basic cleanup before posting your source code publicly?

I can't really tell you what's wrong with such questions, but they rarely come across well.

Think suggestion rather than question.

**What I'd suggest:**

> Some people may be downvoting your question because it uses non-standard indentation - typically all blocks should use the same indentation (e.g. the while-statement is indented too much and the if-statement should not be indented) and you're using non-descriptive naming (e.g. "loop" doesn't exactly tell us what that is). See [this site](http://example.com) for further guidance. I hope you'll edit your post appropriately and try to keep these things in mind for future posts.

You can also avoid the topic of downvoting altogether:

> There are some things in the question that makes it difficult for us to help you. For example, you use non-standard indentation - typically all blocks should use the same indentation (e.g. the while-statement is indented too much and the if-statement should not be indented) - and non-descriptive naming (e.g. "loop" doesn't exactly tell us what that is). See [this site](http://example.com) for further guidance. I hope you'll edit your post appropriately and try to keep these things in mind for future posts.

There's also the other possibility of actually fixing their post, then posting a comment (or just use the Edit Summary).

> You may notice that I fixed your post. The reasons were because of your non-standard indentation - typically all blocks should use the same indentation (e.g. the while-statement is indented too much and the if-statement should not be indented) and your use of non-descriptive names (e.g. "loop" doesn't exactly tell us what that is). See [this site](http://example.com) for further guidance. I hope you'll take these changes to heart and try to keep these things in mind for future posts.

Changing variables names might be considered a radical change in some cases, so, if you do choose to make sure edits, make sure you know the language well enough such that renaming the variable doesn't cause other issues or fix the problem, and absolutely make sure you change all occurrences of it, so we're not left with a [non-verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I agree with nearly everything here, with the exception of changing the variable names.  While mentioning conventions and proper methods are a plus, a change in names can have far-reaching effects in other, unlisted, sections of code.  Granted anyone that knows programming will quickly grasp that, new people may not, and will get stuck when the name change breaks something elsewhere.  +1 besides that though!

Comment: @MatthewJohnson Tbf if they're just going to copy-paste things from SO back into their project then that's their mistake. I would, however, advise against changing the variable names because that could be the cause of the issue the OP was having.

Comment: I [posted a similar comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62611758/how-to-move-on-branch-in-git#comment110724009_62611758) onto a question that did not show research or even the problem. Thoughts?

Answer (score 15):

> was [my comment] useless?

### No

A user may not realize just how hard to read the code is (if they didn't write it - they are probably familiar enough with it to read through the poor formatting). It may actually be a surprise that whitespace matters to other people trying to read it.

If a question/code is hard to read it takes longer to read *if* it gets read at all - It also often leads to "distracting" answers which either misread the question's code or focus on a different point than the (main) one that would help the OP.

So: no, it was definitely not useless.

> should I have formulated my comment differently? How?
>
> How to help users like the original poster to improve their questions (on 13 questions, only one is upvoted, four being downvoted), without offending them?

### Focus on the content, not the person

As is evident from how the comment was received - it was taken personally, in part because of the way the message was expressed.

These terms are subjective and aren't directly related to the formatting or the question as asked:

- un-maintainable
- poor naming conventions

This term is derogatory, and is actually the only part of the comment addressing the actionable part of the comment - that the code wasn't indented:

- ugly

This is accusative:

- Why not doing a basic cleanup before posting your source code publicly?

So distill the point to be about "the problem" and *focus on the content and not the person*.

By writing about the content it also neatly sidesteps the (irrelevant) "this isn't my code" comeback. If I were to have written a comment to that question it would have probably had the same meaning but been expressed along the lines of:

> The code in the question is hard to read - please format the code for readability. Since that makes it hard to answer: -1.

Note that:

- There's no need to sugar-coat requests, but also no need to be overly accusative/agressive about it
- The comment implies how (at least one) downvote can be reversed
- None of the points which don't affect answering the question are mentioned
- I don't feel the need to explain how voting works every time I leave a downvote comment<sup>[*]</sup>
- The outcome *may* be the same

Particularly note the last point - depending on the person it may change nothing how a request is made; human nature is what it is.

<sup>*</sup> *if there is a need, it should be handled by the platform not mentioned in every comment to a user with a downvote*.

Answer (score 12):

I think you could probably have set yourself up for a more friendly response by framing your comment in such a way that it looks less like you're criticizing the OP for what he/she already did, and more like you're telling the OP what needs to change and why.

That way, it looks less to the OP like you're attacking him/her, making you less likely to offend the OP. This will have the added benefit of making the OP less hostile, and actually more open to edit in what you've asked.

So, in the future, instead of comments like this:

> -1 for unmaintainable code with ugly formatting and poor naming conventions. Why not doing a basic cleanup before posting your source code publicly?

Try comments like this:

> The formatting of your code and descriptiveness variable names make it hard to read.  Could you please format your code and rename your variables so that it's easier to understand?

---

You should always try to find a way to make your comment in such a way that it tells the OP what you want him/her to do, while at the same time not offending him/her. The OP is more likely to actually do what you ask when you haven't offended him/her.

Answer (score 9):

My actual approach varies depending on my mood, so I don't follow this consistently. But in general I will do one of:

- Write a "help us help you, please read the [minimal example page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" comment if it looks like the user has pasted a large, incomplete chunk of their own code.
- Format the code myself and maybe add a comment pointing this out, if the issues are mostly confined to formatting and indentation. Sometimes a user doesn't yet know their way around Stack Overflow.
- Ask the user to format the code themselves if it's Python code and I'm not 100% sure what the intended indentation is.
- Downvote often without a comment if it's a proper mess, i.e. a messy copy/paste of someone else's code and no explanation on what's wrong as you describe.

Answer (score 4):

I arrived at this post because as someone newish to coding and new to Stack Overflow I am grateful when people help me clean up my code.

I have a difficult time understanding how other people see code as sometimes my messy code makes more sense to me or other times I simply struggle with getting the code to function and then end up with working but messy code.

The first question I posted this month the very first response cleaned it up for me and then someone even made a CSS style sheet for me. It was so helpful, helped me to learn and made it to where my code is cleaner in the future.

I have a lot of anxiety about posting on forums due to the chance of being told I did it wrong or in the case of this comment even will I anger people by "necro"ing an old post. Despite it being relevant at least to me.

I am actually wondering if it rude for me to post a question on this site or perhaps some other one simply asking "please help me clean up my code"?

**Update:** I now understand from the below responses that Meta Stack Overflow is the place to ask a question such as the last one. Also, the place to actually have your code reviewed is Code Review Stack Exchange

[Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

[Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your perspective! A question like "please clean up my code" would not be on-topic for Stack Overflow, because it's too broad and open-ended. In order to ask a question here, you need to have a practical programming problem. Cleaning up the code might be something a good, complete answer does, but it cannot be the sole focus of your question. However, there *is* a [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) Q&A site where you can post your code and have it reviewed. Note that it needs to be *working* code, and all ways of improving it are fair game for answers.

Comment: As for your concern about "necro"ing an old post: that is not a thing here on Stack Exchange, and especially Stack Overflow. We do, of course, ask that you not post an answer that merely repeats what existing answers already say. But that applies to both new and old questions. If you have a *new* solution to contribute that hasn't already been posted, then yes, you are welcome to post it, even if the question is 10+ years old. A fundamental premise of a Q&A site like ours is that our work is never done, there are always new users with better solutions to share.

Comment: What is the point of putting the last sentence into your post? (If you are asking for responses, it doesn't belong.)

Comment: @philipxy Sorry for the confusion. I agree with kaya3 that my main paragraph is an answer from my point of view to the original question. But as I attempted to say in the above comment, I believe you are right in that it should have been asked on Meta Stack Overflow which at the time I did not understand. Again thank you for helping me to understand how this site works better.

The overall conversation around this subject is educational to me and import. I will edit in a note to explain that it should be asked in Meta in case anyone comes here with similar confusion as to mine.

Comment: Thanks. Please just edit your post to be the best response right now to the original question. Please don't use UPDATEs/EDITs. This is Q&A, not a forum, we don't want a thread of interactions. (Click 'edited' for earlier post versions.) And if you have a (non-duplicate) question of your own to ask then post that as a question. See the help link. PS I couldn't understand what your earlier comment was trying to say re my comment re your last sentence. Thanks for clarifying by editing your question. Although just removing what doesn't belong is better. Thanks for notifying me via comment.

Answer (score 4):

*"Even a beginner should be able to fix indentation. The fact that he's posting the code as-is is more a sign of laziness than lack of language skills."*

As someone who teaches programming to absolute beginners, in my experience bad code formatting is not a sign of laziness, and *does* indicate a lack of skills; though the skill they lack is not specific to the language they are learning.

Beginner programmers may write badly-formatted code because they don't discern a significant difference between their code and well-formatted code, in the same way that someone learning a foreign language might not discern the difference between two sounds which aren't distinct in their native language. It's not that they aren't paying attention, but that they don't know what they should pay attention to.

Imagine an absolute beginner in Java writing `system.out.println` and staring at the screen for ten minutes trying to figure out why their code doesn't work, when it's "exactly the same" as what's in their textbook. Experienced programmers know to pay attention to the difference between `S` and `s` because we've *learned* to pay attention to it. The difference may be completely absent in a beginner's thoughts when they are comparing their code with the textbook, but the ten minutes of effort they spent trying to *find* the difference proves it's not laziness.

So, what you're talking about *can* be adequately explained by a lack of skills, and I think it is wrong to infer laziness.

Comment: While you have a point, I believe you're overthinking it. The cases I was talking about are not about `system.out.println`, but about pieces of code where the person clearly refused to make any effort to write the code correctly. If I take your comparison with people who are learning a foreign language, a sentence such as “i hav prbolem plz help This is my code [...]” doesn't show the lack of proficiency in English, but an actual laziness. This being said, I didn't downvote your answer, nor do I think it deserves to be downvoted.

Comment: The part I'm responding to is about indentation; I was teaching a few students this morning who literally were not aware that their code wasn't indented the same way as my example. I'm only using `system.out.println` as an example to make the point, because I think it is easier for experts to imagine or remember being a beginner and having that problem. [heromedel's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/394403/12299000) says *"I have a difficult time understanding how other people see code"*, which is exactly what I'm talking about.

Comment: That said, I would be really interested to know why two people have downvoted my answer, which is meant to be a call for empathy for beginner programmers, based on my experience.

Comment: There is indentation and indentation. I've seen pieces of code where bad indentation is a result of inexperience. And then there are others, where the person just couldn't care less. Same comparison with people learning English: some may have mistakes, such as French people putting spaces before colons and semicolons, because in French, there are actual spaces before. Others may just skip punctuation because they don't care about their readers.