# Feedback requested: New "recommended" homepage, phase 1

Tags: discussion, question-quality, homepage, se-quality-project

**For the background, see: [The Stack Overflow homepage is over-emphasizing bad questions (and a proposed solution)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258699/the-stack-overflow-homepage-is-over-emphasizing-bad-questions-and-a-proposed-so)**

We've put together a first pass at a new homepage algorithm. You can check it out here:

#### https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=recommended

What it's doing is this:

1. Take the 3000 most recently active questions (same as the current homepage) with Score > -3
   1a. If you can't close/reopen yet, hide closed questions
2. Filter out any questions with ignored tags
3. From the remainder, randomly choose 15 "hot" questions, where hot is just "Score >= 20 and has an answer"
4. From the remainder, choose another 81 using an exponential weighted random over your favorite tags.
5. Mix them together, sort by recent activity and display

Your favorite tags are both **explicit** favorites that you've set, and **implicit** favorites from a bit of machine learning magic based on what you've answered in the past. If you want to see what the machine learning thinks you're interested in, check out https://stackoverflow.com/users/tag-future/current

The "exponential" part of the weighted random means that if it has some tags we think you're interested in, it becomes way more likely to show up on your homepage (topping out at ~400x). The effect is that you see mostly questions in your favorite tags, if you have any, but *unlike* the current homepage it's still a random selection, not a straight sort descending (so you see different stuff every pageload).

It also has two subtabs:

1. Needs Answer: like above, but filter down to only unanswered questions (no upvoted or accepted answer)
2. Hot: like above, but filter down only to hot questions (Score >= 20)

Take a look and tell us what you think. Try changing your favorite / ignored tags and see how it responds.

Some other things we think are good ideas but **have not** implemented yet:

1. Show more hot stuff and less unanswered stuff to anonymous users
2. Give bountied questions more weight so they show up more often
3. Add filter options to filter by tag, score, etc.

What do you think?

### Update

Thanks for the feedback! We're definitely going to take another pass at this next week and we'll update when it's out. Feel free to keep leaving feedback, but some things we're definitely going to look at:

1. Getting rid of the yellow highlighting on the page, since basically everything is supposed to be interesting to you
2. Rethinking how the "hot" part works, since it's basically just selecting for old, popular posts that recently got a probably irrelevant edit or answer (but this might be a good subject for a review queue)
3. Nav / UI - this wasn't really intended to be final or even part of the proposal. It's just jammed in there for now so people can play with it. Also 'featured' wasn't supposed to go away.

> #### Stack Exchange Quality Improvement Project
>
> - [Allow users to optionally filter out low-quality questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253351/allow-users-to-optionally-filter-out-low-quality-questions)
> - **[Feedback requested: New “recommended” homepage, phase 1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261138/feedback-requested-new-recommended-homepage-phase-1)**
> - [What should the system be deleting automatically that it already isn't?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262077/what-should-the-system-be-deleting-automatically-that-it-already-isnt)
> - [Let's have an explicit triage system for questions from new users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236537/lets-have-an-explicit-triage-system-for-questions-from-new-users)
> - [Breaking down question blocks - let's talk about rate limits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236568/breaking-down-question-blocks-lets-talk-about-rate-limits)

Comment: This looks a _lot_ more relevant than it used to a month ago. Great work.

Comment: One thing that I immediately noticed it that this version seems to emphasize very old, but highly upvoted questions rather strongly. Most of the answer added to really old, popular questions are just plain crap. They certainly need some community review, but if the plan was to actually highlight good content I'm not so sure that so many old questions should be put on the frontpage.

Comment: @Mad I agree, this is something we need to look into. It seems to be emphasizing "Popular questions that just got a random crappy new answer / edit" rather than good new content.

Comment: Another idea, which is similar to some old discussions on the frontpage, would be to avoid showing *any* crap to anonymous users. Those users won't help moderate anyway, so showing them only upvoted questions might make sense. It would give a better impression of the site to new users. The one drawback I see is that anonymous users would get a "cleaner" frontpage than high-rep users able to close.

Comment: Wait, where is featured tab when recommended tab is chosen?

Comment: it would be nice if the "needs answer" tab took how recent the question is into consideration, the first one I clicked into was from 4 years ago..

Comment: The "hot" subtab seems useless, as it is showing mostly old stuff. Maybe change it to "record breaking questions"?

Comment: Would be possible to put this in other parts of the network?

Comment: I always wondered about the **hot** algorithm. A low-rep user posts a useless answer to a highly upvoted, old question and now it is hot. I can't find anything hot in my hot list.

Comment: Will there be an easy way to filter the `[needs answer]` view by tag? I would assume if you're looking for unanswered questions, you are looking for a specific language/technology.

Comment: @Rachel yes, we're looking at adding a tag filter to that page, and maybe eventually extending this view to be the default for the tag list pages

Comment: @DavidFullerton Ok thanks. Another question, why does the `[hot]` view show so many really old questions with thousands of views? It would probably be nicer if it showed newer questions that are rising fast, so it would be worthwhile for users to check that view regularly.

Comment: @Rachel Yeah we're going to take a look at that. I've updated the post to call out some of the most common complaints that we're already planning to look at.

Comment: I actually like the yellow highlighting just because I usually only look at 2 tags, and typically there's only a few questions with those tags in the front page. So for me, the yellow highlighting of favorite tags is nice. Before that, I always ignored the front page.

Comment: Please keep the yellow highlighting. There are usually one or two questions on the list that are not in my favorite tags, and the color makes it easy to spot these out. Not that I am not interested in those questions, but I can form proper expectations before I check them out given the difference in highlighting. And even if everything is supposed to be interesting to me, disabling highlighting on this page would result in inconsistencies across different question lists, which is a nuisance when switching between tabs on the homepage.

Comment: It keeps showing me android tags of which I do not partake in, it should probably filter relevancy by higher tag score for high rep users who have a lot of random tags from related questions.

Comment: @Sammaye Check http://stackoverflow.com/users/tag-future/current to see if it thinks you do (or did) partake in android questions.

Comment: @MarkHurd Yeah it actually says I should be avoiding android tags, but it seems the homepage has been changed, it works for me now, shows me only tags I want

Comment: @MarkHurd spoke too soon, not sure why that shows for me on it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24346559/cocos2dx-c-ccshatteredtiles3d-is-slow

Comment: @Sammaye Note that although the tag-future link changes to be user-specific, as a normal user I cannot see anyone else's predictor. Does yours include C++? Perhaps inclusion is overriding avoided tags.

Comment: @Sammaye Of course, immediately after writing the previous comment, I realised I can still just look at your tags directly and I can see you've only answered 1 C++ question for no votes, so I don't know either!

Comment: If you give me mostly questions for the tags predicted the prediction will come true by itself eventually. I'd like to have a way to set my preferences. I'd like to explore new topics that I'm not an expert at yet.

Comment: Please keep the yellow highlight! The tag-future thinks I like questions tagged "java" and "mysql" (cause I answered a lot in there) but they are not favs of mine (cause I prefer different tags that just coincidence). Filtering these out (without ignoring them) is very useful to me. - Sometimes I read them, but most of the time I don't want to see them.

Comment: So I've been using the Hot tab for a few weeks to review recent edits and answers to old questions, and I actually really like it for that purpose. You could possibly move its algorithm into a review queue instead, but I really like being able to ***see*** a broad overview of recent edits and new answers, which none of the review queues currently provide. I would be interested in seeing a Review **tab** instead, though I'll settle for a review queue if other people don't like the Review tab idea.

Comment: Why I cant see any answer / comment of a user that has more than 150k rep? I thought they are the most active in the community.

Answer (score 25):

I can't say I'm going to use the frontpage anytime soon (although this might partially be because of the awful yellow backgrounds).

I'd be a lot more interested if the 'recent' tab had more up-and-coming questions in the `3 <= votes <= 20` range instead of the current `-3 <= votes <= 2` and `> 20` range. Surely there must be several questions that get this kind of voting often enough; if I want to find new questions to answer then there is an entire tab for it.

Aside from that I really don't see the reasoning behind placing a -3 question in the "Recommended recent top questions" list.

The "hot" tab on the other hand *is* very interesting although I would like to see my favorited tags more highly represented. About 33% of the questions there are in one of my favorited tags and only 3 of them are not [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) or [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23). I have 21 favorited tags.

Comment: There's no cap at 2 votes, but beyond 2 votes they tend to already be answered and therefore not shown. Questions between 2 votes and N (currently 20) tend to be run-of-the-mill answered questions -- not particularly interesting, got a decent answer, not much to see here. Or that's the theory at least. We can always tweak it and see.

Comment: I agree that the yellow highlight can be annoying when you have lots of favorite tags. I used to not use the front page at all because of that. The yellow highlight became more useful when I got rid of all my favorite tags except for one, but then doing that has it's own problems (none of my other favorites are highlighted).

Comment: @DavidFullerton: personally I'd prefer that those unanswered low-voted questions mainly stick to the "unanswered" tab while "recent" contains a much higher ratio of recent, well-voted questions. I really don't mind if that means they are answered already (recently answered questions are often more interesting than old ones with 1000 votes in my experience).

Comment: +1 for the yellow backgrounds. The algorithm (correctly) had every question but 1 in the C# tag, which not surprisingly is one of my favorites, which means the whole page was yellow! The ability to auto-refresh on activity/new items would be nice too.

Comment: @DavidFullerton The problem is that you've created a self fulfilling prophecy.  You stop showing answered questions with 2-20 votes to people, so they don't have an opportunity to attract more upvotes.  It's generally the questions that get their first ~20 votes from some place like Reddit that get the initial attention to be considered "hot", and then it creates a positive feedback loop whereby the initial attention given results in even more attention given, further drowning out other content.  This is effectively putting "what is our best content" in the hands of sites like Reddit.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET It's not perfect, though.  I answer lots of [tag:java] questions, because I answer lots of [tag:jena] (a Java library) questions, but *most* of the stuff tagged with [tag:java] isn't particularly interesting to me, and it just fills up my page. :(  I'd rather have it say "you touch 64% of things tagged with Jena, and only .003% of things tagged with Java, so Jena must be more important to you."  Instead, I think it's more like "75% of your activity is in Java, and %50 is in Jena, so we'll show you lots of Java."

Comment: @Joshua: So you want some Bayesian sauce?

Comment: @Joshua Java is in your favorite tags, so that overrides the magic learning stuff. You could try removing it from there and seeing if that gets you better results. You can see more about what we're predicting here: http://stackoverflow.com/users/tag-future/1281433 It's really trying to figure out "what tags are you more likely *than the average user* to answer?" This modulates for the more popular tags a bit.

Comment: @DavidFullerton Well, it's neat to be able to play around with that, although the results aren't great.  I removed java, c, and latex from my favorite tags, and now the "recent top questions" and "needs answer" each only include 1 yellow background question (i.e., one in my favorites), and it's the same one, actually.  :( The hot list doesn't have any.

Comment: @Joshua we only reach back about 3 hours, so it's possible there just isn't much activity in those tags in that time frame. We're considering reaching back further so we can show more relevant content.

Comment: "just isn't much activity in those tags in that time frame"  You mean the tags I removed from my favorites, or the ones that I have left?

Comment: @DavidFullerton Has that page been abandoned in the months since your comment? The last database update seems to have happened 1.5 years ago.

Comment: @TylerH the page still works and the predictions are used, but the date is incorrect. We'll probably just remove the date since they're updated a different way now.

Answer (score 20):

There is definitely some over representation of old/popular questions. I don't understand why this one came up:

[What does 'synchronized' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085709/what-does-synchronized-mean/23679563#23679563)

It's five years old, but a 0-upvote answer was edited 2 hours ago. The question is tagged `[java]` and `[collections]`. I don't even know the Java language and "tag future" correctly lists it as a tag that I tend to avoid.

On the whole though, it looks good. I'm glad you're working on this, I've been seeing far too many questions on my homepage that border on needing to be closed.

Comment: I noticed the same thing on mine, that any question without one of my favorite tags was an old question with a tag that I "tend to avoid". That seems very odd.

Answer (score 13):

This is mainly in relation to the **hot** tab, which doesn't look that great to me.

- **Put a much greater weight towards favourite tags.**

There's only a single question containing of my favourite tags, while there's a lot of questions containing tags which I have a decent score in, but, in general, things I'm not interested in.

Some of my favourite tags don't even show up in [the "Predicted Tag Breakdown" graph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/tag-future/1711796) **at all**.

My general argument is that I'll favourite things I'm interested in, unfavourite it when I'm no longer, and people who favourite things probably do the same (the rest probably don't have favourites, so this doesn't apply).

- **For favourite tag questions, look at lower scores / older ones, if required.**

This can be considered complementary to the above.

There may not be enough questions satisfying the criteria in the favourite tags, but I think people would still like to see them there, thus lower the criteria as required.

- **Allowing subscription to a newsletter similar to / an occasional instance of this page.**

That's actually all I really want, assuming the above two points get implemented.

[The general newsletter](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters/newsletter?site=stackoverflow.com) consists of probably 95%+ things I'm not interested in (there are [some](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110902/can-newsletters-take-into-account-a-users-favorite-tags-on-that-site) [similar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184891/customized-newsletters) [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169705/can-newsletters-take-into-account-a-users-ignored-tags-on-that-site) [requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102606/filter-newsletter-feed-by-interesting-tags)).

Comment: Its general or I cannot access other's Predicted Tag Breakdown?
Can you access [my graph](http://stackoverflow.com/users/tag-future/2886003)?

Comment: Nope. Presumably we can only see our own then.

Answer (score 9):

Now we have **three** ways of getting "unanswered questions":

- https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered (*Unanswered* button at the top)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=unanswered (*Unanswered* tab in the *Questions* list)
- https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=recommended&subtab=needsanswer (*needs answer* mode of the *recommended* tab)

The UI doesn't make it clear what is the difference between the modes.

Furthermore, now we have **four** levels of menus:

- Stack Exchange, recent messages, reputation, user, review, help
- Stack Overflow, Questions, Tags, Users, Badges, Unanswered, Ask Question
- recommended, interesting, featured, hot, week, month
- recent, needs answer, hot

It's confusing.

Comment: This is just a temporary measure to test out a new idea -- that's why the tab isn't linked anywhere. We just threw it in. The UI here isn't final at all.

Comment: I find the _need answer_ mode much more interesting than the _Unanswered_ tab.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe instead you could consider a "learning" tab

This would be selected **relative to single tag**, and 
it would feature a weighted list of

1. the most-voted,
2. most-viewed,
3. most-starred,
4. most-retargeted by duplication flags, and
5. highest-voted answers, along with
6. the most edit activity.

In theory, these Q&A would form the questions that a person learning the new language / topic could read to learn the most valuable insights.

Answer (score 4):

There is no longer a "featured" tab with bounty questions.  Is that intentional?

Comment: No, not intentional. I'm not sure where that went. The UI is just a hack at this point, not intended to be final.

Answer (score 4):

Definitely feels like too many 'old hot' questions, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706990/is-r-that-bad-that-it-should-be-rewritten-from-scratch) - a closed question from years ago.  Perhaps 'hot questions' can explicitly only include either open questions, or questions that were closed very recently?  I can't say I want to see questions like this, ever, unless I look for them.

Answer (score 3):

For me, anyhow, the **recent** tab doesn't look much different than the main page, except that I see some old questions (judging by number of views) with lots of votes.  There are 26 with >0 scores, and 14 with <0 scores.  If 15 of those 26 are required "flair" (step 3 in the "question"), that's only 11 non-flair answers.  This might be an improvement, but (modulo flair), I'm still seeing more downvoted stuff than upvoted stuff.  Maybe this depends too much on favorite tags?

The needs answer is similar, except without the old high voted questions.  In the entire **needs answer** list, there are 15 with >0 scores, and 16 with <0 scores. Everything else is 0.

Answer (score 3):

"Hot" isn't necessarily hot for me.
[image: What will I do with these questions?]

So, as you can see, the "Hot" tab shows me the question which has got views in Ks and answers >10

These questions are, as you can see, have accepted answers. What's the point of showing these questions to me?

After all, I come to answer here, and what this shows is some famous questions with accepted answers and I'm left to gaze at it!

In my opinion "hot" should have questions which is *new* and is attracting more views and there is *not* many answers as those in my opinion are "hot" to me.

Comment: The intent of "hot" is to be interesting answered questions. "Needs answer" is for finding unanswered questions. There are very few questions with high views and votes that do not have answers.

Answer (score 1):

Many questions in my "hot" list seem to have not the slightest connection to my favorite tags or tags that I have posted stuff in or otherwise visit. For example:

- [Good tutorials on XMPP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092534/good-tutorials-on-xmpp)
  Tags: [xmpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xmpp). I have never posted in that tag and don't follow it at all.
- [How to restrict actor messages to specific types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547947/why-are-messages-to-akka-actors-untyped)
  Tags: [scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala), [actor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/actor), [akka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/akka). I have never posted in any of those tags and also do nothing else with them.
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706990/is-r-that-bad-that-it-should-be-rewritten-from-scratch
  Tags: [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r), [architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/architecture), [rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rewrite). I have one post in [architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/architecture), but that's all there is.

Whatever data mining you are trying to do to find out what I find interesting, it's not working very well.

The only thing I could think of is that I might have edits and flags in all kinds tags. But that's only because people post spam and horribly formatted questions in all kinds of tags, not because I would be interested in those topics.

Answer (score 1):

## Relevance

I would like to reduce the relevance of very broad tags, that could happen automatically by including the amount of questions in a tag into the relevance calculation.

It rates the relatively broad tag [java] higher then my favorites. Thats obviously because I answer a lot of questions in java. The problem here is that my favorites happen to overlap with Java and as I'm a Java person, thats to be expected.

But I'm not interested in questions tagged [java] that's not also tagged with one of my favorites.

Same goes for [mysql].

Currently I can "filter" them optically by ignoring the white lines, but if you remove the highlighting that page has an unusable bad signal:noise ratio.

## Timing

I'd like to have a "interesting time" filter.

My usual approach for finding questions I would like to answer is to open the regular start page and skip to the end. Then I open the last 5 yellow questions.
If they are answered I vote as I see fit. If not I write an answer if possible.
This causes me to see questions that are not so easy that anyone could answer them and so I have time to write a proper answer, yet they are not so overwhelmingly hard that I would need to spend hours researching the answer (usually).

So from my point of view the questions that were active in the last 60 minutes are by nature not-interesting because too much happens there. Questions that were active more than 5 hours ago are not relevant either.