# Can an actual name be required on account creation instead of the default user123456?

Tags: feature-request, new-users

One primary source of questions of the **"do this for me"** kind seem to be the anonymous user123456 accounts. Account creation allowing quick anonymous access may be a primary reason for the feeling SO is rapidly becoming a victim of its own success.  Has there been any consideration given to requiring actual User First and Last names on account creation to create a bit more accountability and hopefully stem the swell of this tide? If a user has to put no more thought or effort into account creation than an e-mail address and a mouse click, that opens the door for that level of effort being reflected in the way many will be asking questions later on.

The goal is to insure that user accounts and the ability to post begin being viewed more as a privilege than a quick anonymous way to get my homework done. Requiring an actual first/last name at least serves the purpose of causing a new user to pause and consider whether he is willing to share his personal information and put some skin-in-the-game before gaining access to the lists. As a deterring side-effect, it also provides an accountability trail for professors or educators to search on student names to determine if the work submitted is in fact work of their own.

Now I understand there is no way that junk isn't put in the first/last name fields, but the psychological barrier presented by that type of requirement may prove useful. As for what ends up in the first/last fields, a dictionary search can probably validate 80-90% of first names and the remainder can be flagged for later review.

This is provided as one idea to add to the mix of things considered on meta-so to help maintain the quality of discussion on the list. No gripes, no complaints, just an idea. So please don't ding me too hard for trying to help.

Edit:

Let me edit and acknowledge as was pointed out that many users go by a handle instead of an actual real first/last name. I think that, as a requirement, is better than allowing a blank that defaults to user123456... The point being to provide an account creation that at least requires some thought and some level of identification beyond the default.

Another idea would be a big **WARNING:** at the top of the new account form that reads **"IF YOU FAIL TO POST YOUR ORIGINAL CODE IN ANY QUESTION ASKED ON STACKOVERFLOW ALONG WITH RELEVANT COMPILER AND/OR PROGRAM OUTPUT YOUR ACCOUNT WILL BE REMOVED."** Probably better than a name requirement and at least provides the admins with criteria to remind or employ against repeat offenders.

Comment: A fair number of excellent contributors use handles rather than their legal offline names. Asking for a full name is too much, I think. And asking for a user who just wants to ask a question to create a handle is likely to be meaningless; she can change it when she's ready regardless. I don't see this helping much with user buy-in.

Comment: You make a good point. But going by a handle is a good improvement over allowing a complete blank that defaults to user123456.... I knew that what I was discussing would not be perfect, but fostering discussion regarding the issue is good and may lead to a fix.

Comment: Requiring a handle means you will have a lot of users named "Batman" or "Captain Basch Von Ronsenburg of Dalmasca" instead of "userXXXXXX", but I fail to see the correlation between that and a behavior change from these users.

Comment: What about allowing a handle for outward list use, but requesting an actual first/last for admin use. I understand there is no guarantee that it will be filled, but the point is to create a bit more accountability in the process from the new user standpoint.

Comment: Hmm... this will not result in more accountability since, as you say, the information cannot be validated and may be omitted in the first place.

Comment: One of the best things about SO is that it doesn't require our real names. It's focuses on content, not users.

Comment: I like it that SO does not require real names. I have my real name in here but I like the anonymity sometimes. It gives people freedom to ask the questions without the fear of a supervisor monitoring the stuff they are posting/learning. It's a great flexibility. Learning can happen at any age, and experience. At the same time there is nothing stopping anyone from keeping their real names - such people even benefit from it. Others can browse their profiles and see how knowledgeable and helpful such people are. That can happen only if you allow it. It helps anonymous users as well in learning.

Comment: Jesus Christ, I wondered where all the **pile-it-on** downvotes had come from. All this for making a positive suggestion. This site still has some work to do. I come from a scientific and legal background, citation and peer-review. The anonymous user sites I've been exposed to were usually under federal indictment for dealing in stolen identities and credit cards. Here, there is no such underbelly. From an academic standpoint, when a man or woman was learned enough to offer ideas and criticism of others, then they had to have the integrity to sign their name to it as well.

Comment: What's the point in building "reputation" if you are anonymous? Any identity (e.g. nickname) is still an identity. But a generic/default username is   the summum of anonymity imho. So the only assumption I can make is that anymous users (e.g. users with a default username) are not on SO to build reputation? We build reputation to get credibility, to ensure good questions and good answers. Not filling in the username, to me, gives me the impression they do not care.

Comment: It has been my experience that most of the quick anonymous accounts can be attributed to people who do not want to be identified as having received help on homework questions they have waited until the night before its due to start working on. I get the nickname use and while that wouldn't pass muster in academia, for SO they work fine, but allowing default anonymous names of user12345... does nothing to foster having members with any sense of community at all. They have no accountability whatsoever. If they take heat under a default name, they simply create another.

Answer (score 8):

Example new user:

> I want to ask a question!...oh, I ***have to*** enter a username?! **I don't have time for this!** Screw it, I'll just use
>
> ```
> alkjfasfslakfjsadlfjsdalkfj
> ```
>
> There! Now on to my question!...

**It's pointless to require a username** to somehow force users to put more effort and thought into the process of asking a question, because a username is inherently irrelevant to that process.

> Now I understand there is no way that junk isn't put in the first/last name fields, but the psychological barrier presented by that type of requirement may prove useful.

**I don't think that a lot of users will care.** People just want to have their questions answered. They're not going to let a username requirement get in the way of that.

### Solutions Being Discussed to Help Alleviate Bad Questions

Just want to point out some possibly more productive solutions that are currently being discussed on Meta (this is not an exhaustive list):

1. [Feedback requested: New "recommended" homepage, phase 1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261138/feedback-requested-new-recommended-homepage-phase-1)
2. [What should the system be deleting automatically that it already isn't?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262077/what-should-the-system-be-deleting-automatically-that-it-already-isnt/262081#262081)

Comment: I guess turning it around, the question becomes "What, if anything, can be added to the account creation process that may discourage or lessen the number of **do it for me** questions that appear on the list?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I think you may be fixating your efforts on the wrong process. *Account creation is not a problem.* **It's the process of asking a question.**

Comment: "It's pointless to require a username to somehow force users to put more effort and thought into the process of asking a question" -- Citation needed please.

Comment: Maybe a big WARNING: at the top of the new account form that reads **"IF YOU FAIL TO POST YOUR ORIGINAL CODE IN ANY QUESTION ASKED ON STACKOVERFLOW ALONG WITH RELEVANT COMPILER AND/OR PROGRAM OUTPUT YOUR ACCOUNT WILL BE REMOVED."** Probably better than a name requirement.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin again, I want to point out that you're focusing on the wrong process. Account creation is not a problem, and bears **little to no relevance** to the process of asking a good question. If you want to throw a bunch of big warning signs in front of users, you'd be better off doing that in the question asking process. Except we already do a pretty good job of guiding users during that process, [even those with tunnel vision](http://blog.codinghorror.com/treating-user-myopia/).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Account removal for a poorly-asked question is unnecessarily harsh.

Comment: @Daedalus yeah, about that, no matter how much some people might want to scare bad question askers away, it's probably more productive for us to **encourage good question asking instead**.

Comment: All, these are just ideas. I welcome the feedback and the barbs and arrows. The site is working fine, there are just a large number of really, really bad posts that reflect no effort on the part of the poster. I don't know how to solve it, but I do know that if nobody contributes ideas in that regard, it won't get solved.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin there are ***plenty*** of ideas currently being passed around. I'll link to some in my answer.