# Why did my question get listed in the "interesting questions" list?

Tags: discussion, interesting-page

I created a question and immediately saw it getting listed in "interesting questions" list.

How do you decide which question goes in "newest questions" list and which one goes in "interesting questions" list?

Comment: Active should be the right word for that page, as Interesting page lists out the post recently modified, answered and if any other sorts of activities happen

Comment: Why did this question get listed in the "Hot Meta Posts" list?

Comment: @NiekHaarman - Probably because it is Saturday, weekend and great weather so only really good programmers are writing code => hardly any questions on SO => even less questions on Meta => even most futile question gets attention

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd The great weather allows for programming outside, which is good :)

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd *less* => *fewer*. The weather has no effect on pedants.

Comment: @ClickRick - I stand corrected. Thank you.

Comment: When you post a question, the inter-galactic forces bring about a change (actually a turmoil) in the entropy of the system which causes some posts to be erratically picked up to be displayed in the hot questions list.

Comment: The algorithm sees you, and finds you lacking. You should feel bad.

Comment: Duh. Because Waffles.

Comment: Would you have written an uninteresting question?

Comment: @ClickRick: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/505/3394

Comment: could someone please answer the question now?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 'Newest' list, is exactly that. The newest questions on the site sorted by the newest first.

There's an entire blog post on the 'Interesting' algorithm https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/. I'm pretty sure that algorithm is still used today.

It is possible for the questions to show up on the interesting list and the newest list. Though with the interesting list being personalized, it may not show on that list for everyone. The newest list should be identical for everyone. Though caching, and when the page was loaded may have factors on differences on that list.

It should be noted that there is a newer home page that may replace the 'Interesting' tab in a beta test right now, with a possibly better algorithm. [Feedback requested: New "recommended" homepage, phase 1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261138/feedback-requested-new-recommended-homepage-phase-1).