# On Meta, how do you get attention for questions without an answer?

Tags: discussion, support, meta

It's not possible to set a bounty on a child Meta in order to get attention. What can I do instead?

For example, [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265471/462608) hasn't received a good answer yet during the past 10 days.

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265233/what-should-you-do-if-nobody-answers-your-question-can-you-repost-it. Though meta is slightly different since there are no bounties here.

Comment: @StevenV I don't have anything new to add and this is not a technical question that I can do a research on and then add new info. Bounties do not work here. That question is clear enough on its own IMO.

Comment: It got attention (it was apperantly in the "hot questions" list), but nobody bothered to answer it well. There may just not be a good answer, or you may just have to wait.

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius Someone linked to [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/) in your original question, which actually seems like a pretty good answer.

Comment: Well, posting another question linking to the old question is one way...

Comment: Another option would be [this way](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261030/1841194)

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius Please remember meta votes are not the same as StackOverflow votes.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Edit.**

Add details, clarifications, screenshots... Remove superfluous asides, boring backstories, that poem you thought was sooo clever at the time but it turns out is making all readers close their browsers. Make sure your title is descriptive and specific.

*Don't* edit just to bump. But remember that edits *do* bump, and if you make a *good* edit then chances are someone will see it.

Comment: I can definitely see a use case to edit just to bump a question. This one for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29209753/is-there-any-exp-internal-equivalent-in-pexpect/30978454#30978454 The given answer is not very satifying, since it claims the pexpect lacks support for a specific feature. However, the question have been asked three years ago and not touched since. There is a chance this now exists.

Answer (score 7):

[Community ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/robotic-overlord) "randomly poke[s] old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention".

While that doesn't put the questions in a highly visible list the way bounties do, it does mean they will continue to be bumped up until they are finally answered.