# Tag synonym request for `lme4` and `lmer`

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

I don't know where else to put this request: if I try to propose a tag synonym pair [lme4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lme4)/[lmer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lmer) I get

```
Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators
```

This is a false positive (`lme4` is *not* version 4 of the package, it's a long story) -- I think I've found something like this on meta before, but can't locate it right now.

`lme4` is an R package for fitting linear and generalized linear mixed models ([G]LMMs); the "4" denotes usage of R's "S4" class system. `lmer` is the function within the package that fits LMMs.

There are 238 [lme4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lme4) questions, 127 [lmer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lmer) questions, and 36 [lmer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lmer) [lme4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lme4) questions.  In principle someone could also decide to use more specific tags for other functions within `lme4` (such as [glmer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glmer), for generalized linear mixed models), but the evidence is that [even questions that are asking about `glmer` rather than `lmer` are tagged with `[lmer]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27924670/warning-message-using-glmer-and-mixed).

Therefore it seems to make sense to keep just the broader tag, [lme4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lme4).

Comment: bump?  does anyone have any other suggestions for getting attention ... ?

Comment: related: [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274888/version-specific-synonyms-2d-array-3d-array-multidimensional-array), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157869/version-specific-synonyms-can-only-be-created-by-moderators), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121457/version-specific-tag-validation-on-tag-synonym-page)

Comment: bump (I don't know if this will make this question active or not).  Does anyone have suggestions for the meta-meta-question of "how do I improve this question so it gets some attention of *any* kind?")

Comment: ... I see [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292259/how-can-i-draw-attention-to-a-question-in-meta) and [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266782/on-meta-how-do-you-get-attention-for-questions-without-an-answer) answer about attracting attention, but neither really works for me ("edit but not just to bump"; "ping a moderator").

Comment: ... it's been suggested that I flag a related question for moderator attention.  I've tried that; I hope it's not considered an abuse of flagging.

Comment: You need to explain further - how many are in each tag? Could there be corner cases where one tag is valid while another is not eg: are they completely synonymous - have you checked for corner cases?  Is doing a syn. possibly going to lose information or selectability in anyway? I'm obviously not a member of the `R` community (although toyed with it briefly) - so I can't say one way or the other, but the more info. you can provide for community feedback and convince the request is necessary - the better.

Comment: And specifically, which tag should prevail? I presume you want `lme4` to be the dominant tag here, with anything using `lmer` to point to `lme4`.

Comment: Thanks for the update; I've [added the synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/lme4/synonyms).