# Version specific synonyms: [2d-array], [3d-array] -> [multidimensional-array]

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

I can't add [2d-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/2d-array) and [3d-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/3d-array) as [multidimensional-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multidimensional-array) [synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/multidimensional-array/synonyms) because

> Failed to propose synonym:
>
> Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators

(the same issue is discussed on SE meta [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157869/version-specific-synonyms-can-only-be-created-by-moderators))

Can a moderator add these?

Comment: I've proposed them as synonyms now which should let the normal synonym voting process happen.