# Is it wrong to try to draw attention to a post I feel should be closed?

Tags: discussion

There is [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567450/not-sure-what-went-wrong?rq=1) where I'm not sure what went wrong. It was asked 3 years ago but is a very poor question. It's in a popular tag (C++) but got very few views (probably as a result of the poor title).

I stumbled upon this question today, and thought about trying to edit it and answer it but I just don't know where to begin. I'm not sure I understand the OP's problem enough to try and edit it into a useful question. The OP has long since vanished and hasn't returned (which isn't to say the question can't contribute to the site)

I feel the question can't be edited into anything useful, and therefore should be closed; however, all I can do is cast a single downvote and a single flag, neither of which will raise awareness and the question will linger for ages. If I could at least edit it that would attract attention but I'm not sure how to edit it (perhaps I could just edit the title?)

My question is: **besides posting on meta, what can I do to draw attention to a question I feel needs to be closed?** I could:

## Edit it slightly, but being < 2k I'd need my edits approved

If I had more than 2k rep, is it appropriate to make an edit to being to draw attention?

## Paste a link into a chat room with no context and let the community handle it from there

Is it appropriate to enter a C++ (in this case because the question is obviously bad regardless of the language) chat room and paste a link asking the community for help?

## Raise a moderator flag

I don't really need *moderator* intervention, I simply need *community* intervention.

I found a similar question on meta: [attracting a crowd to a high-quality question that you would like to see answered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266782/on-meta-how-do-you-get-attention-for-questions-without-an-answer)
 - I *could* place a bounty on the question, but I don't really want to see an answer and I'm not sure whether anyone besides a mind-reader could provide an answer.
 - I don't think I can edit this particular question into anything useful

Comment: re `"Is it wrong to try to draw attention to a post I feel should be closed?"` -- Do you mean like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33512416/hey-could-someone-help-me-with-a-java-programming-assignment-i-need-to-make-a-f)? You will find that this site is littered with a lot of questions that should be closed but aren't. My guess is that the best any of us can do is to vote to close it, and move along.

Comment: I would suggest that based on my belief that the majority of questions should be closed (due to lack of research on s.o.), that no. But start with doing it in comments with reasons.

Comment: There is a flag reason `should be closed...` that you could use. Don't expect it to be handled quickly though, the size of the corresponding review queue is quite large.

Comment: Yeah, stuff doesn't get closed very quickly. Actually, those close votes age away, if I recall... so, your effort could potentially be undone if enough people don't back your vote. I was actually surprised that [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33506666/building-an-image-centric-website-in-node#comment54798034_33506666) from yesterday got 3 close votes.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers

Comment: If the question has so few views, why bother with speedy handling?

Comment: "_is it wrong to draw attention to a post_"... *posts a link to the post in the opening sentence* haha

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Don't edit a question you think isn't salvageable.  Only edit it if you plan to actually salvage it.

While you *could* post a link in chat, most rooms will get annoyed at you pretty quick if you're just spamming lots of close vote requests.  You should really keep this for situations where it's particularly important to close the question and you feel that the question really merits special attention.  Just being one of another several hundred thousand questions that meets the closure criteria but is getting virtually no attention at all simply doesn't make it a priority to close.

Fundamentally there are just more questions that merit closure than there are votes from people willing to vote to close them.  You trying to draw special attention to this one question (that nobody is even looking at, trying to answer, or that could potentially get salvaged) is only taking time/votes away from another newer question that's much more likely to attract low quality answers or where there's a shot of the author actually fixing the problems with the question.

If you flag for a mod it'll just get declined.  You're only wasting a mod's time, and potentially getting yourself flag-banned if you do this too much.

If you see a post that merits closure, vote/flag to close it for the appropriate reason.  Downvote if appropriate, and feel free to comment if you think that you can help the OP improve it (clearly not the case here).

Comment: I fully agree with the second paragraph (only use cv-pls requests for questions that doesn't get closed by the normal process). If you're looking for a room that either accepts or can help in judging the question feel free to ask in the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers).

Answer (score 2):

The reason for closing bad questions is to avoid wasting people's time with them.  Making a lot of noise in any form to draw attention to get them closed will probably take more person-hours than will be saved by not having the question around anymore.

Search results already do a good job of de-prioritizing negative-score questions, so just downvote and move on when it comes to *old* bad questions.

This is just another way of stating Servy's point, which is that aiming for perfection in curating SO is a fool's errand.

Obviously, if a bad question does come up again for some reason (e.g. used as an example in this meta post), that's a good time to get it closed.