# Comment formatting is not working with & (and other special characters) sign(s) after letters/words

Tags: bug, comments, markdown, markdown-rendering

When using the `&` sign in a ***comment***, the formatting is not parsed correctly for example,

> SO is a ***Q***&A site.

The ***comment*** doesn't seem to get formatted as it is supposed to as can be seen in the image below:

[image]

If I add a space before the `&` the ***comment*** is formatted as expected, again, as can be seen in the image below:

[image]

I've made an example ***comment*** in the ***comments*** chain. It seems to be specific to the ***commenting***.

### Update #1

Please see [@TripeHound](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2096401/tripehound)'s [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356694/comment-formatting-is-not-working-with-sign-after-letters-words?noredirect=1#comment515197_356694) for the rundown of broken characters.

### Update #2

It seems that if you have space before closing format then it will not parse the comment as can be seen [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356694/comment-formatting-is-not-working-with-and-other-special-characters-signs#comment517034_356694).

Comment: SO is a ***Q***&A site.

Comment: **Q**&A *Q*&A ***Q***&A

Comment: Testing (all star-star-Q-star-star-symbol): **Q**! **Q**" **Q**£ **Q**$ **Q**% **Q**^ **Q**& **Q**( **Q**) **Q**- **Q**_ **Q**= **Q**+  **Q**[ **Q**{ **Q**] **Q**} **Q**; **Q**: **Q**' **Q**@ **Q**# **Q**~ **Q**, **Q**< **Q**. **Q**> **Q**/ **Q**? **Q**\ **Q**|

Comment: According to [Babelmark](http://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?normalize=1&text=***Q***%26A%0A%0A**Q**%26A%0A%0A*Q*%26A%0A%0A___Q___%26A%0A%0A__Q__%26A%0A%0A_Q_%26A), normal behavior is for this to work. Perhaps the SO Comment Markdown parser has a weird bug in it related to word boundaries??

Comment: Looks like `! " ) - _ ] } ; : ' , . ?` work; `£ $ % ^ & ( = + [ { @ # ~ < > / \ |` don't.

Comment: @TripeHound it would appear your test is inconclusive. Check the source and you'll see this: `<b>Q**£ **Q**$ **Q**% **Q**^ **Q**&amp; **Q**( **Q</b>` and this: `<b>Q**= **Q**+  **Q**[ **Q**{ **Q</b>` among others. I'm not convinced each of those breaks individually with that test alone.

Comment: Just checking one random char: **Q**(

Comment: @Waylan No, it's not 100% conclusive – I didn't try each character in isolation – but it from a couple of tests, it _appears_ that (a) if it was _already broken_, you see two asterisks before the Q. (b) If the current character _breaks_ you see two asterisks between the Q and the character (and it leaves it "broken"). (c) If a character _works_ there's nothing between the Q and it (and it leaves it "OK" for the next set).

Comment: Zero widths don't fix :(

Comment: If you're going to try and bump a question, don't do it with useless edits, please try to edit in something useful or new in to the question.

Comment: @Pang The questions you linked to discuss the main site. [Here is a question that discusses bumping questions on Meta specifically](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266782). </nitpick>

Comment: *Space before the asterix. *