# Comment format seems not to be working correctly

Tags: bug, comments, markdown-rendering

I've just added my last comment to [this question and its comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69361903/how-are-boolean-values-treated-in-excel/69362126?noredirect=1#comment122596272_69362126), but when I try to emphasise "**Product**" in the word "Sum**Product**()", it seems not to work.

Is that a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Hereby a screenshot of the mentioned comment, where you can see that the double asterisks don't format the word in the comment:

[image]

Comment: I am trying to put that word (or part of a word) in bold. Normally this works (as a next comment, I had written "test**test**test" with the expected bold format), but in this particular case I don't see bold text and the asterisks just remain.

Comment: The issue also takes place if the word "SumProduct" is not in code format (you might check the different edits I did on my comment).

Comment: Also, next time you want to report something like this, it's better to include something more than a link to a comment. Comments can be deleted at any time, and whatever "issue" you experience, if it happens at all, can be easily demonstrated with a screenshot. In the comments you link, the word `sumproduct`only appears in code blocks, so the issue is not apparent. Not sure if it works outside code blocks. I'll try: Sum**Product**, **Sum**Product. Apparently it does. So no bug?

Comment: @yivi: you're right, I edited my question, adding a screenshot.

Comment: Maybe it's because of the parenthesis? Sum**Product** vs Sum**Product**().

Comment: @yivi: Indeed: when I don't put parenthesis, the formatting is correct. Is that a bug or is that expected behaviour?

Comment: It looks like a bug but it is so isolated that I wouldn't count on this getting any kind of priority in the next decade.

Comment: Would be a dupe of [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356694/1426539), I think.

Comment: @yivi: it's a duplicate, indeed. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: You cannot use bold markdown for Sum**Product** (). I expect it's due to the "(" being a punctuation character. However, [HAIR SPACE](https://codepoints.net/U+200A) saves the day ;)