# How do I find the "better" questions OR hide questions I'm not interested in?

Tags: discussion, questions, old-questions, rss

The front page seems to show me what's "interesting" based on my tags. Those featured are ones that have bounties on them, etc. The /questions has similar ways of filtering.

For the most part I'm hanging out in the / and firing off an answer to things I know, however I find myself wanting to do some heavy lifting or a challenge, and the unanswered questions tend to just be old questions that probably will never be accepted.

Can I hide/ignore certain questions from my feed or are there suggestions for improving my filters?

Comment: Work a tag.  For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23?sort=newest&pageSize=15

Comment: Wasn't there effort to actually improve the algorithm, though?  I remember hearing about it a while back on the podcast, or seeing a link on Meta about it.  I'm looking for that now...

Comment: Write an RSS based app, filtering out the questions _not of interest_ as these match your personal settings.

Comment: I like that idea.  Pretty simple and I can include my own personal hiding methods.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=recommended&subtab=needsanswer

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat: That's a great answer, how do I navigate to that? I'll likely lose the link some how, and it's just nice to know where to find things.

Comment: @AlanAsher It isn't official yet, so the only way you can get to it is with the link.

Answer (score 2):

About a month ago, a prototype homepage was added at https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=recommended. The ["need answer" subtab](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=recommended&subtab=needsanswer) shows you the questions it thinks you are most likely to be able to answer, so I think that's what you are looking for. You can find more details on [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261138/2846923) Meta post.

<sup>Note: that page will probably become the new homepage at https://stackoverflow.com/ sometime withing the next week.</sup>