# Improve the usage of the show filter for the new navigation system

Tags: feature-request, bug

In the new navigation system there is a filter called `show` with different values according to the tab you are in.

```
New         => recommended, all
Popular     => all time, today, week, month
Need answer => all, need answer, no answer, bounties
```

And there is the special bounty tab which belongs to the need answer tab, this is it's link https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=needanswer&show=bounties, pretty self-explanatory.

I think this filter should be a little more useful. Let me explain how.

Stack Overflow receives a huge number of questions everyday and we rely on those filters to ignore the bad quality questions and to focus on the ones that really deserve attention.

In the `Popular` tab this filter does a good job. A popular question is filtered by a time frame so you can filter out the good old ones and focus on the good new ones.

The `New` it's also good. `recommended` will filter anything with flagging or improvement issues removing some bad questions from the start. Check [Feedback requested: New "recommended" homepage, phase 1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261138/feedback-requested-new-recommended-homepage-phase-1)

> What it's doing is this:
>
> 1. Take the 3000 most recently active questions (same as the current homepage) with `Score > -3`
>
>    1a. If you can't close/reopen yet, hide closed questions
> 2. Filter out any questions with ignored tags
> 3. From the remainder, randomly choose 15 "hot" questions, where hot is just "Score >= 20 and has an answer"
> 4. From the remainder, choose another 81 using an exponential weighted random over your favorite tags.
> 5. Mix them together, sort by recent activity and display

This is impresive work and it makes sense for the `New` tab. The problem is **the last tab**.

Problem 1.

The `Need answer` is merged with the bounties . This is not very intuitive because you will have bounties with answers comming up when you asked for bounties without answers.

**Bug:** If you select bounties and then select no answer all you get is bounties with no answers but there is no difference if you want yo go back to *all the questions with no answer* or the *bounties with no answers*. I guess is because of the &sort=ending filter still being aplied to the url.

**Proposed solution:** Bounties are a category of questions by itself so there is no need to have them together with the need answer tab so filtering can be a little more expressive on them. Eg: tab=bounty&show=recent or tab=bounty&show=noanswer

Problem 2.

`Need answer` if for question that doesn't have a answer marked as accepted or no answers at all.

Paste the following link in your browser https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=needanswer&show=all&sort=votes&layout=expanded&tagFilter=list&tags=javascript

What you get as the first result is ["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background) which has 4424 votes and 15 answers including one marked as accepted so the `all` filter is filtering out, well basically nothing. Remember we are still in the `Need answer` tab so the previous makes no sense.

**Proposed solution:**
If a question have an answer marked as accepted it is definitely **not included in this tab** it doesn't matter which filter combination is. `Need answer` tab is for questions that need answer, period.

Note:

I know [advanced filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) is present but there is no explanation of the new query values there. I hope it will be updates as soon as new new navigation system becomes official.

Comment: You may want to post this at Meta Stack Exchange. Also, while slightly counter intuitive, the "no answer" issue is more by design, and has also been addressed. Look at the tag [`new-nav` at MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/?sort=newest&layout=expanded&tagFilter=list&tags=new-nav).