# Make it easier for users to suggest improvements to low quality questions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, low-quality-posts

Reading [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253358/1427033), the suggestion to tell OPs that their question has serious issues seems like a great idea. Downvoting is incredibly useful but can be vague and confusing to new users. Closing is also important but is the first time for guaranteed, question specific feedback and it can be tough for a new user to dig themselves out of that hole.

Basically, I want to add the capability to quickly provide the OP with feedback about why their question is bad. Now, I know we have comments that can do this, but comments can take a while to type out, especially if there are dozens of low quality posts to deal with. I worry that dedicated users will start out trying to help but soon become burnt out dealing with the flood of people who do this and eventually just vote to close and move on. I'd like to avoid that and make it as easy as possible for a user to suggest feedback.

Something like:

[image: Picture with new button added]

Clicking this would bring up something similar to the `flag` menu with a couple of options:

```
Code Quality - Code posted to StackOverFlow should be well formatted
    and as small as you can make it. This helps other users to read  
    quickly and will allow more people to help you faster!

Grammar/Spelling/Syntax - Good spelling and proper English helps 
    users to understand your question and take it seriously. 
    Consider editing what you've written and you'll get better 
    help, faster! 

Some Other Third Thing - (1) Fix your post (2) ???? (3) Profit!
```

These are intentionally written in an encouraging way that's focused on the OPs because by making it about how we can help them, I'm hoping they'll actually care enough to do it.

After a user does this, OP receives a notification (maybe a standard one, maybe a new, more in-your-face one that goes away with enough rep) that shows what the user said. Clicking on it would bring them to their question in edit mode and perhaps provide them with some links to good examples.

Now this definitely won't solve all problems and shouldn't replace downvotes and closing. However, I hope this will allow for more, less stress suggestions that result in overall question improvement!

*Possible addons:*

-delay closing/notify potential closers that an improvement has been suggested. This keeps the "well, its closed. Screw it. I give up/time to post a new one!" issue from happening before they can respond.

Comment: I would suggest an improvement on this, get rid of that red box and replace it with a hand drawn circle.

Comment: Blasphemy. There's no need to improve Shog9's posts.

Comment: Typing out an appropriate comment doesn't seem to be that much more time consuming that selecting a particular "improvement" reason.

Comment: This sounds great! Why was it rejected?

Answer (score 5):

### The best way to suggest improvement is to show, not tell.

The best guidance you can give a struggling user is highly customized. In many cases, the best help you can give is to edit the post yourself. Poor grammar / confusing sentences? Fix them to the best of your ability (and maybe leave a comment if there are bits you can't decipher enough to fix). Poor formatting? You can fix that, too. If you care about improving low quality posts, **edit them instead of flagging them for someone else to take care of**. There's a reason we allow *everyone* to propose edits; we truly believe that the best content is created collaboratively, and many posts can be improved even if you don't have specific domain knowledge about the content.

When a post has problems that you can't fix with editing, a custom comment is the way to go. If we create a menu with limited options, it is guaranteed that we will not cover all cases. If a user has feedback that doesn't fit one of the pre-defined reasons, they have to go back and type out a comment anyway (or, worse, they just leave the page without any feedback because they've already wasted time reading through a menu that didn't have the right option – or they flag with a reason that doesn't quite fit but they wanted to tell the OP that the post was problematic anyway). Additionally, it's much friendlier and more helpful to get a comment from a real human being than from a pre-populated, generic flag or notice. While we are not a social networking site, our sites *are* communities of people, and we want to let that come through in the user's interactions with the site.

Lastly, to address your worry about users getting burnt out:

**If a user is feeling burnt out from cleaning up low-quality posts, it's okay for them to take a break.** There are millions of registered users on Stack Overflow; no one person has to bear the weight of keeping the whole site clean. Take a break, go for a walk, go on an internet-free vacation for a week...other people will pick up the slack. Every individual's contributions are important, but the site is designed to be collaboratively maintained, so if individuals vary in their activity level, things will continue to run pretty smoothly.

Answer (score 4):

It is vitally important that questions with serious problems get closed *immediately*, not a while later.  In addition to providing the appropriate feedback indicating that the question needs to be fixed before it can be answered, the fact that answers cannot be posted is *an important incentive to actually fix the question*.  When the question author feels that they can get answers without actually fixing anything, there is no incentive to fix anything.  Likewise, it's important to ensure that users are not posting answers to incomplete, unclear, inappropriately scoped, etc. questions because those answers are generally going to be of much lower quality.

Comment: The issue is that I've rarely seen questions being reopened. Hence incentive to improve the question = 0.

Comment: @cmbarbu Questions rarely actually get fixed to improve the problems that they have.  The owners almost always refuse to fix the problems that caused them to be closed.  Of questions that actually get improved, I've almost never seen them have a problem getting reopened.

Comment: Precisely, I improved questions put on hold in the past, trying to address the issue and had 0 feedback on the improvements => there is no point in closing the question *immediately* if anyway it never happens that a question is improved enough to reverser the closing or put on hold.