# Could we make anonymous commenting easier

Tags: discussion, comments, help-improvement

I would every so often enjoy to be able to leave anonymous comments without disconnecting/reconnecting my stackoverflow account.

This would be mainly useful on commenting questions, this would be helpful on the (in)famous question of downvotes but more generally, as pointed out by "[Make it easier for users to suggest improvements to low quality questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262139/1174052)" I often feel like adding a comment to improve the post (typically when doing reviewing work) and I not always would welcome an answer from the poster asking me to solve the question (it happens more often than not).

This is completely separate from the retaliation possible issue: I just don't want my mailbox to be filled with follow ups on recommendations to improve the post.

Edit: To all that say or +1 the "just ignore it it is so easy to do". I could do exactly the same with spam email: it is never the less enjoyable to have spam filters.

Comment: Have two accounts opened in different browsers. Do everything on your main account, and leave "anonymous" comments on the other. This can be useful for commenting on downvotes without fear of retaliation.

Comment: So ignore the follow ups, if you really want to.  That seems like such an extraordinarily easy thing to do as to not require a new feature, and a giant can of worms that anonymous comments can cause, in order to solve.

Comment: There are mountains more than enough crappy, pointless comments around without encouraging more through the use of anonimity. If you have something to say but aren't prepared to stand by it, don't say it. Doesn't "retaliation" get sorted out without recourse to extra accounts and stuff?

Comment: @BillWoodger I'm completely ready to stand by it but when I review I don't necessarily want to follow up on all the pointers I give to new users.

Comment: @Servy I could do exactly the same with spam email: it is never the less enjoyable to have spam filters.

Comment: You've made not much more than 100 comments according to your profile. They look like useful contributions. I'm sure there are people dealing with hundreds of inbox notifications per day. I don't really see your problem. You get the intro to the comment, so can take a good guess at whether or not you want to look at it. If you don't like replying to comments, ignore if there is nothing likely-looking in the intro. If I leave a comment for a beginner and they follow-up because they don't understand, I like to reply, so your method wouldn't work for me.

Comment: @cmbarbu Preventing replies is *radically* different from anonymous postings.  If you want the ability to prevent replies to a particular comment that's *very* different from making it anonymous.  I still don't see how it's at all worth it, but it has far less problems.  Remember that there was once a time where people *didn't* need spam filters for emails, because there simply wasn't rampant spam.  There isn't rampant spam in comments, so people don't need spam filters there (at least for now, \*fingers crossed\*).

Comment: @BillWoodger Thanks for taking the time. Do people with hundreds of notifications a day pay any attention to it? I find notifications a useful tool to be hyper reactive on threads of interest to me (like questions I asked). In this context I am bothered by notifications following up on "maintenance" participation as it tends to interrupt my work flow to check them. Is there any other way to forcibly ignore notifications from a given thread or make notifications to happen only on selected threads (out of the obvious: I ignore threads I don't want to hear again about).

Comment: I know, from a screenshot, of at least one user who simply doesn't click on the inbox. To see how your questions are going, you have the alternate route of going directly from the question. Same with answers. Same with comments you have made that you may be interested in (you'd have to "filter" manually and virtugally to ignore the other comments). I think with anonymous coments, we'd get a lot more comments, and a lot more rubbish comments, because not everyone would want to use them in the way you want.

Comment: You want things to work in a particular way, whilst the voting on this question indicates that is not what other people would consider useful. The way everyone works (differently) would require hundreds of "interfaces" or one which was customisable in hundreds of ways. I only get a small number of notifications. I'd probably work out something different ways of doing things if I got lots. 99% of users won't get many. 1% may get lots (invented figures). It's a tricky one because you are taking time to comment, whereas most people are clicking "do this quickest way, gimme badge".

Answer (score 6):

Stack Exchange does not support anonymous commenting. Just because it cannot be enforced doesn't mean we should turn it into a feature and actually *encourage* it.

Comment: Anonymous for the reader doesn't mean anonymous for the moderators and impossibility to flag it.

Comment: @cmbarbu That won't eliminate all of the behavioral problems created by comments being anonymous for regular users.