# Good first question tag

Tags: feature-request, new-users

GitHub has this "good first issue" tag to help mark issues of the type 'Easy for a beginner to fix but not worth my time'.

One of the strong complaints of new users is that it is so difficult to start answering questions since all of them are so above their level. This would help ameliorate their problem.

Maybe high reputation users

- ones who are allowed to mark them as "good first issue".
- block other high reputation users from answering these questions
- after a while increase in reputation does not matter as much
- use their energy in moderation and other important tasks
- be awarded for those non Q&A tasks too

Yes I have gone through

[Make it easier for users to suggest improvements to low-quality questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262139/7952027)

[Stack Overflow for the non-noob](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258663/7952027)

[Filtering questions by "difficulty" / "level"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253338/7952027)

[Thwart publishing duplicate and low-quality questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253305/7952027)

Comment: This isn't a game. The purpose is to build a library of high-quality answers to programming problems. There's no reason for tricks. If someone can post a good answer, and is willing to do so, then they should.

Comment: "mark issues of the type 'Easy for a beginner to fix but not worth my time'." That feature already exists: Closing as a duplicate.

Comment: New users are as likely to be experts on technologies as old-hands. To **answer** questions what you need is to be knowledgeable about things **outside** Stack Overflow, not to be an expert on the site rules.

Comment: Indeed what Jeanne says. Beginner questions are very likely already answered. Probably numerous times. If they are not already answered... the question should probably not have been asked to begin with. This feature would just make it even less likely people look for duplicates and promotes creating yet another duplicate answer.

Comment: It seems that you didn't take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) but it contains useful information about the purpose of SO: "With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming." A library of programming knowledge, not a free help desk where volunteers are paid with reputation for debugging someone else's code. While debugging questions are on-topic (when they fulfill certain standards), they are not necessarily the most useful contributions to SO's knowledge base.

Comment: "*One of the strong complaints of new users is that it is so difficult to start answering questions since all of them are so above their level.*" this doesn't seem like an issue worth working on. Because it's a misleading XY problem at best. The issue *isn't* that users can't answer questions. It's usually that they feel they cannot contribute. And/or gain reputation to unlock more site features. Both of these are *different* problems than "cannot answer questions". But the way the reputation system currently works, that's how they are reflected.

Comment: Users can contribute by doing curation work - voting, flagging, editing. However, only editing gives *some* reputation out of these and only a limited amount. Rep is used to unlock more site features but IMO it's a bad metric to solely use for privileges. A user who has done 1000 accepted edits is surely more qualified to make an unsupervised edit than a user who just reached the 2k rep with no edits under their name.

Comment: @JeanneDark I fail to see how your last comment relates to my question. I am not talking about allowing low-quality questions to survive.  I am saying that let the moderately new users concentrate on answering the good first issue questions.

Comment: So when an expert comes across a new, good question that is not a duplicate, and they know the answer and assume it's easy (well, it wasn't easy for the respective OP), they should refrain from answering it? I do not see how this can help further SO's goal of becoming a high-quality repository of programming knowledge. What if the expert is only on SO to answer questions and not interest in spending their free time on moderation? What if they answer anyway (they could already refrain from answering now)? What if their answer would be better than the low-rep user's one?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Stack Overflow is not GitHub. Here, everyone can contribute to the knowledge base regardless of their reputation points.

Everyone hunts for good questions. If you can find a question that hasn't been answered yet and is written clearly then there's nothing stopping you from answering it. There is no advantage that high-rep users hold over low-rep users*. If you know the topic and you know the answer then you can share it with others by posting on Stack Overflow.

Starting on Stack Overflow is difficult due to the quality that we expect from all contributions. Once you take the tour and read through the help section, you should be ready to post your first answer. Amassing the reputation to gain moderation privileges is a more difficult task as you need to spend much more time looking for questions to answer.

The points you listed in regards to high-rep users are valid and should apply to all users. It would be good if some of them took the time to moderate existing content instead of answering the same topics again and again. Maybe some incentives would be good. Most users with some experience on this site should already know that simple questions are most likely duplicates and they can vote to close them. Gaining reputation for closing as duplicates has been proposed before.

<sub>* An exception is a protected question. Users must have 10 reputation points to answer these highly active questions to prevent spam.</sub>

Comment: "The points you listed in regards to high-rep users are valid" - disagree with that (and only that), because it really is not an aspect specifically tied to high-rep users. People hunting for reputation for the sole purpose of having more reputation points is a human being trait, not a high rep user trait. Because let's face it... we treat it like money.

Comment: @Gimby Does my edit help?

Comment: Yes definitely, but you already had my upvote ;)