# How to assert a bad question

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed

This is Exhibit One in the fight against bad questions:

[How to test code that writes to stdout?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26144614/102937)

I closed it as "Unclear What you are Asking."  It was reopened by five community members.

OK... Seriously?

What is it about this question that is so morbidly fascinating that *five community members* would vote to reopen it?

Comment: Didn't you know that you can earn more rep reopening questions than by closing them, and that people love to upvote answers to really poor unclear questions because that answer might possibly be correct and at least they tried and we don't know that it's *wrong* after all and that run on sentences are fun?

Comment: @Servy: That sentence is nearly long enough. Please demonstrate more effort.

Comment: It's not a stellar question, but I understood it and it might be useful. It's asking how to test that the output to user (stdout) is correct

Comment: Questions like this being on topic and "ok" are what drives away a lot of people from answering questions. Sorting through these to find meaningful questions is not fun.

Comment: This is subjective. The original question was immediately clear to me. You're right, it is morbidly fascinating!

Comment: The original form of the question was horrible, however, it's current form after all of the edits is a pretty useful question. it's amazing what a few good edits can do to a poor question.

Comment: @enderland Actually, I think it's all that eagerness to close these questions that drives a lot of people away from answering questions. Admittedly, it's not an amazing question, but I'd guess some of the initial wording may only have been unclear because of a possible language barrier. Nevertheless, it seems fairly clear that the OP was trying to test the behaviour of the `print` function (i.e. testing the output of `printf`).

Comment: @Bruno The solution is obviously to make it so that only the people who want to see the bad questions get to see them... [Which is WIP, but probably not an easily solvable problem.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253351/allow-users-to-optionally-filter-out-low-quality-questions)

Comment: Language barrier.  The day China gets its act together is going to be a sad, sad day at SO :)

Comment: I strongly agree with @Bruno. I see far too many questions closed far too fast, and get frustrated as a result.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: Without examples, your broad statement is just a platitude.

Comment: BartoszKP seems to have fixed the question up into something workable and probably even useful.  Isn't this what we're supposed to do?  (Never mind that it seems any solution will be a hack involving `fflush` and `dup2` or something similar.)

Answer (score 25):

The question, in a broad sense, seems pretty reasonable to me when worded: "How do I unit test an operation that prints to the console?", or even better "How do I verify (assert) what was printed to the console in a unit test?"

Obviously the answer is to redirect STDOUT to a file (as the answer notes), and for all I know this question was a duplicate. "Unclear what you are asking" though? Its perfectly clear. Moreover, for those that don't know you *can* redirect STDOUT, such an answer could prove very useful.

A hard question, an interesting question, no. A *clear, useful* question, possibly.

Note that I would agree that the question in its current form *could* be construed as "Unclear What You are Asking?" (though I understood it just fine) without the comment thread that clarifies it quite well.

Comment: I edited the title, removing the word "assert."

Comment: @RobertHarvey The title has definitely been much improved from the original. It is now much more obvious what he is asking.

Comment: For me the title now is perfectly clear.

Answer (score 9):

You probably focussed too much on the word "*assert*" in the question and didn't try to understand the rest of it. If you replace "*assert*" with "*test*" or "*verify*", the question immediately makes more sense. It seems otherwise fairly clear that the user was looking for what to put within the `test_print` function to test the `print` function above.

I guess the OP might not be a native speaker, but someone who has learnt the word "*assert*" through its programming usage.
Unfortunately, "*assert*" in a programming language doesn't really mean [what it means in English](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/assert):

> verb (transitive)
>
> 1. to insist upon (rights, claims, etc)
> 2. (may take a clause as object) to state to be true; declare categorically
> 3. to put (oneself) forward in an insistent manner

When you "assert" that an actual value is equal to an expected value in programming (e.g. `CU_ASSERT_EQUAL(actual, expected)`"), what you're really doing is testing whether actual and expected are equal, and producing an error if this is not the case. If you wanted to "*declare categorically*" that "`actual==expected`" (and if you wanted that state to be true from then onwards), you'd just use an assignment (`actual = expected;`), yet it's of course not at all what unit tests do.

In that context, someone misusing "assert" to mean "test" or "verify" is quite forgiveable.

Comment: The OP insisted in multiple comments below the question that what he wanted to do is *code an assertion against stdout in his test framework.*   He wasn't asking for a general solution beyond that.  Replacing "assert" with "test" or "verify" changes the meaning of his question.

Comment: Hard to say now that most comments have been deleted. I don't think it changes the meaning of the question, since "assert" in the context of a unit test does precisely that: test or verify.

Comment: Comments reinstated.  Enjoy.

Comment: Thank you. Reading the comments, I understand "*assert stdout*" as "test the content of stdout" or more generally "do whatever those `CU_ASSERT_` macros do to variables, but with stdout instead". The wording is far from ideal, but it seems fair enough, at least sufficient to define the problem. Of course, the OP might not know unit testing well enough to formulate these concepts with perfection. Nevertheless, it seems a reasonable question to ask. (Remember it's always much easier to phrase a question perfectly if you already know the domain and the answer well, but then you wouldn't ask).

Comment: @Bruno The fact that you need to make assumptions about what the OP actually wants, especially combined with the fact that other people interpreted it to mean different things, *is exactly what makes the question unclear*.  Closing the question, and providing an opportunity for the author to clarify what it is that they really want, is what makes the question potentially useful and answerable.

Comment: @Servy It seems that many of us found it clear enough. I don't disagree with the logic of your argument, but those who read questions should also be expected to make a little effort to try to understand them, if they wish to attempt to answer these questions, otherwise, perhaps they should just move on... Closing just prevents those who've understood from answering and the OP from getting an answer. I'm not convinced that really helps anyone.

Comment: @Bruno You found it clear enough *even though your interpretation of what was being asked differed noticeably from the "very clear" question other people thought was being asked*.  The fact that it seemed to clearly mean one thing to you, and clearly means something else to another person, means that the question *isn't* in fact clear.  Closing the question allows the question to be clarified and improved so that by the time each of these people who "clearly" know the answer are answering the *right* question by the time they go to answer

Comment: @Bruno When a question actually gets answers from 3 different people who thought that the question clearly meant three different things it creates a real mess.  It makes it far harder to actually clarify and improve the question as doing so is going to turn two of the three "clearly correct" answers into very wrong answers, those answers will confuse future readers, etc.

Comment: @Servy Again, I don't disagree with your point in principle, but in this particular case, there aren't thousands of possible interpretations. There's only 2 functions in there, one called `print` (with a single `printf` statement), the other one called `test_print`. It doesn't take a genius to make more than an educated guess as to what's expected of `test_print`, especially in the context of unit tests (and using the word `assert`). A bit of good will when reading a question does no harm. Nitpicking on the fact that the question isn't phrased perfectly is a bit over the top here.

Answer (score 6):

I don't have any kind  of "answer", but I do have some discussion points. I think what we have here is a difference in acceptable-risk thresholds when mapping the text of the question onto an intent.

For those who voted to reopen, it seemed perfectly clear that "*assert stdout*" was shorthand for "*assert some equality predicate for the contents of stdout in a unit test*". This mental substitution was easy for them because such a substitution was a reasonably strong contender for the intended meaning, and it seemed (in their assessment) substantially higher than any other possible alternative. It wasn't a risky substitution.

Those who decided to close it were not prepared to make that mental replacement, either because

- it didn't occur to them, or
- that possible interpretation did occur to them, but their tolerance for risk in misinterpretation of the question's intent was too low to allow them to accept an interpretation of the question

This last point is significant: the close-voters may have considered not only their own threshold for misinterpretation risk, but also took into consideration how the question would be viewed by all future readers of the question.

Comment: Speaking as the person who initially closed the question, you can see in my comments below the question several attempts to ask the OP to clarify his meaning.  It seemed clear to me that the OP did not understand what an assertion is.  It also seemed clear to me that he thought a simple code substitution was possible, and did not understand the inherent difficulties involved in what he was asking.  If he'd stated even once in plain language what he wanted to do, I would have edited his question for him and left it open, but he stuck to his "assert stdout" wording.

Comment: Far from being an isolated case, this example is highly illustrative of the difficulty we encounter with people who ask perfectly plausible questions, but who are not equipped to understand the answers we give them.

Comment: Finally, editing the question so that it more clearly states what you believe his intent is is not *mandatory,* but it's certainly strongly advised (if, in fact, you actually do know for certain what the OP's intent actually is).

Answer (score 4):

I agree with all the answers here - this question seems all right. However, at first sight I downvoted everything in the linked thread and voted to close. Only after rereading few times I did understand what it's all about. So I took the liberty of editing the question again - I did change it quite substantially, but I believe I didn't change its meaning. I'm not a native speaker, so I hope it is better - otherwise perhaps someone could improve it further.

Comment: Note that the question has been edited a few times since it was originally posted... You might want to check the edit history.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yeah, I've noticed. Other editors did improve the question, however I feel they've been too conservative and wanted to retain too much of the original form. In general this is of course very good and recommended. However, I think that not in this particular case (I won't go into edit wars of course if someone decides that my edit was too much :) ).

Answer (score -3):

I would have understood the original, and edited about as others did to help it along.

Not only that, you unilaterally closed it after it [had been edited to be coherent](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26144614/3) *(vs. its [original state](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26144614/1))*.  I want to be clear I'm speaking about moderators closing questions...not communities *voting to close questions*...because I think the bar is higher and a line was crossed here.  It's a poor choice to pick on, and especially to then choose it to complain on meta as a candidate for "why you shouldn't be challenged...because the question *obvioulsy* should be closed by one individual with power".

Last I checked, a question doesn't have to be fascinating--morbidly or otherwise--to be welcome and kept open.  It just has to be a on topic and answerable.  In the spirit of "innocent until proven guilty", moderators should have the same attitude with closing.  A one-button click to close a reasonable question from someone willing to participate in refining what they mean is bad karma.  This was a plausible question from a non-native English speaker, edited to a reasonable question, then *closed by one person*.

Bear in mind that people can help out in different ways.  Some people might be reading questions more to learn, and see these as opportunities to "give back" by clarifying the question...even if they don't know the answer.  It's always nice to help people along with their "programming English" (even if StackOverflow [has started smoking crack](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/02/cant-we-all-be-reasonable-and-speak-english/) on that particular issue).

For anyone bothered by even the *original* question, may I suggest loading up [Harder Better Faster Stronger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gAjR4_CbPpQ) and play it loud.  Look over the question and the history.  Is it not a futuristic-feeling, cool experience of seeing a "new way" of how dynamic improvements can be made in real time?  Versioning and collaboration...from low-quality to quality-enough-to-be-useful for future visitors...

Telling people they suck and beating them with a mallet doesn't have that futuristic feeling.  By comparison, I think that's been around for a pretty long time.

Comment: You should not keep a question open just because it might possibly be editable into an acceptable question.  If the question, in its current state, doesn't meet the standard, then it should be closed. If it gets fixed up, it can be reopened, but it shouldn't be open *until that actually happens*.

Comment: @Servy Where did I say "keep a bad question open"?  I said a reasonable question which may have quality issues but can be improved.  This is an example.  I understood it, and several other people did.  Was it well written?  No.  Was it somewhat ambiguous and our guesses might be wrong?  Perhaps.  But "question isn't perfect" isn't a good close reason.  This was fine and quickly improvable. Robert thought it worth complaining on meta that people besides the OP improved it because they understood it and reopened...and he considers it effort wasted on the OP. Others, including me, disagree.

Comment: And the fact that it's improvable is what means that it has a decent shot of being reopened *if it is in fact improved*.  Closing a question doesn't mean that it cannot possibly *become* a good question.  Closing a question means that it's not a good question *right now*.  When a question cannot become a good question you *delete* it.  You *are* asserting that we should be keeping bad questions open right in the comment that you're saying you didn't say that.  How ironic.

Comment: @Servy I define "bad" as off topic--not as "written by someone who isn't an English native speaker and is having a hard time expressing themselves".  "You aren't speaking English well" is not a close reason and shouldn't become one.  I see a lot of *actual* bad questions and tell people why they are bad in comments.  This wasn't a "bad" question under my definition.  Should I flag your comment for not knowing how to use the word ironic?  Should we give people some leeway?  Do you want to live in the world where we don't?

Comment: Then your definition is not in line with the site guidelines.  You're using the definition of what should be deleted to determine what should be closed, while the two are radically different.  If a question is unclear because the author is having trouble expressing themselves then the question isn't a good question and it is *very important* that it be closed *as soon as possible*.  That doesn't mean you need to stop there, it means that if you feel the question can be improved you should take the time to clarify the question, improve it such that it's *not* ambiguous, and *then* answer it.

Comment: @Servy Edited my answer to show it *had* been edited, and it was closed anyway at that time.  I'm going to stick with saying this was a bad close, the community agrees, and I hope more attention is drawn to this issue...because there are real problems for moderators to tend to, instead of complaining to meta when they are overruled for crossing the line in unilateral application of close-power.  Their one vote does it, and that's a higher bar than those who are just voting with others.  More benefit-of-the-doubting-yourself.

Comment: I was surprised to see Robert bring this up on Meta as well, because by the time I saw the question it seemed reasonable, but I think you're digging a little too deep to make this a serious case of mod power abuse. Note especially that the revision Robert was looking at when he closed it was all but certainly [the _second_](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26144614/2); the timestamps of the close vote and Deduplicator's second edit (which you've linked as "edited to be coherent" -- and I agree that the question is pretty clear at that point) are about 30 seconds apart.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Right...it's not the closing...but getting irritated about being reversed and not feeling a decent enough thing resulted from it.  Asking what is so fascinating about the question--as if a question has to be "fascinating" to be on the site or justify a community disagreeing with a unilateral action.  The reaction errs on being "in the spirit" of moderation...and that's the only "serious" thing, to the extent that The Internet is Serious Business at the end of the day.