# Would there be the possibility of adding filtering according to reputation?

Tags: feature-request, filtering, custom-filter

I considered that for people browsing to answer questions it might make it easier to be able to filter according to rank, e.g. someone looking for a challenging question will want users with high reputation, and someone looking to answer run-of-the-mill newbie questions to filter for low ranks. I wish to make it clear that I am not in any way suggesting an apartheid of ranks, but an easier interface by which to query for questions.

So let's dig deeper and have a more elaborate query that compares the user's prowess in the topics they're asking and answering and judge by the votes. I admit that it would seem that there's no final solution to such a query,
yet perhaps that might encourage the SO to deliver a more flexible query system. Just a thought.

Comment: eh, sure, it's possible, but it's pretty unlikely SO the company would implement such a feature. Besides, a user's reputation isn't necessarily an indication of the difficulty of the questions they ask. Most high rep users i've seen that routinely ask question actually ask rather simple ones.

Comment: @Kevin-B You're right. But that doesn't mean I'm wrong, either. It's just another parameter to query with, and IMO a potentially useful one.

Comment: Simple's in the eye of the beholder. Consider Programmer X who's racked up tens or hundreds of thousands of points in questions and answers about the C programming language. Now they're figuring out Python. They're going to have some pretty low-end questions. Hopefully they know the site well enough to find their answers without actually having to ask them, because that's the whole point of Stack Overflow, but if they do have to ask...

Comment: Same feature request on meta.SE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152353/756727

Comment: Related in the sense that your actual problem is filtering by difficulty of a question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253338/2745495

Comment: When I was new to SO I could probably have answered almost any C# question due to my direct domain knowledge, but my knowledge with other programming languages was lacking, why should I have been prevented from answering questions I knew the answer to because I had just heard of SO?

Comment: [Herb Sutter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1661064/herb-sutter) has been a member for over ten years. He has less than 2000 rep. He is a widely acknowledged C++ domain expert and communicator. We'd be stupid to filter his contributions in any way.

Comment: @user4581301 So when you get down to it the reputation serves no purpose but to filter users out of specific things? Is there a rulebook that altruisticaly defines these rules? I know that the no-commenting < 50 rule has definitly been questioned.

Comment: I don't like most of the reputation walls and can cite many users to whom they should not apply and many users who routinely abuse the power the reputation (or gold badge) grants. I particularly don't like the no comments under 50 rule. I understand it's necessity, though I would prefer that we eliminate the problem it solves, spam, by eliminating spammers. Preferably in a brutal and painful manner.

Comment: There is almost zero relationship between rep and question quality, in my experience answering 2k questions and voting on tens of thousands of posts over the past 7 years or so. There are many ways to reach high reputation levels without commensurate quality, like asking one lucky question years ago that happened to become canonical and heavily SEO'd, or asking a ton of mediocre questions and using the site as a help desk, since it takes 5 downvotes to negate an upvote and you get rep for accepting an answer. Many upvotes on questions indicate "I have the same problem as you".

Answer (score 12):

We don't want such filtering because reputation isn't something you should base your decisions on.

Reputation doesn't mean that that person will ask a good question or a challenging question. A high-reputation user can still ask newbie questions. A brand-new user can ask a very challenging question.

Don't pay attention to reputation when answering questions. Just answer the questions that you think would be a good addition to our knowledge base.

Comment: For example, there are plenty of users with high reputation solely due to asking a _lot_ of questions.

Comment: (and the part Ryan skipped for obvious reasons <strike>a lot</strike>some of such users still could not ask non-duplicate or somewhat well researched questions)

Comment: @Dharman So what about a more elaborate filtering according to previous reputation of the user on the topic? That at least will solve the oldie-come-newbie problem.

Comment: @ShmuelGreenberger The what problem? What do you mean previous reputation?

Comment: @Dharman Sorry. See the edit. What I basically meant was that if I see that the person asking a question in a certain topic has been judged by the community as a worthy questioner or answerer in that same topic, it would be a decent indicator that the question is a good one. As regards a newbie starting out, you're right. There is no community judgment to here or there. I hope I'm clearer now.