# Contention: should points be completely eliminated on SO?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Alex' comment below brought to the fore inability to summarise, thanks for that Alex.  Here's a summary:

a, **'real-life' works perfectly without points**

{i.e. all of the supposed benefits of 'points' are trivially achieved in a situation without points, and this is a completely obvious aspect of human interaction}.

b, **all the everyday major pro-sumption sites works perfectly without points**

{i.e. all of the supposed benefits of 'points' are trivially achieved in a situation without points, and this is a completely obvious aspect of human interaction}.

c. **all the everyday major pro-sumption sites shy away from points because of the problems points create** [for example, on SO]

{a few comments have been made: "*who cares* what the biggest most successful X does?!". In any field, the thinking "*who cares* what the biggest most successful X does?!" is puerile. If the SO "points experiment" was a huge success, we'd be saying the other guys have screwed up, indeed they would have changed already.}

d, **no points ==> all the problems of points eliminated.** (obviously enough)

e, SO is amazingly moribund, **it should on principle consider BIG changes** to fix the points problem, rather than considering tinkering. {there is a twin benefit; fixing the problem AND fixing the moribundness per se.}

---

(A) **"There are no points in real life"** but it's easy in real life to know who is worth listening to.

Ask a technical question on any QA site and it's completely obvious who has a clue, even if everyone's totally anonymous. Think about experts you admire in your own speciality. When I see a post by a top expert ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9402041/294884) if you're not a graphics programmer), the person **certainly doesn't need a "112k" after their name to obviously be a leading expert**.

(B) Other online "communities" (Wikipedia etc) have no points, but operate fine.  "Case closed."

(C) SO is, obviously, a company that makes money to pay salaries from prosumption, like other huge commercial operations such as tripadvisor.com.

Those other "prosumption-coms" **of course, obviously, shy away from "points"** (again, tripadvisor, amazon, youtube etc - many of the major properties of our era) - often at worst they will do something like indicate that a user has contributed N reviews. On trip advisor I'm a "top reviewer" ("yellow star!") and that's as close as they get to the geeky madness of points. On amazon they strongly discourage any back and fore in comments, and so on.

**NOTE** if you're not familiar with Toffler's term "prosumption" - one of the basic business models of the today: a company actually tricks the con-**sumers**  in to being **pro**-ducers of the company's wealth - here: [Toffler explains Prosumption](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lqsGfF7iLSw) (Amazingly, he coined the term before it actually happened.)

(D) All of the many abuses of, problems with, and indeed **the flat out hokey wankyness** of "points!" would be eliminated at a stroke.

(E) And perhaps the most important point......

almost on principal, **change is good**: major shake-ups (disruptions, disintermediations) are how the internet should work.

**SO is now moribund, like any Western Democracy.** (*Humorous evidence* - recently, almost unbelievably - **like a cliché** - the SO organisation was having a serious discussion about tinkering with the design on the profile page - "how big should the logo be?!" and so on, exactly like any late-stage failing megacorp. So funny it's not even funny.)

At small, fast moving companies (especially doctom startups), the whole mission can be changed on a dime. In the very early days of SO this sort of conversation could have happened ... *"What to do about this points stuff? Let's try totally turning it off for a few months, like at other prosumptions. I'll change the database now and we'll see what happens..."*

---

## Contention Recap:

---

a) **There are no points in real life.** You can instantly tell who's an expert.

b) Prosumption corps are a major, obvious, and now well-understood part of today's economy. It's a basic of prosumption corps **that you avoid points systems like the plague**.

c) Tinkering at the edges of any problem **is incredibly boring and unsexy**.

Contention - totally and completely eliminate points on SO.

---

*Footnote* - **every meta on SO that suggest radical change, gets heavily downvoted**.

This is part of the phenomenon of SO being incredibly moribund, and, points-oriented users.

I believe this post is **the most extreme suggestion ever made on SO** (any other candidates?)

---

Note - this post is about eliminating "user points".  As discussed with AD7 below,

Regarding voting on answers, that is unrelated to users having points. Allowing anyone to "thumb up" anything is an absolutely basic aspect of any site on the internet today, of any prosumption site from youtube to Facebook to amazon. (Note that it is the actual logo of Facebook.)  It's how the internet and social interaction works.

The anomaly of SO having "user points!" is a (you might as well say childish, "geeky", hokey) exceptionalism in the prosumtion internet industry.

---

## "Point-less Stackoverflow" technical challenge!

Even though no other major prosumer businesses have points systems, there are a number of sensible "pro" arguments for points systems.  (Example, "enables moderation", etc.)  Below, a couple blokes suggest one benefit of a points system is "on a question, knowing who is worth listening to." I feel this is really odd as it's a fundamental human talent (rooted in language and social skills) to be able to trivially do that superbly.

The "scientific proof" would be making a web page version of SO where all names are masked by an XXXX. Perhaps some web-genius can do this.

[image]

(TBC, in my opinion it's pointless setting out to "prove" this as it's fully obvious, but there you go.)

Comment: One of the great strengths of SO/SE is its bottom-up, earned-privileges community moderation (editing in particular). How do you propose that fit in with the elimination of reputation?

Comment: @josh - wikipedia works "fairly well" and any anonymous anyone can edit anything.  right?  secondly; what you're saying is in some ways not real: I see no editing to speak of on SO. where's the editing?  people sometimes vote to close, that's about it, and the whole process is miserable.  what other "earned privileges" are you referring to? what?

Comment: One of the most annoying things to deal with on the internet in general are people who can clearly and convincingly express **a bad opinion/advice**. The rep system is one factor in allowing users who don't know each other personally to determine who to listen to; and it's self-correcting since persistently touting bad/wrong advice or answers doesn't result in long term reputation to fool new users; and users who've put the effort in to accumulate a sizable reputation _usually_ have advice worth listening to and act accordingly if proven wrong.

Comment: I'm afraid this is totally wrong AD7. On the contrary, I often see technical posts that are **totally wrong** made on SO by people who chase high points.  Conversely it's commonplace to see excellent expert advice from someone who is clearly an expert, who has no interest in the site or points.

Comment: I only need to find (and boy would that be easy) one post which is totally right to contradict that POV; I didn't say all long-standing users on SO are right. You do see users who demonstrate they are experts in their field and have low rep - are they the rule or the exception? (rhetorical). Are they disadvantaged by the points system (sort of - but only in that their activity is restricted/moderated)? Are other user losing out because of the points system affecting this minority (IMO no)?

Comment: I'm not sure what to say.  Your sentence *"One of the most annoying things to deal with on the internet in general are people who can clearly and convincingly express a bad opinion/advice"*  ... That is completely wrong. The opposite is true; it's a non problem, indeed that's why every pro-sumption dot com avoids points (even accounts, naming, personalities) like the plague.  All you need to do is glance at the internet - surely you've used the internet (e.g., booked a hotel room, bought something on amazon, etc)

Comment: I'm not really sure what that means =). When I'm booking a room I'm not listening to someone ask a question or reading their answers - where's the connection? Anyway: If there was no reputation there'd be no need or motivation to vote on questions and answers. If there were no votes on questions and answers - how can users broadly identify good/bad questions or compare answers?

Comment: Alternatively: You've been around some years, and our experience doesn't look to overlap much. Let's say I start iphone development and ask a question. I get two completely opposing answers (or 20 varying answers) - one by you one by another user. Each answer at face value is well written and superficially appears to be correct. Both have a ton of comments. How could I evaluate which is the right answer at a glance? Wouldn't you find it at least frustrating if I accepted the other dude's answer who joined the site yesterday and IYO blatantly doesn't know what he's doing? Rep works.

Comment: "When I'm booking a room..." the entire travel industry now runs on prosumption review sites, difficult to understand what you're saying.  "Anyway: If there was no reputation there'd be no motivation..." the universe's social media ("you've heard of Facebook! wikipedia!" etc) is utterly packed with presumption content, no points involved; you 'can't stop' people posting on the net.

Comment: "...ask a question. I get two completely opposing answers..." the whole point is that problem simply doesn't happen anywhere, you decide by judgement who's right; in the incredibly rare case of a technical disagreement here on SO the points mean nothing, zero.  Regarding **voting on** answers, that has nothing to do with users having points.  Just let anyone "thumb up" anything (like any site on the internet).  It's how the internet and social interaction works.  The bizarre anomaly of SO having "user points!" is a (really, childish, "geeky", hokey) exceptionalism in the internet.

Comment: `the universe's social media ("you've heard of Facebook! wikipedia!" etc) is utterly packed with presumption content, no points involved;` - praise the lord SO&Family **is not** a social media. Congratulations for the unpopular post of the week!

Comment: My points are not wanky. So you can't have them.

Comment: @brasofilo ... (1) SO is social media.  (2) SO is a prosumption site.  A social media business, or presumption business, makes money from, consumers creating content. **The raison d'etre of stack overflow or youtube or tripadvisor, is that, you can make money from consumers creating content.** There is no other purpose or reason for the existence of these things.  (For sure, wikipedia is different because it is charitable, as I understand it. The principal is the same.)

Comment: So, you wanted to replace Gamification with exactly what? Borification?

Comment: I'm by far not a "points-oriented" user but still downvoted your question. While you're right that there are many users who got their points by farming easy questions and are far from being experts (e.g. there's a recent 10k user in the python tag who's good at entry-level things but has little to no knowledge of more advanced topics), simply removing rep doesn't solve the underlying issues (one of which is people that have no clue getting upvoted by people having even less of a clue). Also, we tie moderation privileges to rep; without it, you'd have to invent a completely new scheme for this.

Comment: There are points in real life. SO is real.

Comment: braso - gamification is silly, so get rid of it. we're all engineers trying to build stuff to feed our families.  using that ridiculous word ("gamification!") is ridiculously appropriate, just get rid of it: it's plain silly.  l4mpi , there are zero advantages to what you say: see the five points in my post up top, "case closed".

Comment: "there are zero advantages to what you say" - That's my line. You fail to make a compelling argument that eliminating rep would improve anything, except for "they (FB/Wiki/etc) do it too" and "all these rep problems will be gone" (which ones? IMO most things you could cite here are problems with the userbase/newbies, not with rep). And please NEVER use Wikipedia as an example of a good community as it has tons of problems and is also dominated by petty arguments about deletion and what's not noteworthy - guess what, influential musicians are not considered noteworthy, but 2 girls 1 cup is.

Comment: The points can stay, but people should not look at the points all the time but at what makes them happy like answering good questions or whatever...

Comment: "*There are no points in real life. You can instantly tell who's an expert.*" - Interesting. What is your plan to proof that hypothesis?

Comment: Well, a +1 for getting so much attention.  You obviously enjoy a heated debate and do not lack the intellectual wit to have fun with people who may or may not take themselves way too seriously.  As for me, I guess I'm childish, because it tickles me to no end every time I get an up-vote and it saddens me greatly when I get a down-vote from some judgmental person who thinks I deserve it.

Comment: Seriously gang, OK, **so if my "radical" idea is crap** ... can anyone else suggest RADICAL ideas?  Personally I have a gut instinct that a radical technological solution **relating to duplicates on QA sites** is the answer to everything.  But I haven't figured it out in my head yet, and there's no more red in the cave, so I'm screwed.  Come on, the internet is about insane disruption.

Comment: "There are no points in real life. You can instantly tell who's an expert." Did you proofread this? That can't be what you meant to write.

Comment: Hey Jens and Bill. "What is your plan to prove that hypothesis?" When I ask a question, I can easily tell who's talking as an expert, a specialist in the arcane speciality under discussion. The point number after their name means nothing. Indeed, this is exactly what you do as well. When talking about one of your technical specialities, it's inconceivable you're influenced by the "111k"! after the name. You're both suggesting that when you ask technical question, you (personally, guys) are influenced by the "111k" after the name: which is risible. For proof:

Comment: ....for a psychological "proof" of such a basic, central, human skill (much like say "detecting motion in field of vision") as how well we judge expertise in a field by evidence of arcane knowledge, language skills, command of detailed facts .. **you'd simply do this:** Someone technical make the QA pages presented **with all the names removed**. Like when you do a blind tasting with the bottle in a sleeve. (This psychological exercise would be as worthwhile as, say, "proving" that teenagers want to have sex.)

Comment: BTW, I'm sure there's a web-tech expert around who could set that up: **"pointless stackoverflow"** (How clever is that?)  So you'd be able to browse around on SO, BUT, every name (q, a, comments) would be masked with a XXXX.  It would do this http://goo.gl/MaJujR to all names on the page.  I'll chip in €50 by praypal to anyone who can do it, that's 50 so far who'll add?

Comment: **"Pointless stackoverflow"** has to be one of the cleverest names I've ever came up with and I used to like name hamburgers  :-)

Comment: {BTW it goes without saying that the "high rep - crap answer" phenomenon is an everyday feature of SO sites, particularly the less hard-science SO sites. You get the (amazingly socially dull) phenomenon of eager! students-of-a-field! pointhookers! who endlessly bend over backwards to answer questions by using dictionaries, etc.}

Comment: Note - I completely understand the argument (made by others above) that the Points System is good **for reasons such as**: making more pro-sumers work as moderators, deleting swear words, editing, closing bad questions and so on. That's a rational, arguable, "good reason for a points system". It helps SO make more money by enabling moderation, etc. But the concept *"a points system helps you decide which answerer is an expert"* is not sensible. You guys asked for "how to prove" this (again: it would be like "proving" teenagers want sex); I've provided the total solution (and e50! :) )  XX

Comment: If you want to try out a point-less, badge-less SO, you can use this userscript. http://pastie.org/9225352

Comment: Wow, that's amazing @n00neimp0rtant. Indeed it's **the only factual contribution on this page.**  Perhaps you could make it an answer?  I"m going to figure out how to use user-sciprts.

Comment: I don't consider it to be an answer, myself, especially because I am neutral to the system given its merits and its flaws. But you proposed an interesting idea, and I wanted to see firsthand how it would change my own perception of SO answers.

Comment: Having read the original post your arguments against having a points system seem to be a) real life doesn't have points therefore we should have no points, b) wikipedia doesn't have points therefore we should have no points, c) tripadvisor doesn't have points therefore we should have no points, d) it's quote 'flat out hoky wankyness' and e) change is good. France has good cheese doesn't mean we abandon our laws for their laws, change the official language to French and eat snails. Change for changes sake isn't good either, take for example genocide.

Comment: Hey alex, it couldn't be clearer.  I've inserted a summary of a, b, c, d, e in the top of the question.  (If you're additionally saying "my language is colourful" - whatever, sure.)  (Your comments about cheese etc.: I'm unclear what you're parodying or what the point is.)  **I will edit into the post a simpler summary of the five points now.** Thanks for the idea of a summary.

Comment: Regarding "Change for changes sake isn't good either" that's a very general bromide. The point is that SO is **exceptionally moribund** and there is everywhere evidence they have entered fully-senile late stage "tinkering" insanity like any Western democracy or most large corporations.  (For example, the almost unbelievable couldn't-make-it-up-as-a-parody "debate the size of the logo image! on the profile! page" affair.)

Comment: Maybe I wasn't so clear with my analogy; your first 3 points explain examples of where no point systems exist as a reason to move to a no-point system. I was attempting to convey the idea that adopting their way of doing things won't necessarily improve things hence cheese is good in France (Wikipedia, Tripadvisor is successful) but that doesn't mean we should all adopt the French lifestyle (emulate features of Tripadvisor or Wikipedia). I'd be more inclined to side with you if there was some hard fact indicating that point systems are bad.

Comment: 'Change for changes sake' does get used often but it's completely apt in this instance as there's no hard fact or reason as to why we should change. Regarding the colourful language; that's completely fine with me I was simply going through each point you were making and just thought that describing something as 'flat out hokey wankyness' doesn't exist as an argument against something. You mentioned 'the problems' as well but I'm not familiar with these problems you'll have to enlighten my foolish self in that regard as I haven't seen these abuses of the point system first hand.

Comment: _"I feel this is really odd as it's a fundamental human talent (rooted in language and social skills) to be able to trivially do that superbly."_ This. I can't do this. I do not have this ability/talent/skill. Me=(good programmer+poor language and social skills). Like the cliche. Just ask my exes. And I can't be the only one. Or there wouldn't be a cliche. What do you propose we do?

Comment: If you don't want reputation, go to a different site.

Comment: This is the funniest diatribe response to a downvote I have read...lol - needed that laugh

Answer (score 51):

> You can instantly tell who's an expert.

This statement is so obviously false that it's ridiculous. Sure, if *you're* an expert you can tell who else is, but that ignores everyone else in the world. We're not just here to help other experts.

> Even though no other major prosumer businesses have points systems...

This statement is also false. [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/) has karma points. Even if it were true, that statement would be irrelevant. The fact that Stack Exchange is doing something different than Facebook and YouTube is not necessarily a bad thing.

Finally, points on Stack Exchange are not just used to tell who is an expert in a particular topic. That's not even their *primary* purpose. Reputation points track your participation in the community and [unlock privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

Comment: *.. for a psychological-test "proof" of such a basic, central, human skill as how well we judge expertise by evidence of arcane knowledge, language skills, command of detailed facts .. you'd do this: make the QA pages presented with all the names removed. Like when you do a blind tasting with the bottle in a sleeve..*

Comment: @JoeBlow Yes, I read that the first time. Repeating it doesn't make it any more relevant. Just because you can pick which flavor you like best in a blind taste test, doesn't mean you can tell what answer is correct on a programming site. Everyone has taste buds and knows how to use them. That doesn't make them wine experts.

Comment: Check out that awesome gravatar! Uh, that was simply an example of doing a "blind test".  ("blind tests" are common, as you know, in psychological  testing.) I'll edit it out.  I just repeated what I said, since you just repeated what you said.  the problem is we have two competing "it's just obvious"s. My thought experiment of doing an obvious psychological test, points, how obviously obvious out how obviously obvious, uh, my obvious is. (Your latest comment that non-experts don't have this ability, is also (obviously!) way wrong - heh.)

Comment: @JoeBlow I didn't just repeat what I wrote earlier, I greatly expanded on it. This isn't just a case of two competing "it's obvious" statements. Your suppositions are easily refuted with counterexamples. There's absolutely no basis for your claims.

Comment: Hmm, if you're talking about the "humans can easily tell who's an expert" issue: The expanded information you've added is (A) that to you, your view is "obvious". And (B) you've raised the concept that "non-experts" can't tell who has a clue. {Do you now agree with me then, that, experts can trivially tell who has a clue?) Secondly (on an other point), you mention Reddit (excellent example), in contrast in contrast to my examples (facebook, amazon, etc). In your final para. you repeat what I already mentioned in the comments.

Comment: @JoeBlow I never tried to refute that an expert can tell who has a clue. In fact, I already said "Sure, if you're an expert you can tell who else is..."

Comment: [Friend 1 clearly identified Friend 2 as the expert](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=rm%20-rf%20%2F) - you seem to be in favor of giving users no means to identify _that_ kind of help @JoeBlow.

Comment: @JoeBlow: it's hard for people with no expertise to recognize experts (that's the whole point behind snake-oil vendors). You should read, in particular, about the Dunning-Kruger effect.

Comment: @JoeBlow The wine tasting analogy is a false one. People can tell what wine they enjoy tasting, not which wine is more expensive, or which wine is considered by the wine community to be better, or which wine contains antifreeze. Similarly, when two people who both know more than you do about a topic are arguing, it can be _very_ difficult to know who is right, and who is simply willing to say anything to _seem_ right, or who is simply more eloquent, or who is better at quoting documentation out of context.

Answer (score -13):

This is an interesting proposal.  I actually agree, and voted up.  Points are necessary for the underlying privilege system, but we really don't need them displayed on the page.

Just the other day, I did my duty and told somebody who left unconstructive comments to please stop.  They told me, "You have 131 points.  Come back when you have 20,000".  Really?  I had to post the FAQ entry on comments to get the guy to shut up.  I had been a member of that SE site for 7 months at that point.

Voting up answers is good.  That's a good use of "democracy".  But giving publicly visible credit for answers only encourages gaming and elitism.

Comment: Nothing wrong with a bit of elitism, you newb.

Comment: `I did my duty and told somebody who left unconstructive comments` usually people who say they did their duty etc. (and don't link) did not do anything, or what's most likely in this case is the nonconstructive comment was towards someone who did not care to use google search or the docs.