# "Uhhh... what?" kind of answers

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1443297/507674

> ```
> 8587321344/1024/1024/1024
> ```
>
> is wrong.. correct is below..
>
> ```
> 8587321344/(1024*1024*1024)
> ```

Anyone with basic math knowledge knows that these operations are exactly the same.

Yet the answer has a +7/-0 score and is accepted.

This just leaves me scratching my head. How on earth did this happen, and how should this be handled? It's a no-op answer, but with such a high score I don't think downvoting will help much, and being Accepted I don't think commenting to say "you're wrong" will help either... Not to mention it's like 5 years old now (just noticed).

Comment: *six years* and only 7 votes? It *is* surprising there are no downvotes on it though.

Comment: And +7 is **not** a high score. Not for an answer 6 years old.

Comment: I am not familiar with PHP semantics with large integers. Perhaps that's at play here? What happens with such numbers on a 32-bit system? Perhaps `(1024 * 1024 * 1024)` produces a large integer and thus *large integer / large integer* gives correct results? There is more than meets the eye here and perhaps the answer **is** correct, and you wrong.

Comment: Since the question ask about divisions and how to get the calculation formula right, the answer is valid.

Comment: @MartijnPieters A numeric literal that is too big for an int will be treated as a float, and `float / int` is treated as `float / float = float`, so either way you would have the float issues.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: right, in which case the answer is indeed nonsense, if only for missing a proper explanation as to why the author thinks it is the right answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm slightly more baffled as to why the OP thought it was the right answer...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: but the formula is mathematically *no different*.

Comment: Computers don't observe common math rules.  Like integer division truncates the result and truncating once instead of three times of course is liable to produce a different result.  Best way to pursue a question like this is, you know, ask a question about it.  At SO, not here.

Comment: [It's a PHP question, all of them are "Uhh... what?"](https://eval.in/108854)

Comment: If people would remember and laugh about the mistakes I did 5 years ago like what's happening here... huh never mind, anyway I think I got an issue here about the site, we need to find a way to maintain old posts.

Comment: Anyone can explain me why does this question have the score of -6???

Comment: @nicael because everyone already knows what to do with incorrect answers.

Answer (score 8):

> How on earth did this happen,

The title of the question is "convert bytes to GB in php". When searching for that particular task, this question may come up. Regardless of the topic of the question or strangeness of the answer, the answer *does* describe how to convert bytes to GB. Those searching for a way to do this likely found the answer helpful.

> and how should this be handled?

By:

- Leaving a well-written (e.g. not bold or all caps...) comment asking for clarification.
- Down-voting the answer if you feel it is truly not helpful.

*Not* by:

- Calling it out on meta, which generally leads to unfortunate bandwagoning, which at 161k you should know.

Other ways to handle dubious answers, which do not necessarily apply to your specific example:

- Flagging as NAA if you truly believe the answer is [not an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-it-is-not-an-answer), which this one does not qualify as, since it does attempt to answer the question.
- If you are unsure how to handle an answer you find questionable, search meta first for related discussions. For example, for more information on what to do with *wrong* answers, you may also be interested in [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266028/improving-an-accepted-but-wrong-answer).

There are many answers on SO that are less-than-great. We have the voting and comment system to take care of these. Use them. Meta is not the place to deal with these types of answers<sup>†</sup>.

---

<sup>†</sup> My thoughts on Patrick's comment below:

> ... bringing this discussion to meta is exactly what he should do. This is about answers that are not salvageable and should be deleted, but the high upvote count prevents that. It is a totally legit question.

Valid points; but there are two things that, in my opinion, should be considered:

1. More research into existing topics (e.g. I found [How to handle historical, highly upvoted but completely incorrect answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255198/how-to-handle-historical-highly-upvoted-but-completely-incorrect-answers)) on this matter could have been done to find existing discussions. This is expected of any question, including ones on meta.
2. This question, which is *generally* legit (re: non-salvageable answers that cannot be deleted due to upvotes) could have been asked without a specific example to jump on.

At first I was not sure why this question received so many down-votes. After I thought about it more, I liked it a bit less, for the given reasons. In the end I gave it no-vote.

Comment: I do agree on most of your answer, but bringing this discussion to meta is exactly what he should do. This is about answers that are not salvageable and should be deleted, but the high upvote count prevents that. It is a totally legit question.

Comment: @PatrickHofman At first I was not sure why this question received so many down-votes. After I thought about it more, I liked it a bit less, for the above reasons. In the end I gave it no-vote. However, two points to consider: 1) More research into [existing topics](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255198/how-to-handle-historical-highly-upvoted-but-completely-incorrect-answers) on this matter could have been done before asking this, and 2) a question about non-salvageable answers with upvotes could have been asked without a specific example to jump on.

Answer (score -14):

Downvote the answer, leave a comment (use bold face, all caps if necessary) and move on. 6 other votes and the *high* score becomes negative.

And don't think about flagging the answer or it will be declined as:

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an
>   altogether wrong answer

Comment: **WHY, OH WHY WOULD YOU SUGGEST USING BOLD FACE AND ALL CAPS IN COMMENTS? THAT PRETTY MUCH GUARANTEES NOBODY WILL READ THEM.**

Comment: I almost wanted to flag your comment @FrédéricHamidi :)

Comment: Downvoting with an appropriate comment is the right thing to do. I recon leaving a bold and all caps comment below the answer is better than bitching about it on meta SO.

Comment: @Patrick, oh, you're free to do that, it would be a good meta-example of what would happen to such a comment :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Sorry, I can't flag since I upvoted it.

Comment: @PatrickHofman not that you should, but _technically_, it is currently [possible to flag a comment after upvoting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/236522/165773)

Comment: @gnat: That's new for me. Thanks.