# How do I answer a question in a comment?

Tags: support, rejected-edits

In [How to cleanly verify if the user input is an integer in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14900490/how-to-cleanly-verify-if-the-user-input-is-an-integer-in-ruby/14900559#14900559), a valid question is asked in a comment to the accepted answer.

> How would we use this piece of code though? –  camdixon Jan 27 '14 at 21:29

I have 41 reputation points, so I cannot write a comment. But I can edit the answer, to provide a better solution in context of both the original question and this new question.

However, my suggestion was rejected. On dodgy grounds. So now the accepted answer stands alone. And future users cannot see the context.

What's the appropriate cause of action? I could have improved the knowledge base that is StackOverflow, but I am not worthy of the comment section.

#### Duplicate?

The reason this question is not a duplicate, is the bizarre situation where comments are forbidden land, but I can edit and / or answer. I am asking what the correct protocol is, because my edit was rejected by 2/3, on very different grounds.

Comment: You can add another answer and refer to the comment?

Comment: Ok. Is that the acceptable way of doing it?

Comment: Of course, why not? You can always add additional information as answers, even if there's an accepted one. You need to see it from the viewpoint of a future researcher, who will find this information useful.

Comment: Ok. I've just seen many late answers being badly received, so I thought that was frowned upon. I **did** see it from the perspective of a future researcher. They will look on the accepted question, and see the question in the comment. And see that it is unanswered. I don't think they will scroll. I didn't.

Comment: It doesn't depend on the question's age, but on the quality and usefulness of the late answer. If it just repeats information that is to be found there in other answers, it will get downvoted.

Comment: see also: [Improving an accepted but wrong answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266154/839601)

Comment: So, it's been marked as a duplicate, despite it not being so. And the referrals lead to other supposedly duplicates. You really should take the time to read, before judging.