# Similar to bounty, accepted answers should be chosen automatically after some time

Tags: discussion, feature-request, accepted-answer, old-questions

Every search, I come across questions helpful to me, but without accepted answers. I upvote the answer I see as the best solution, maybe to help OP choose, but then I see the post date is 3 years ago.

**Does SO notify OPs after some time that they have answers waiting?**

It makes me wonder whether *any* of the answers actually helped OP... Did he find a better solution himself? Did he forget to edit the question, which could lead to better answers? In reality, I know OP probably just forgot about his question.

If this does not happen already, I think **SO should implement an automatic accepted-answer**, based on time AND votes received. The user whose answer is chosen should not get full rep (**similar to automatic bounty rewards**).

Then, if OP checks his question, he has 2 options.

1. Agree with the community and reward the user the remaining 5 rep.
2. Choose a different accepted answer, and reward that other user full 10 rep. (I think the original answer should keep his 5 points rep.)

I've seen other meta posts ask about questions without accepted answers. Yet those refer to commenting/reminding OP to accept *their* answer. This discussion is meant to be more general, and less biased, if that's even possible.

Comment: Accepted answers are for the OP to decide. How could anyone else do it?

Comment: ah no, there are way too many examples of popular up voted answers being completely and utterly wrong and no actual correct answer to the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly. It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for him or her personally, but not every user comes back to accept an answer, and of those who do, they may not change the accepted answer if a newer, better answer comes along later.
>
> [What does accepting an answer mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

How does the system know what's [right](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292087/what-is-the-prevalence-of-accepted-or-top-voted-answers-that-are-actually-intrin) (recent example)? Highest voted doesn't always mean it's correct?

---

"Accepted" means that the provided answer worked for the asker. It does not mean it is correct. It certainly doesn't mean that you, as another person with the same problem, should blindly accept it as correct. This is especially true if the answer is years old.

It is your responsibility to evaluate the solutions provided and see if they work for your project as well. A green checkmark doesn't remove that responsibility because it worked for someone else.

Comment: Could you possibly add these questions to the "review" page? Therefore allowing people with sufficient reputation to review the questions and decide personally whether the answer is sufficient enough for closure? Perhaps task moderators with the job if abuse would arise?