# How to deal with highly viewed questions with security flawed answers

Tags: discussion, support

I stumbled across an old, but familiar WordPress issue and eventually found the correct answer again after digging through *loads* of dreadful advice on the Internet and here on Stack Overflow:

[The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020186/the-uploaded-file-could-not-be-moved-to-wp-content-uploads/32144990)

Most of the answers across the Internet recommend setting 777 permissions on a web folder. In this case this is addressing the symptom of the issue, but not the root cause.

And it is insane.

This question has been viewed nearly 10k times. I found [another question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292087) asking something similar, and the responses were essentially 'time will fix it'.

However, if advice is potentially dangerous, should they be flagged as well? Or should I hope people ignore the incorrect answers and let downvotes work their course?

Comment: You can comment about the problem/downvote/post a better answer. But flagging? Why? Mods aren't supposed to take care of technical inadequacies like this, AFAIK.

Comment: I feel there is a difference between 'technical inadequacy' and 'propagating dangerous advice'. One doesn't deserve a flag, the other im not quite sure - Hence the question.

Comment: Same sh*t, different pile. Mods are there to moderate the community, not the answers. Put a comment as a warning, downvote, post a better answer. Maybe bringing it up in a chat room can give some more visibility and therefore more downvotes (don't take my word and CHECK IF IT'S APPROPRIATE first. I am not a big chatroom user, so I am not certain this is acceptable in all chat rooms)

Comment: Meh - it's WordPress, who cares?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [How to deal with highly voted answers with security vulnerabilities?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158741/how-to-deal-with-highly-voted-answers-with-security-vulnerabilities). Loosely related: [Problematic PHP Cryptography Advice in Popular Questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293930/problematic-php-cryptography-advice-in-popular-questions)

Answer (score 4):

Downvote and leave a comment why it's a flawed answer (if one doesn't already exist or upvote the existing comment).

You could leave your own new answer, or upvote another answer that is better.

You shouldn't flag these flawed answers since moderators are not here to moderate technical accuracies. The community should be able to downvote/comment on these flawed answers and take care of them themselves. If for some reason the community doesn't take care of them, well, too bad.