# Mod seems to have deleted all the answers to a supposed duplicate

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I had answered this question [Generating a random password in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101956/generating-a-random-password-in-php/6101969?noredirect=1) a looong time ago.

I based my answer off the users question and nothing to do with security etc, only based off how the user asked the question.

For some reason there was a decision to DELETE all of the answers on the question, I am not sure why fully.

The only comment we have is from a moderator:

> Visitors should be getting potentially-security-related information from a source that can be updated properly, not a question that's closed to new answers. I'm deleting the answers to this duplicate so that visitors will read the answers to the open question instead. (If this question is ever reopened, answers will be undeleted.)

Well now the question is reopened, and the answers in the supposed duplicate anyway are just as "insecure"

Can these old answers please be reinstated, lock the question if you must, but there is no reason to delete old high upvoted answers that actually answer the original question.

Comment: Agree - deleting answer just because it *might* contain insecure code is wrong. For this we have downvotes, comments, etc.

Comment: Reading the comments, there also appears to be an issue where someone has been editing the answer even though they know they are not supposed to do that.

Comment: Yep... That has been happening as well. A user was injecting their own opinion into the highest upvoted answer.

Comment: That edit added something like _"Security warning: `rand()` is not a cryptographically secure <...>"_. Which should've been a comment left for the OP of the answer, so the OP can decide whether or not to include that.

Comment: I agree that deleting the answers is a bad idea - I would rather see the whole question deleted. It's the first hit on google for `php generate random password` and both the second and third hit follow the same approach as OP does in the question but do offer working code. And the results from the fourth hit onwards are arguably way better than the top ones.

Comment: @l4mpi the code in my answer was just as "working". NO password generators are secure. That is why you are supposed to ALWAYS ask the user to change the auto generated password.

Comment: I think that the Mod didn't really consider how their actions may extend beyond just that question - this is a collaborative community, btw.

Comment: **Note:** I've locked the post to avoid the meta effect while discussion is taking place

Comment: @Neal can't see your answer as it's deleted, but still, it's a crap question as can be seen by the crappy answers it already got in the short time it was reopened. Thankfully it's locked for now.

Comment: ok people. @JeremyBanks fooked up ;-) It's ok it happens... :-)

Comment: @PeeHaa: We figured out that much already. Now it's just a matter of getting the answers undeleted.

Comment: @JonClements what do **you** think should be done here?

Comment: It's a horribly wrong answer (made worse by the many upvotes), but that's usually not considered a good enough reason deletion by a mod.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: `rand` is safe enough if the source string is scrambled. Then, attackers can `rand` all they want. All of these _"It's unsafe!!!"_ screams are solely based on the _assumption_ the attackers knows how you generate your passwords. (If they do, you have bigger problems than those passwords) Sure, it may not be the "best" answer, but that doesn't make it _"horribly wrong."_

Comment: @Cerbrus The attacker knowing your source code is a standard assuption in security, and if your copied from stackoverflow that assumption is clearly true in practice. The proper approach is simply using a csprng, like `/dev/urandom`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298642/mod-seems-to-have-deleted-all-the-answers-to-a-supposed-duplicate?noredirect=1#comment217005_298642

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Like I said, if the attacker can see your source code, you have bigger problems. Like the attacker also having access to your DB (through your source code), and as such being able to mess with your users, any way.

Comment: @Cerbrus Perhaps you publish it as an open source application. Or perhaps the attacker simply took the code from stackoverflow and checked the passwords your service generates match its outputs. @.Neal A CSPRNG generates stronger passwords that a typical human, but they're usually not memorable.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Database passwords aren't stored on source control sites, right? Treat the "seed" for the password the same way. Then you an have your open source code, with a simple PW generator.

Comment: What I don't get is why you would object to a disclaimer in your post stating that it isn't cryptographically secure, and linking to a better resource. You basically say in the comments that you don't care about the security because you just fixed OPs code, but you also don't seem to care about informing other people about the security implications (remember your answer is not just for OP). Changing the answer so that it's more secure (e.g. telling people to shuffle the alphabet if they copypaste the code) or at least pointing to a secure answer would make your answer better, so why not do so?

Comment: @l4mpi: Imo, the edit should have been a _suggestion_ to the author of the answer, instead of simply editing it in there, advertising some other answer. I agree with the warning, though.

Comment: @Cerbrus given the fact that the answer is more than four years old and OPs reaction to comments about the security problems is literally "Whatever ^_^", I can certainly understand why users would just edit this into the answer by themselves. Especially given the fact that this is the top google result for many search queries about generating passwords in php.

Comment: Hm, I can agree with that, @l4mpi

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can anyone provide a single documented instance of a website hack occurring through a weak random password generator? This seems more theoretical than practical. I don't dispute the theory, but I do question how practical of a concern it is.

Comment: @ChrisBaker Yes, actually, but I don't fully understand the statute of limitations on computer intrusions. ;) Instead, have an academic paper https://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-12/Briefings/Argyros/BH_US_12_Argyros_PRNG_WP.pdf

Comment: @ScottArciszewski Interesting, thanks. I'll have to give that a read at lunch :)

Comment: @Neal - I think you'd come across a better man if you re-instated the link to Scott's answer and/or other more secure newer answers. The site was intended to be collaboratively edited to fix stuff like this. It also  reduces friction for folks bumping into this post and getting a more secure solution rather than scratching heads and wondering where "look elsewhere" is.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what happened or why a moderator was drawn to this 4+ year old post, but it looks like an attempt to remove posts with security issues.  Typically moderators don't make technical judgments on answers so for the time-being, I've gone ahead and undeleted the answers to the question.

The rule of thumb is if the answer contains "security issues", then [downvote, comment, or edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293959/426671).  If [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101956/generating-a-random-password-in-php) is in fact a duplicate of [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356289/php-random-string-generator), then we should merge the 2 question so we don't lose valuable information in the answers.

Related:

- [Problematic PHP Cryptography Advice in Popular Questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293930/problematic-php-cryptography-advice-in-popular-questions)
- [How to deal with highly voted answers with security vulnerabilities?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158741/how-to-deal-with-highly-voted-answers-with-security-vulnerabilities)

Comment: And here we see *Sula nebouxii* in its natural habitat, doing what it does best: moderating the moderators.

Comment: I left a comment, it was ignored. I applied an edit, it was reverted and the author yelled at me for editing their post. The thread was locked, I could not submit a better answer.

Comment: To adress the possible duplicate: One of the questions just asks for a random string, which has by itself no security implications. The question discussed here specifically asks for a password. A password is usually used in a more sensible context. The currently top voted answers in both questions have no mention of the (theoretical) security implications of using a non cryptographical secure rng and an edit adding a disclaimer that this answer is potentional unsecure was removed by the owner. Maybe it would be best to force that disclaimer into the top voted answer, but leave it be otherw.

Comment: @ScottArciszewski your comment was not ignored. I just have not really been active on stack overflow for almost 2 years. Editing my answer in a very interesting way made me come back online. Instead you could have just pinged / flagged the answer for a moderator addressing your concerns.

Comment: We don't really do this "pinging users repeatedly until they show up again" thing on SO - especially not when Scott left his original comment just *last week*. And this sort of thing isn't for a moderator to handle.

Comment: @BoltClock I was implying that if Scott really thought there was something inherently wrong, some moderator could have jumped in, which it does seem like that _is_ what happened, but with weird results.

Comment: @Neal But the point is that moderators here aren't for dealing with technical problems in the posted answers, it's the community (including Scott) that deals with that. He gave you a chance to deal with it yourself. You didn't (for a perfectly valid reason). In that case, editing is appropriate.

Comment: This is a pretty weird misjudgement by the deleting mod, especially given that he [campaigned on an "undelete the things!" plank](http://stackoverflow.com/election/6#post-29528400). He also seems to have [forgotten the difference between editing and answering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101956/generating-a-random-password-in-php/6101969?noredirect=1#comment50475021_6101956). I hope that this is, and remains, a unique incident.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Remember that mods are human and can make mistakes when making decisions on stuff. That's why we have Meta so these things can be hashed and and possibly reversed.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I've generally been against deletion from the position that more harm is caused by removing content than leaving it around. However, security is the where that's most often untrue. Very many users have been harmed by poor security practices, and we as an industry need to get our act together. Unmaintained resources are a frequent source of bad information, and I strongly feel that we should get rid of them in particular. (Closed is usually unmaintained -- it's rare/discouraged to edit-in better answers.) However, taking unilateral action on this question was too overzealous of me.

Comment: I can't say that I follow your thinking on this, @JeremyBanks. You had the ability to reopen the question. Editing the answer(s) with a remark about security -- perhaps a less obtrusive edit than Scott Arciszewski's -- also would have clearly been the path of lesser harm.

Comment: @JeremyBanks And a dictatorship on what is and isn't secure is **not** what StackOverflow is about. Your moderator privileges were not given to you for this purpose. The community decides on what is and isn't secure. You certainly have an *input*, as part of the community, but that input does not extend to the control of whole sets of questions and answers to force forward what is, effectively, your individual opinion. Although I *completely* agree that security is important, you could have answered that post with facts and figures (and I still think you should) to aid in this regard.

Comment: @Jimbo Moderators act according to their best judgment every time they make use of their moderator tools. As a moderator he has input that is binding for the community, unless overturned by the balance of powers (the community votes against it or other moderators disagree). There's no dictatorship at play here; let's not cast this in a worse light than it really is. Like bluefeet has already stated, moderators are humans, too. They all make mistakes.

Comment: @TylerH They are *expected* to use their best judgement; in this case, the moderator did not as evidenced by the reversed outcome. The moderators do not control the community, they help shape and guide it. Just a simple mistake, I'm sure, and I think the outcome of this was a positive one. We can leave this now.

Comment: @Jimbo A reversal in outcome does not indicate that a moderator used anything other than their best judgment.

Comment: @TylerH Fair enough, it merely illustrates that their best judgement was not up to scratch in that individual case. Regardless, this is now sorted.

Comment: Delete a piece of insecure advice and a reader will secure their fish today, comment pointing out the insecurity and they can secure their fish forever. Or something.

Comment: @JonHanna inb4 "Commenting doesn't actually help because they get burried"