# Should we do something about the answers to "Remove Server Response Header IIS7"?

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-question, security

[Remove Server Response Header IIS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178831/remove-server-response-header-iis7) is a popular question that deals with a security topic. It has a number of answers with a different approach, but according to the comments, some of these answers are questionable.

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7338448) can cause freezes according to a comment, and can cause issues with async requests [according to official documentation](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/web-development-best-practices/what-not-to-do-in-aspnet-and-what-to-do-instead#presend). It's also unclear if it works for static files.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1201377) suffers from the same issues.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12615970) seems to be OK.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14893226) says that the first two do not work for bad requests, although a comment disputes that claim.

There are a bunch of other answers to the question.

Given that the goal of the question is to improve security (I'm researching the subject because of a report by a security firm on a project), it seems harmful to me to have suboptimal advice with high visibility. Some people will read the entire page and consult other resources to reach a good solution, but voting on the answer indicates that some do not read further than the top voted answer.

So, should we make further efforts to make sure that visitors follow the best advice, or should we leave it as their responsibility to do enough research before doing what an answer says?

Note: I'm aware of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293959, one of the possible actions listed in that answer is to raise a specific case on Meta.