# Is it okay to change code examples that mention gender when not relevant to the question?

Tags: discussion

On a number of occasions, I've come across questions and which **have nothing to do with gender**, but contain example code assuming binary gender. A question might ask

> What's the pythonic way to designate unreachable code in python as in:

```
gender = readFromDB(...) # either 'm' or 'f'
if gender == 'm':
    greeting = 'Mr.'
elif gender == 'f':
    greeting = 'Ms.'
else:
    # how to indicate this can't happen?
```

when something like this would be equally illustrative, but be uncontroversial:

```
accessLevel = readFromDB(...) # should be ENUM('USER', 'ADMIN')
if accessLevel == 'ADMIN':
    showDebugInfo = True
elif accessLevel == 'USER':
    showDebugInfo = False
else:
    # how to indicate this can't happen?
```

**Why not make this change?**

In the context of the question, **this change has no bearing on the meaning**. It reads from a database, it has an if/elif/else chain based on the result (which is supposed to be an enum), some code runs based on the values, the else branch should never be taken.

Bringing up gender when it's not relevant, and especially claiming in example code that it can only be one of two possible values, is "likely to offend". Identity documents with three or more gender options are widely accepted and available.

Per the code of conduct:

> language likely to offend or alienate people based on race, **gender**, sexual orientation, or religion

Many such examples *literally* `assert` that some people's genders do not exist.

I've seen previous discussions about editing old content, for example the [campaign to rid Stack Overflow of bad cryptography code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293930/problematic-php-cryptography-advice-in-popular-questions).

> The general consensus is that if you can "fix" the answer without destroying it, do so.

If you don't see a problem with the use of gender as an **example** for a question that is **not about gender**, consider the following example in the context of a question such as "how can I ensure the value of a variable is one from a small list":

*(I'm sorry that this is provocative, but it wouldn't illustrate the point otherwise)*

```
if race not in ('white', 'black'):
    raise ValueError(f'invalid value for race: `{race}`')
```

**The "answers" provided here don't really answer this question, and the closest thing to a duplicate cited here is one where the conclusion was that editing to remove a dig at hipsters is fine.**

Cited duplicates:

- Are moderators allowed to tolerate Islamophobic posts?

*A moderator who has been active on this question said would have been appropriate to edit, but the reference has been deleted entirely. This seems inconsistent with the response here.*

- Is editing code in posts to remove gender frowned upon?

*This question is about whether using "dude" as a variable name is a thing that should be fixed.*

- Edit a post that can (possibly) contain offensive/unnecesary text

*The hipster question, people seemed to think it was okay or not care.*

- What makes something offensive?

*Question lack context, answer cites a page that no longer exists.*

Comment: I would not fix someone else's code unless the OP specifically asked for a more gender-fluid solution, and even so, our fixes should not change the intent of the answer. Better, instead, to vote on answers according to your perception of their utility and correctness, and to create your own answer, if you feel it is needed in that particular situation. If you find something egregiously offensive, for example, a post that denigrates someone's gender, then that text should be flagged for moderator attention.

Comment: I can see how it could offend someone, but it's really just an example. "Asserting" is a strong word as well. What if the author simply was not aware of other genders?

Comment: Then that is hardly offensive since it does not directly insult or denigrate anyone. Leave it alone and post your own answer if you feel it is needed.

Comment: @vr. FWIW, the overwhelming majority of cases are just that (or more or less that), for a large array of reasons.

Comment: There are plenty of "f"s who aren't "Ms."s (cough) and plenty of "m"s who aren't "Mr."s, so we'd be "correcting" that for the question asker too?

Comment: ".. a question asking about how to indicate code paths that should be unreachable." - I am confused by what your question is or how it relates to gender identity? The proposed sample code could have been any other binary decision, and the else statement in the code, would have been unreachable. So my stance, is to leave code in a question the way the author wrote it, since political and society policies, have little to do with the sample code or any question about an IFELSEIFELSE conditional statement involving a variable with a binary value.  BLUF: I would reject any unnecessary edit proposal

Comment: Sure genders can be used. Why conflate what is at worst an over-simplification of datasets with what you appear to be calling a terrible coding error? The example, even if wrong, can be used to illustrate a coding point.

Comment: @ryanc - But changing an author's code, to address  isn't political and society policies, serves no purpose since the code being provided typically is just a MRE

Comment: @ryanc - I don't understand why it's relevant to answering a question about a conditional statement, laws like GDPR are political, and the other half of the spectrum is societal.  If a conditional statement is performed on a binary variable, which can only be one of two values, then the else statement in an IF_ELSEIF_ELSE conditional would be a unreachable no operation code block. It confuses me what you are asking exactly.  You suggest the code is bad practice but don't actually express the reason it is, putting explicit else statements, is a practice I routinely use.

Comment: @ryanc - I neither agree or disagree regards to the topic of the existence or the concept of genders.  My thoughts as a programmer are difference then my thoughts as a member of society.

Comment: Again, never change a user's *intent* in their answer, and *that* is what is wrong with changing the answer. Again, if you feel that you have a better answer, then post a better answer.

Comment: I have rolled back one of your [recent edits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/815320/2227743). Changing "invalid" to "unexpected" in the error message, arguing that it's offensive to declare a gender invalid, was a misunderstanding on your part and off-topic: what was "invalid" was the user's choice, not the gender itself. The original error message didn't need to be changed. You have the right to be offended as much as you want by anything but *don't push it in other people's content*. And besides social opinions, just programatically, your edit didn't improve the post at all anyway.

Answer (score 19):

## Don't.

There's nothing "broken" with the question in that it's asking a reasonable technical question; their business logic must accommodate more than two genders, and they're asking for an approach on how to do it.  At *best* this question is probably unclear or too broad since we don't know their requirements.

But there's nothing for *you* to edit or improve in the question.  The OP would need to highlight what their own requirements are.

Comment: @ryanc:  Don't presume their culture.  It could be that this is an alien concept to them. **You can't introduce that sort of thing in an *edit***.

Comment: @ryanc:  But in doing so, you lose the intent of the question and the meaning of the question entirely.  Someone asked this specific question in this specific domain for this specific purpose.  There is nothing to be gained from injecting "neutral" language into this just to avoid the fact that this developer just so happens to be facing a challenge in dealing with more than two genders.

Comment: @ryanc:  Someone *asking* about what to do with more than two genders is hardly problematic.  Someone *declaring* that there are no more than two genders is *very* problematic.  This is a situation that is clearly the former, and ***not*** the latter.  Please don't make this into something bigger than it absolutely *has* to be.

Comment: @ryanc - I don’t believe that the question you cited even exists. Even if it doesn’t I don’t believe it’s been well received, because the nature of the question, is trivial in nature and likely is a duplicate of a hundred dozen different questions

Comment: @ryanc:  Okay, from that question I can *safely* say...you're making a much bigger deal of this than it needs.  Giving the OP the benefit of the doubt, they probably didn't have to deal with more than two genders as a part of this work they were doing.  Fixing it *now* doesn't really make it better.  In fact, it introduces something to the question that...really wasn't needed to be introduced in the first place.  Let this one be.

Comment: @ryanc - There absolutely is no reason to edit that question. Editing variable names and modifying comments, doesn’t improve the clarity or quality of the question, editing it today serves absolutely no purpose

Comment: The question pointed out was an exemplar type question from a long time ago, surely the suggestions that there are only two genders may make StackOverflow less welcoming to those who are neither male or female as the question imply they don't exist.  It doesn't hurt to change this to a more neutral example if we are going to keep this a "reasonable technical question" when the focus is literally on how to handle unreachable code path.

Comment: @metatoaster - It's not Stack Overflow that is suggesting the number of genders that exist, it's an old question from 2009, modifying a couple of comments and a variable name WILL NOT improve the quality of that question. One would literally have to go looking for that question to be offended.

Comment: @SecurityHound It's not about being offended, it would be useful to modify content to be less alienating for a group of people. I don't get the insistence on being hostile to the idea to modify content to be more neutral when it is possible to do so, and when there is no technical reason why the less neutral text be left in place when a less distracting, more neutral text be put into place to avoid the need to have this discussion in the first place.

Comment: I don’t get offended by variable names. I will maintain that an edit to the code in the question would be superficial since it does make the question easier to understand.

Answer (score 18):

Don't change this code.

We should change the code or sample data if it had an obscene remark or something that would generally be considered NSFW. However, an example using two genders is a perfectly valid example of someone's actual code.

Some people disagree with the fact that there are two genders, and there are people who disagree there are more than two. Stack Overflow is not the place to start arguments about who is right. You may disagree with this part of the answer, but the question wasn't asking about how many genders there are. The question has nothing to do with genders. There's no need to start pointless arguments by editing code to fit your worldview. This applies to political statements, religious views and everything else that isn't programming-related.

If you really think that the code example is contentious, and you want to prevent someone from complaining about it in the future, you could try to edit the question and all answers with a neutral example. But we are living in 2023, so chances are that your new example could offend a new group of people. Better to just leave it alone.

Edit code only to fix **programming mistakes**. If the code has security vulnerabilities or really bad quality code, adjust it to improve it. Stack Overflow is all about learning to program correctly; these edits matter.

Answer (score -11):

When a user posts a question like the example given by OP, they are asking a question with fundamental technical flaws. A good analogy is the classic Stack Overflow post where a user asks how to parse [X]HTML with regular expressions. [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

It seems that the guideline should follow Stack Overflow's general guidelines on answers to users who are asking how to use a tool (a boolean or enum) that is fundamentally unsuited to the job they're trying to accomplish (representing a user's gender and/or honorific)?

There are situations where programmers are forced to do this because of business requirements. But nobody is asking about their business requirements on Stack Overflow.

To be clear, I am not making any moral or political argument here. Offense is not a factor.

I am saying that if a user goes live with code like the example provided by OP, which makes an explicit assumption about a mapping between gender and honorific, they are insufficiently modeling the problem domain, and they will eventually encounter a user for which their assumption does not hold. The logic represents a software flaw in modeling the problem they're asking about. The code is incorrect.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what this has to do with whether or not these kinds of edits should occur. People post questions with code that is incorrect all the time, it's *usually* incorrect to edit them because that's precisely why it was posted, it needs to be corrected. via an answer. but your answer never really seems to... indicate any action that should or shouldn't occur?

Comment: Fair point. The basis of my comment is the post above from Dharman. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/423666/53315

-- "Edit code only to fix programming mistakes. If the code has security vulnerabilities or really bad quality code, adjust it to improve it." --

I am claiming that OP's example code is a case of a programming mistake, and really bad code quality, and thus warrants an edit.

Comment: @SeanEdwards - It’s not bad enough to merit an edit, and if you did edit the code, the only thing you should be removing is the unnecessary else statement and absolutely nothing else about the code.  Whether or not gender should be represented by a binary data type is absolutely an opinion. This question absolutely nothing to do about SO or a programming question that exists on SO.