# Wrong answer is marked as a right answer?

Tags: discussion

What can we do when the wrong answer is marked as a right one?

There are many situations on SO when someone asks the question, marks a wrong answer as the right one (unintentionally), the wrong answer becomes popular and everyone is just doing it the wrong way, but then people starting to actually check it and complain in comments.

Is it acceptable to edit someone's wrong answer if there are many comments complaining?

P.S. I don't mean complete edit with replacing - I mean adding a note in the end of **potentially harmful answer**, as it's described here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266102/1809978

Answer (score 6):

No answers are marked as "right". The OP has an option to mark an answer as "helpful" (accepted), that doesn't mean it's right. Generally votes tend to be a better indication of rightness but even they can be wrong occasionally.

If you think an answer is wrong, downvote it and write your own alternative answer. If there already is an alternative answer you think is right, upvote it.

The writer of the answer is the one receiving the votes on their answer, not you so if you change an answer and it gets downvoted because you were wrong, that's not really fair on the original answerer.

Comment: If you look at the example, you can clearly see that answer is misleading regardless of many "+1"

Comment: So write your own answer, explaining what to do and what not to do.

Comment: There is one, not even my answer

Comment: But the accepted one has more +1

Comment: If you think another answer is correct, upvote it.

Comment: @dk14 _"If you look at the example, you can clearly see that answer is misleading"_ That doesn't matter. It's completely on the OP's behalf. downvote and delete vote to get rid of the misleading answer.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong. The right answer has more votes

Comment: Lovely, that'll be the system working as designed then.

Comment: Yeah, regardless that not many people reads the second one

Comment: And wrong one is still **accepted**

Comment: because the author of the question doesn't care anymore

Comment: They found it helpful, they are one, the voters are many.

Comment: But it doesn't really work: It's easier to "+1" than actually check. Did you read the comments?

Comment: I mean that solution doesn't work. It gives unpredictable results all 42 voters were wrong because they assumed the right answer without actually checking if it works. People in comments checked that - but it was too late

Comment: just downvote the incorrect answer and move on

Comment: I don't intend to continue the conversation as my question was a duplicate, and every acceptable action was discussed in original topic