# How to fix kerning issue with 'T' and ':' when using bold formatting

Tags: support, design

Some of the text blocks in SO contain this:

> [image: screenshot]

This looks a bit cryptic since the `:` merges with the `T`
The same happens for `T` followed by `;`, `[`, `!`, `"`, ... and some capital letters.

Can this be fixed by the SO developers or is it a browser issue?

Comment: What browser? Screenshot maybe?

Comment: This only seems to occur in Firefox and only if I write the T followed by e.g. y or : in bold font... The both characters are then somehow merged

Comment: This must be a recent issue, I've never seen this before on Firefox but I can confirm it's like this now.

Comment: Here is the screenshot: http://expirebox.com/download/ebc27e1c6e3b904a21a93f4d0e375d9c.html

Comment: This is even worse than the customary **Edit**. Good thing **EDIT** is [officially discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255644/should-edit-in-edits-be-discouraged/255688).

Comment: This also happens with Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

It has something to do with the font size.

```html
<!doctype html>
<title>font test</title>
<style>
    body
    {
        font-family: Arial;
    }

    .size
    {
        font-size: 13.7px;
    }
</style>
<p>
    <strong>T:</strong>
</p>
<p class="size">
    <strong>T:</strong>
</p>
```

Output:

> [image: screenshot]