# Rejected edit that does not change the intent, but reviewers say it does

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

Here is a suggested edit I made which was rejected: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10779276

I'm asking because I find a high rejection rate for suggested edits (why do these not go to the author as well to override if they agree?  They have more specific knowledge and context than random reviewers)

Here is more background on the edit:

In the answer the author references an external bug tracking system issue which original had a state of "Open" for the issue KT-7033.  Issue KT-7033 is now "Fixed".  This is VERY important information, and in the answer the author states basically that "X is true, until Y is fixed".  He says this because people will not use the correct, best, accurate answer (in cases such as Android) while `X` is true.  Therefore the current status should be updated.

So I did suggested edit using strikethrough for the phrase that is no longer true, small grammar change, and added "(fixed") text after the issue.

That keeps the original intent of the post, no content is lost, no extra noise and brings outside linked information inside the post.

How is that not a good edit?!?

Comment: This did not *"This edit deviates from the original intent of the post"* ... he obviously intended the status of this to be known.  *"This edit does not make the post ..., more accurate"* but it does make it accurate for the current state of the world.

Comment: Well, however, I'd suggest post a comment instead of just edit the post when you want change something which is *big*, like your edit.

Comment: Why do you consider this "big" @KevinGuan?  It brings in the linked status, with minimal edits.  Someone reading the first line of the answer likely would reject it and not read the comments.  Just as the author of the Question says in his comment "I want to avoid the jar" because he is on Android -- which is exactly the wrong message to send.  The best answer rejects itself.  In fact his comment further influences other readers to do the wrong thing.

Comment: *"why do these not go to the author as well to override if they agree?"* - that **is** what happens, if the author returns during the review period they can cast a binding vote. However, we don't wait around hoping that they'll show up...

Comment: Therefore I am confused why we have suggested edits if everything should only be in comments.

Comment: @jonrsharpe this was reviewed within a 30 minute window, the author wouldn't have time to show up especially considering time zones. They should still have a chance to see the edit and override any time later.

Comment: @JaysonMinard insofar as they can see the review history and edit their own answer at any time to include rejected edits they don't think should have been, they already do!

Comment: @jonrsharpe ok, I don't think the average author is aware of that.  Talking to a few people in the community with around 1000 reputation, none knew I had made suggested edits on their posts.  Usability issue, or people don't take time to learn the details of the system.  But about this type of edit, is it really the wrong type?  What is the best source of "here are good suggested edits that won't get you rejected, and in trouble / banned from editing"

Comment: The guidance is here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit. You're right that it's not easy for an author to see the rejected suggested edits on their question, but I think that's partly by design.

Comment: @JaysonMinard: *big* here means *You didn't just want change some simple things such as fixed format, grammar, spelling, etc. But **added** or **removed** something which possible isn't what OP wants to do.*

Comment: The guidance linked above says I can also clarify the meaning of a post ("without changing it" -- how do you do that?), or clarify mistakes, add addendums / updates as the post ages.  So I did an update as the post aged of the state of the referenced issue.  All of that seems within the realms of guidance.  I've done much bigger changes that are accepted.  It is radically not consistent.

Comment: Guidance should therefore be changed @KevinGuan to remove "add addendums / updates as the post ages" because you are saying additions are not welcome.  Nor are "clarify the meaning of a post" if you make any changes to do so.  I'm obviously confused.

Comment: I would suggest leaving a comment in situations like that.

Comment: @TinyGiant comments are good in some cases, depending on the wording of the answer.  If the first line is "iPhones cause your house to burn down" but now after 2 years it is found they do not.  A comment is not sufficient to remove the fear caused by such as strong first statement in the answer.  Everything is context, and I do use comments in some cases, edits in others.  It is lame when answers are abandoned and authors do not consider comments for incorporation.

Comment: I would still have left a comment. You're actually changing the meaning of the post, and it is highly unlikely that your suggested edit will be approved. So sure you can suggest an edit, but you must realize that it is most likely going to be rejected.

Comment: The problem is from my perspective, I didn't change the meaning of the post since the post had a conditional "bad things happen until XYZ is fixed", noting that "XYZ is fixed" still leaves the meaning and removes the danger of people thinking "XYZ is NOT fixed."   Obviously this is more subjective than I thought it would be.  Context matters, and moderators may not have it.

Comment: Your edits aren't reviewed by moderators, they are reviewed by users with more than 2000 reputation points. Once you get 2000 reputation points your edits will no longer be reviewed, and you can start reviewing other's edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see it problem with your edit is that it is significant from one side, but from other not significant enough - basically you just added word *fixed* in a rather confusing way - and as such it does interfere with authors intent.

My first option would be, like others have commented, to leave comment to the author (since he is active member) and let him edit the answer.

If you do want to make edit yourself, or the author does not improve the answer in some reasonable time, IMO preferred way would be to add *Update* addition at the end of the answer explaining that issue is fixed with other relevant information (version...)

In general, you should approach editing answers with more caution, especially with edits like yours where timing is not crucial. You have to be more careful than when you are editing bad question that will get down voted if you don't improve it quickly.

Also people reading answers usually also read comments, so they will get information that issue is fixed from your comment, too.

Comment: Thanks.  So a rule is, let the author make a change via a comment, before suggested edits.  There are other places on the SO site that tell you to make suggested edits (when in review queue for example).  I think I understand this as "don't edit, make comments, wait a long time, remember to come back, make an edit, it will be rejected, stick with the comments"  ... I'm not being sarcastic, but realistic.  Because that is the exact current experience.

Comment: Note:  I added "(fixed)" and strike-through the comment about waiting for the bug to be fixed.  What is a less confusing way that you would recommend?  an update at the end maybe too late in the answer to be read (the first sentence rejects many users).  An update at the top is better, but not sure if would be rejected for being at the top.  Looking for advice.

Comment: I think answer is short enough and people would note update at the end, but you can add it at the top too. At least I would not mind that. Just separate it with line to stick out as addition to original.

Comment: "*Also people reading answers usually also read comments too*" yes I agree unless there is a short-circuit that sends them away in the first sentence of the answer.  Also, we shouldn't make everyone do archaeology to find all related content when authors fail to own their Question or Answer and update it for clarity and correctness.   This is like asking users to read source code via only a stream of "git commits" instead of reading the final source code.  We would never accept that, yet it is how SO becomes.  Many abandoned Q or A that have a messy comment trail.

Comment: One note on "*timing is not crucial*" ... it is in another way.  Kotlin 1.0 is approaching and we are fighting the "alpha" and "beta" period questions in SO that have invalid, outdated and sometimes completely misleading information, to make sure as people Google or SO Search their way into Kotlin they don't find answers that send them off the deep end.  It is VERY HARD to improve this type of aged/bad content on SO, to modernize it for a rather different current state of Kotlin.  So timing is important before a release that floods in new users. :-)

Comment: Balance is hard to find. Maybe with some other reviewers your edit would pass. That is risk you are taking while editing. Point is that you should not get discouraged by this rejection, and maybe be more careful next time, knowing that people might see things differently.

Comment: jaja, I was being cautious this time (my previous edits were bigger, and some might say "*Crazy!*")  ... one more step towards *MORE cautious*

Comment: If you think timing is important, then you might add answer of your own. Of course, that is not perfect solution and you might get down voted. But I honestly think that main issue with your edit was in "where and how" not in information itself. Update on the top or the bottom would most likely pass.

Comment: I did, submitted a new edit, on top.

Comment: But it is on the way towards rejection as well: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10780341

Comment: And it is approved now :)

Comment: You killed the cat by looking in the box :-)   (your vote).   Thanks!!!  I'll minimize my edits in this way, while still trying to keep things current and accurate.

Comment: I think this edit would pass even without my vote. Keep up the good work :)

Comment: thanks again, moral support from a Delphi addict is always good.

Comment: "Update" is noise that should be removed from posts, not added to it.

Comment: @TinyGiant In cases like above Update is not noise. It adds new needed information, but it does not invalidate or trash answer that made sense at some point (or can still make sense for some users)

Comment: @Dalija Please see: [Should “Edit:” in edits be discouraged?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255644/4639281) It is noise and should not be added. If a user wants to see the revision history, they can look at the revision history.

Comment: @TinyGiant Have you actually read [Should “Edit:” in edits be discouraged?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255644/should-edit-in-edits-be-discouraged) ? Yes, such "Edit" are meaningless. But when you have Q - "how to do this", with A - "this is known bug, workaround is this" when bug is fixed, that answer is no longer valid, and new information should be added. But it should be added in a way that shows how answer made sense at some point and why no longer does. Not making that clear is confusing, and adding visible, clearly separated Update or Edit addition makes sense there.

Comment: @TinyGiant You have people using SO, that don't even know how to edit their own questions and add additional information. Do you really think that everyone is going to dig through revision history to find out proper information. Everything relevant should be visible in answer immediately.

Comment: You can say something along the lines of "This issue was fixed in version X, if you're using an older version then it will require the following workaround", which is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @TinyGiant Yes, you can say that. You can also have "Update" in front of it. I really don't see what is the big deal here, in this particular case.