# Does this place value form over function?

Tags: discussion, edits

I'm asking with respect to some edits made to a [one of my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258054/ssis-password-issue) (10k+). They were:

1. Removed synopsis of root cause in title
2. Put an error message and code into a quote block
3. Removed two "superfluous" phrases and two "superfluous" question marks

My main criticism of the edits is that I believe a note on the root cause would be valuable for someone looking at a list of question titles while having an SSIS password issue. SSIS password problems are all over the internet and they all seem to boil down to inappropriate package security configuration or inappropriate timing of validation. The root cause of my instance of "SSIS password problem" is not something I had come across in my research before asking the question - so there are now three types of root causes I'm aware of and one of those has very little coverage on the internet.

In order to make answer-seekers' lives easier, I put a synopsis of the root cause in the title. The user who edited my question basically said "that's how we do things around here". Given the above context:

does Stack Overflow value form over function such that my helpful note in the question title should be removed because that's how you do it here?

---

For completeness:

- edit #2 I have no problem with, I think it improves the question
- edit #3 struck me as minor and pedantic so I mentioned foolish consistency being the hobgoblin of little minds and accidentally started a fight with the other user.

Comment: Side note: for future edits avoid "EDIT" in the posts - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255644/should-edit-in-edits-be-discouraged

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Per your title: No, we don't. But we *do* value form fairly highly, and we value function in ways that are not always obvious. In particular, SO was founded almost entirely in order to minimize noisiness in finding answers: this is of course a matter of form, since in a long forum thread that happens to contain the answer somewhere, the extra forum posts before and after it are "just a matter of presentation". But in practice, a 10-page thread with one or two nuggets also has a problem of *function*, because it's difficult to find things efficiently.

None of the titles your question has had are very good. The original one is only useful in the same sense that a tag is useful: it narrows the scope down to, oh, a given decently small chunk of problems that might still quite reasonably number dozens or even hundreds of fundamentally separate issues. Titles should be as specific as possible, and this is basically the same as putting [ssis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssis)[password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/password) and no title at all. Putting in a disclaimer about having tried the obvious ideas is worse than useless; only a *list* of them is helpful, as otherwise the question requires answerers to assume (probably wrongly) exactly which "obvious" ideas you've tried.

Putting in a quick summary of the answer is not enormously helpful here. It does narrow down the field a bit (anyone without a mixed bitness environment will know to keep looking), but it doesn't describe the full diagnostic results that would reasonably be relevant; it also includes pointless fluff about being solved, which is far better left to the Accept mark and upvoted answers.

A better title would include the error code and a brief description of the multi-computer environment, and ideally allude to the bitness and perhaps differing user accounts involved. It might look like the one I just put in. It's still somewhat unclear to me (and presumably other readers) exactly which of the two computers has what bitness and project settings, so there's still unexplained magic between the problem description and the answer. That doesn't necessarily need to go in the *title*, but it should go  in the *description*.

Comment: The mixed bitness aspect was part of the solution, not part of the question. Your new title brings that useful distinction from the solution to the forefront in a way that apparently fits this site better than my blunt attempt. I appreciate your fix for the original problem, and your explanation in this meta-answer. To me, this is "the" answer.

Comment: @Paul: The distinction is sometimes subtle, but the key is whether it's debugging info that needs to be teased out, guessed, or otherwise determined, or if it's the logical answer based on the information already provided. In this case, you already knew, or easily could have known, the bitness; it just wasn't obvious at first that it was relevant, and when it was, the answer was not far at all.

Answer (score 15):

### The title

The title was (at the time the user edited your question):

> SSIS Password Issue [Solved: it was 32 vs 64 bit issue]

The current guidelines prohibit adding the solution to your title. People facing the same problem will generally not be using the solution as search terms, they will be using the symptoms of the problem.

> You're right, putting "[SOLVED]" in the title is not the right thing to do.
>
> If the OP made the edit then leave a comment explaining the correct behaviour - i.e. post the solution as an answer.
>
> If someone else made the edit then roll back the edit and leave a comment addressed at the editor explaining the right thing to do.
>
> <sub>[Is it OK to add [Solved] to the title of a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question)</sub>

In this case, the editor rolled back your edit as expected.

If you want to help users facing the same problem find your question, your best bet would be to formulate a title that accurately describes *the problem*, not the solution.

Currently the only useful part of your title is "SSIS Password Issue", which is very unlikely to help users facing the same problem find your question.

### The noise

Often we write questions as we would if we were speaking our questions out loud. That is to be expected, but unnecessary sentences and phrases make finding the relevant content more difficult.

Questions should be as short and to the point as possible, while also being complete. We want to know everything that is relevant to the problem, without having to wade through stuff that isn't relevant to the problem.

Editors are encouraged to remove fluff when editing a post:

> Yes, absolutely remove such things.
>
> Anything that is not relevant to the question/post is noise and should be removed.
>
> That includes salutations, signatures, 'thanks' and the kind of content you have highlighted.
>
> <sub>[Should I remove 'fluff' when editing questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions)</sub>

As we can see from the edit, the editor did exactly this. There is no need for "Any input is greatly appreciated!" or "(read: frustrating)" because we know you're going to appreciate our help and we know just how frustrating "interesting" problems can be. Likewise, there is also no need for three question marks, we already know the statement is a question.

### Form or function

We are building a repository of useful solutions to programming problems. In order to make our repository as useful as possible we need place a high value on form. That doesn't mean we only value form, or that we value form higher than function.

You come here for help solving problems, which we will (for the most part) happily provide; but when it comes time for us to make your post jive with the rest of the site, just give us some slack.

We're trying to make something great, and sometimes that requires stepping on a few toes.

Comment: I appreciate that you seem to actually be trying to answer my question here. A couple things: 1. you don't need to assume which question I refer to, there's a link in my meta question. It came out as a superscript "1" for reasons lost on me (feel free to edit and fix (seriously, that's not irony)). 2. The problem in the original question IS vague, which is why *in this case* I maintain that the note IS useful to people experiencing the same vague symptom.

Comment: Alright, 1. I missed that (probably because it was a superscript 1) 2. People facing the issue won't be searching for "32 vs 64 bit", they will be searching for the symptoms of the problem instead of the root cause. All you can do is make sure your question accurately and succinctly describes the problem and hope for the best.

Answer (score 7):

> User removed synopsis of root cause in title

Questions, and question titles, are not supposed to provide the answer. *Answers* provide answers; that's why we call them "answers".

Your title should accurately describe the problem, the symptoms you're having. The solution goes in the answer. "SSIS Password issue" is decidedly nebulous. I would expect a good title to include the fact that you're using two separate machines and what kind of error you're getting. Something like "SSIS Password connection error from second machine."

> My main criticism of the edits is that I believe a note on the root cause would be valuable for someone looking at a list of question titles while having an SSIS password issue.

Or they could actually click on your question and look at the accepted answer.

Comment: You haven't addressed the reason behind the note in the question title. Please address the reasoning instead of just pointing at "rules".

Comment: @Paul: The reasoning behind the rules are that we call questions "questions" and we call answers "answers". It really doesn't need to go much further than that. If we wanted answers in question titles, we wouldn't call them "questions".