# Credit for commentators - best practice and SO community view

Tags: discussion, comments

I have recently had a small debate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49708842/havign-trouble-with-methods-string-char/49708871#49708871), where I advocated for the person answering a question to mention a commentator.

This commentator had posted the backbone algorithm of the answer in a question related comment almost as soon as the question was asked.

Several SO users argued that the algorithm was trivial and considered it as a dictionary reference, but IMHO all it takes is a 5 words long sentence to do the decent thing and acknowledge the fact that some has already thought of your answer earlier.

So my question is : what is the best practice here ? If you comment and help someone out, would you like to be mentioned as the inspiration of an answer?

EDIT-0 : removed the reference to a comment related RFE since it is clearly not a desired feature.

EDIT-1 : Following the marking of this question as a duplicate - I want to emphasize that I am asking about the best practice here - some SO users would acknowledge commentators and some would not. IMHO there is no question here - if a comment is good and solid and you used it in your answer - give credit to the commentator. I simply want to understand what the general perception of SO users is on this issue, and conform with it.

Comment: @rene "request for enhancement", maybe?

Comment: @rene I don't know. There might be [other uses](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=rfe)...

Comment: RFE does indeed stand for Request For Enhancement. Do you have any thoughts on the question itself ?

Comment: I would love to know why the downvotes are pouring here....

Comment: We are used to call RFE a feature request here but that is more for the software. And for the down votes: I don't think we want to see anything happening that makes comments more important, which kind of feels what you suggest in your last sentence.

Comment: @rene : cool, thanks for the input. Wish more users on SO were as decent.

Comment: If the person comments something, they should not expect credit as an answer because answers don't belong in comments in the first place, so if the person posted something that was basically an answer, and someone else posted their comment as an answer, then it was in the wrong place to begin with.

Comment: Although an answer definitely can quote a comment, and that usually should be credited, although it depends on how word-for-word they copy the content. (They might not even have seen the comment, they could just have come up with an answer that went along the same lines as a comment that happened to be there, so there's no way to force someone to quote because they might not be quoting)

Comment: It is a bit more draconian, what the answerer *should* do is flag the comment as "no longer needed".  Since it is just a half-baked thought that is merely noise that distracts once a proper answer is available.  Referencing a non-existing comment in an answer is equally distracting.

Comment: @HansPassant : Fair enough, IMHO if you are going to flag out a good suggestion by a decent SO user, just add "Thanks to [userXXXX] for a previous comment". And the levels of daconianism here on SO are borderline psychotic :D (meaning - If this was applied to a business it would not be profitable due to all the red tape)

Comment: Hmm, it is notable that it is the exact opposite of "red tape".  It is trying to observe all kinds of forms of etiquette across a multi-cultured world and not upset anybody by accident doing so that is complicated.  Just focus on providing useful Q+A and leave the rule book at home or a social site and you can't go wrong.

Comment: Also you have a close/reopen vote relating your own questions.

Comment: @RannLifshitz totally agree with your "Wish more users on SO were as decent." - sometimes people post "feature-request" and than complain that others don't think such suggestion is useful... I'm not sure if you intentionally put "EDIT:" in your post to demonstrate something... I hope you know that it is bad practice - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255644/should-edit-in-edits-be-discouraged.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov : thanks for the support buddy. The 'EDIT' tags are intentional, I thought it was a convention used by SO users.....
There are so many  nuances here that take quite a bit of time to learn and get used to......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's always nice to acknowledge the source, even if the source is just a comment.

But unless we are talking about a case of plagiarism (harder to make regarding comments), actually attributing the ideas of your post to one comment (or even to an external source) is not mandatory.

Linking to comments is tricky though, since comments are supposed to be temporary, second class citizens at best; and can disappear on any moment.

Do not get particularly attached to comments you make. If what you posted in a comment (didn't read the linked thread) was important and  enough, maybe you should have posted it as an answer instead.

And if it wasn't all that, maybe you shouldn't be worrying so much about attribution.

Comment: Thanks buddy. Point taken.