# Why was my question 75732423 deleted?

Tags: support, review-queues, specific-question, deleted-questions, vote-to-reopen

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75732423/14887783), and it was closed.

It was "in review" for ten days and was closed today.

I edited the question and "Submit for review" it 10 days ago, and checked the "This edit resolves the original close reason and the question should be considered for reopening."

The original reason it was closed was:

> Closed. This question is seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more. It does not meet Stack Overflow guidelines. It is not currently accepting answers.

I'm pretty sure the edited question doesn't mention seek libraries. Maybe I might have done something wrong, but I edited and submitted multiple times. I thought the review should be based on the last edit.

This question was automatically deleted yesterday without alerting me:

> This post is hidden. It was automatically deleted yesterday by CommunityBot.

1. Why was this question still deleted after being edited?
2. Will multiple edits affect the result?
3. Has this question entered the reopening queue?
4. I waited 10 days for the result. Is this normal?

Comment: all the reasons for deletion are mentioned in the linked help article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/auto-deleted-questions

Comment: Has it entered the reopening queue: [Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75732423/timeline) but it never completed the review: https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/34032451

Comment: From the timeline, you'll note the reason is noted: *"Scheduled: RemoveAbandonedClosed"* THe question was closed, and considered abandoned, and so deleted as it didn't meet the requirements to *not* be deleted.

Comment: *I waited 10 days for the result, is this normal?* Even if you waited 10 years, what did you expect to happen?

Comment: Related reading: [Should "Edit:" in edits be discouraged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255644/should-edit-in-edits-be-discouraged)

Comment: I'm not a SME but to me it seems your edit did resolve the original close reason. Can't judge if it is good enough to be re-opened. Going forward: you could have prevented deletion if you or anyone else upvoted the answer on that question. Again: I can't judge if that answer warrants an upvote.

Comment: It is a vague requirements dump. Ask a question with a [mre] about how you are stuck coding to a full & precise specification. [ask] [Help]

Comment: @philipxy It's not how to ask a good question that bothers me, it's that the question has never been reviewed.

Comment: @Thom A I don't actually want to know the exact reason for the closure, I already have a guess that my question wasn't reviewed and I want to confirm that guess.

Comment: @rene If I waited 10 years, I'm sure it wouldn't be my problem. I don't actually want to know the exact reason for the closure, I already have a guess that my question wasn't reviewed and I want to confirm that guess.

Comment: @SageJustus my comment was on the deletion , not the closure. The closure reason, however, was also stated at the top of the question when it was closed, so no reason to guess; it was there in plain text.

Comment: @ThomA sorry, my bad, I actually mean is deletion. I can only see that the community bot deleted the question, but I don't know if it's because of the failed review or no review.

Comment: As mentioned it's because it was closed and the bot determined the question was abandoned.

Comment: The answer is simple, and the same reason all my 'recommended closure' flags age away. There are not enough close/reopen vote reviewers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not a Java subject matter expert, so I don't know if the question should be currently closed for other reasons. However, as [rene commented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423832/why-was-my-question-75732423-deleted#comment951539_423832), your edit did resolve the "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more" reason for which it was originally closed, so I've undeleted and reopened it.

> 1. Why was this question still deleted after being edited?
> 2. Will multiple edits affect the result?

Your question was deleted automatically by the Roomba script in its `RemoveAbandonedClosed` task. As you can see from [The Community user deleted my question! What gives?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/auto-deleted-questions), the criteria for that are:

> ###### If the question was closed more than 9 days ago, and ...
>
> - not closed as a duplicate
> - has a score of 0 or less
> - is not locked
> - has no answers with a score > 0
> - has no accepted answer
> - has no pending reopen votes
> - has not been edited in the past 9 days

If any of those conditions had been false, then your question would not have been deleted. So, yes, there were definitely things you could have done which would have prevented deletion. Those actions are:

- vote to reopen your own question, which is [a privilege you gained at 250 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes).
  Voting to reopen the question *probably* would have also made it more likely to be viewed in the Reopen Votes Review Queue, but I don't know the actual algorithm used to select which review tasks are presented to users, so can't say what the actual impact would be. However, you voting to reopen would have made it such that it only needed two reopen votes from other users, rather than needing three reopen votes from other users.
- upvote the answer
- accept the answer
- edit the question within the last 9 days

> 3. Has this question entered the reopening queue?

Yes. Completed review tasks are visible to all users in [the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75732423/timeline). Once the review task was completed by the deletion of the question, that would have been visible to you.

> 4. I waited 10 days for the result, is this normal?

It depends on how you define "normal". Your question received a single review with a "Leave Closed" result. Unfortunately, I can't know what the user was thinking when giving that response. Unfortunately, Stack Overflow does have a chronic shortage of users willing to take the time to perform reviews and other curation tasks. There are a lot of reasons for that, which have been discussed in multiple questions on Meta Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange. It's a large topic, which is too long to go into here in any detail.

Comment: I edited and submitted multiple times, I thought the review should be based on the last edit?

Comment: If I hadn't asked this question, there doesn't seem to be any other way to reopen my closed question?

Comment: @SageJustus Yes, the review should have been based on the most recent edit as of the time the review was shown to reviewer. I've contacted the reviewer and asked why they chose "Leave Closed". They said they'd look into it further and probably respond on this question. Once your SO question was deleted, it would have been quite hard to get it undeleted. As I detailed in this answer, prior to deletion, there were multiple things which you could have done to make it more likely for the question to be reopened and/or to prevent it from being deleted by the system.

Comment: The best option to not get question closed is to upvote an answer, but it's not the perfect solution, maybe there is no answer or I don't really want to upvote it?

Comment: Why is there only one `Leave Closed` without a slightly more detailed reason?

Comment: @SageJustus Depending on what action(s) the user took in addition to selecting "Leave Closed" that's all the information the system shows, even to moderators. Sometimes, we do get a bit more information, but not always. There might be more information moderators can find elsewhere about what actions were taken, but the system doesn't make them obvious. It should. I consider that to be a poor part of the current review system design, and have felt that way since they rolled out the current design.