# How can I improve this question about parameterizing a test fixture?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I just asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77017044/how-to-parametrize-a-test-suite-fixture-in-criterion) on main about how to parameterize a test suite or fixture using the Criterion testing framework. Currently, it has 11 downvotes, one close vote, and one upvote, which seems to indicate that it is low quality. What can I do to increase the question's quality?

Comment: Why do you feel it needs improvement? You only asked it 18 minutes ago. It has no downvotes, or close votes against it to indicate it "needs improvement"; it's just not been viewed much (5 people prior to me had viewed it, and I assume *at least* one of those will be you).

Comment: @ThomA I might be wrong but I think almost everything can be improved, even well received questions do get edited from time to time.

Comment: Right, but like, there's no evidence that it needs to be improved, so this post is effectively acting as an unpaid bounty in driving traffic to it. That's not what meta is for.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question of why you think a question that was asked less than 20 minutes before you posted this question *needs* improvement. There's a different between something *needing* improvement and something that can be imrpoved. This question can be improved by explaining *why* you think it needs improvement, as that's clearly why you're here. Is it purely that you didn't get a response in 15~ minutes and so felt it was "low quality"? If so then you're mistaken; there are no SLAs on [so] and there's no requirement your question is viewed, let alone answered.

Comment: @ThomA It was just downvoted.

Comment: @MehdiCharife probably because you invoked the [meta effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect)

Comment: @RobertLongson How can I reverse this effect?

Comment: You'll want a time machine, @MehdiCharife, and then you'll want to stop yourself from posting this question.

Comment: @ThomA I just posted a [feature request for meta-effect detection and reversal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392713/should-sites-provide-mechanisms-for-detecting-and-then-reversing-the-meta-effect?noredirect=1#comment1313306_392713) on meta if you might be interested.

Comment: I assume you want the upvote on your question also reversed?

Comment: @ThomA Only if the upvote was produced by the meta-effect.

Comment: My first impression is that it's hard to tell what the question actually is, because of how the presented information is organized.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel What about now?

Comment: Please don't rollback useful edits, you don't need an "update" heading, as I stated in the edit comment.

Comment: @ThomA I think the update heading provides more context. I have read your edit reason, but it appears that it fails to take into account the fact that very few users will actually look at the edit history.

Comment: That doesn't change my point.

Comment: @ThomA It doesn't change your point, it negates it.

Comment: It doesn't negate it at all. The point remains because the existence of the revison history is a fact. It is available for *all* posts. I'll try and find the meta post that advises if such headings.

Comment: Meta post advising against such titles: [Should "Edit:" in edits be discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255644/2029983)

Comment: Can the  close voters explain what's not clear about this question?

Comment: The question should be the question, complete all by itself. The evolution of the post should not matter, nor should the fact that it evolved. No one should have to know there were edits and no one should have to visit the edit history except out of personal interest.

Comment: Related: *[What should I keep out of my posts and titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131009/what-should-i-keep-out-of-my-posts-and-titles/131011#131011)* - *"Changelogs. ... You don't need to tell people what you changed. There's a real changelog (revision history) that's visible to everyone upon clicking the edit card/link under a post, which takes you to the post's /revisions sub-page. And people who are following the post will get notifications about edits to the post."*

Comment: @PeterMortensen related to what?

Comment: I can understand why *this* post is being downvoted, but the Stack Overflow post? It doesn't make any sense. Of course, it's the meta effect, but what's actually wrong with the post itself? It seems clear and it's written quite well. I think we're shooting ourselves in the foot here, as this post could be useful to others. So what if it's about small edits? It's irrelevant to the post itself.

Comment: @BlueRobin unfortunately (fortunately?) we can't directly ask those who casted said votes.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

While it may be frustrating to see your question being down-voted (we've all been there), if no reason is given, then the only things you know are:

- downvoter count
- downvoting time interval (roughly)
- what your question is containing

From this position your question might contain some unwanted content (too long code chunks, inappropriate language etc.), here I do not speak about your question specifically, but in general, what unwanted content may be at question, wrong tags, missing content (details, code, text, illustration, whatever) or low quality content (misformulated statements, misleading assumptions, etc.).

If you think your question might need a review, then you can reread it once or twice and see whether you find things to improve. If so, do the improvement. This by itself might clarify what was wrong if you find some serious faults and fixed them.

But, if you did not find faults, or you consider them less serious than being down-vote magnets, then you might write a comment below your question, politely asking what needs to be improved in the question. If you get a meaningful answer, be polite, thank the answer even if you disagree and use it as a guidance for improvement if you find useful content in it.

If you do not get answers nor faults, then do not worry about it. Some people are down-voting for no reason. Others are down-voting with a reason, but do not bother sharing their concerns with you. And finally, those who politely tell you what was wrong with your question are trying to help you even if they were the ones who down-voted your question.

Comment: I will stay in the "no vote" camp as there are some merits to this answer, but especially the statement *"If you do not get answers nor faults, then do not worry about it. Some people are down-voting for no reason"* kind of ruins everything. There is no way to prove that is happening, it is just baseless conjecture. That does not belong in a meta answer. It is actually more likely that you get no replies in comments because people do no want to explain downvotes; it is too common that this results in angry retaliation.

Comment: @Gimby in my thought process one needs to read his question again, trying to find errors and if he did not find anything to fix, then he should ask a question in the comments about it. Now, if you reviewed your question, found no faults and nobody has given you an answer on what the problem is, then you do not have the means to fix your question. This is why I think you should not worry in such situations. If you were unable to find out what the problem was, then you cannot improve your question. So, the last decision is whether to worry about it. In my opinion the answer is no.

Comment: @MehdiCharife Here I received some comments for the downvote and I consider them useful. But I still agree with my answer and hence, I'm not worried about down-votes until someone provides convincing explanation about the reason for his down-voting and maybe action points of what needs to be improved. Otherwise, down-votes are just manifestations of the freedom of opinion. I respect the opinion of all the down-voters, even if I still think this is a good answer.