# Why is a question asking about how to improve a post on main being close voted as not clear?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, meta, unclear

I recently asked [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426266/how-can-i-improve-this-question-about-parameterizing-a-test-fixture) on meta about how to improve [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77017044/how-to-parameterize-a-test-suite-fixture-in-criterion) on main. Currently, the former question has a total score of 18 downvotes and 4 close votes. The close votes mention as a reason that the question lacks clarity. However, I fail to see how this is the case. What can I do to improve my meta question, or make it more clear?

Comment: I mean, 2 of the votes were casted before you updated your question to now ask about the now downvoted so post. Ignoring the meta effect, your question was infact quite unclear, in that there was no reason to believe your post needed to be reviewed at all.

Comment: @KevinB So the close reasons are now no longuer valid. Why were they not retracted?

Comment: Because the world is asynchronous. Retracting a vote would require the person who casted it to care enough to return and retract it.

Comment: And since there is no built in incentive to return and reassess a post, you're counting on folks who are either bored or have a personal revisiting policy for posts they've voted on. In general the old stuff stays and the upvotes for a fixed post will come from new visitors in the future. That can be slow. Since only the close voter can cancel the close vote, you're usually stuck with them, and hopefully no one sees reason to add more close votes.

Answer (score -7):

It's the pile-on effect. Once you get an initial early downvote, it usually doesn't make any difference what you do to improve your question. The damage is done, and others will downvote it regardless of how good it becomes.

Instances of people coming back to remove their downvote, or even upvote, due to your edits are extremely rare.

This is just how SO works I'm afraid.

Comment: I think the pile-on effect certainly exists, though I'm not sure how significant it can be.