What details do I need to add to question about C++ in Arduino?
What details do I need to add to question about C++ in Arduino: What modern C++ libraries/functions does Arduino C++(Arduino IDE 2.3.2) have and does it depend on the performance of the microcontroller?
And after answer I changed my question to make it more understandable.

Regarding downvotes on this question, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426282/. Although personally I don't think you're doing anything wrong by asking.

This is probably a better fot for Discussions; but I am not sure if you'd get an answer there, considering its low traffic.

I think the question is perfectly clear, but it is far too unfocused and shows a lack of research. It's important to understand that Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum; we want a simple, self-contained question with an objective answer and an obvious, practical application. We don't want a vague wondering about a variety of Arduino platforms and what might or might not be possible with each. A suitable question looks more like "why can't I use X with [specific platform details] even though it's listed in standard Y?", or "How can I work around the absence of Z to solve W problem?".
As Security Hound pointed out in the comments, there's an argument to be made about topicality here, too. We aren't interested in trivia about the environment (IDE, compiler, hardware, etc.) you're programming in - we're interested in practical problems arising from that environment.
Reading the question:

Based on the use of Arduino, it does not have, for example, std::vector, but it has decltype, classes, you can write uint8_t.

decltype, uint8_t and classes are language features and syntax. std::vector is part of the standard library. You are asking about two fundamentally different kinds of support (what language version vs. what libraries), and don't appear to understand the difference. You are expected to have basic background information on the question you want to ask first, so that you can a) ask coherently and b) understand whatever answers you might get. But this is also important because your question exists for everyone, not just you: it needs to be something that can be a useful reference for someone else.

The question is that if you use a more productive platform (Arduino Due, ESP32-S3), will more functions be available?


Do you really mean "functions", or do you mean "functionality"? The former is a technical term referring to one specific category of thing; the latter is a catch-all.

What do you really mean by "more functions"? What if some are added and others are taken away, for example?

What do you mean by "more productive"?

Do you actually have the option to use these alternatives?

Are you hoping someone will recommend one such alternative to you? (Questions seeking such a recommendation are off topic.)

Why are you asking this? If it's not to get a recommendation, then what you're seeking is really too vague to be answered. If you want to know exactly what's available with a specific platform, it would be better to read the documentation. At any rate, we won't compare and contrast them for you, and we certainly won't make up your mind for you about what to use.



And a list of what can be used from modern C++ in usual Arduino IDE 2.3.2? I am asking about features of standard C++ library, additional standard libraries(memory, string, iterator…)

Even narrowing it to the standard library (i.e. not language features), we don't do lists, aside from some legacy Q&A that was carefully chosen and discussed to hold back a tide of other questions, and we mostly don't do that any more either.

If anyone has a better reference link for "we don't do lists", please edit it in.

Thank you for your answer, I changed my question

This change is only a slight improvement. The problem is more fundamental than this; you need to ask a different kind of question.

"You are asking about two fundamentally different kinds of support (what language version vs. what libraries), and don't appear to understand the difference." Ironically, it is this answer that fails to understand the difference. The distinction you're attempting to draw does not exist in C++. The language standard requires the implementation of the standard library. A standards-compliant implementation is not allowed to have only one. So, in the world of C++, the standard library is part of the language. There is no "fundamental difference".

Rewrite of comment because I failed to see you already linked to the C++ book recommendation list meta posts. It was really the C book recommendation list where things started to collapse. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355588/the-c-book-list-has-gone-haywire-what-to-do-with-it/379637 . It's just too much to ask of people to respectably maintain lists, IMO.
