# Can I edit the Edit Summary of my post edits?

Tags: support, edit-summary

I have not actively used SO, so I just learned about the timeline/revision history feature.

I had made a number of edits to my [recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76950218/timeline).

It looks like on my first edit, I actually noticed and filled in the *Edit Summary* input field, but after that, nope.  So history shows a bunch of *added NN characters in body* comments.

Is there a way to edit those comments to make them meaningful?  Or should I just leave them be and try to do better in the future?

I tried looking for guidance, but these are tough terms to search for.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to edit the edit summary after editing

Comment: Mods can edit the edit summary, but normal users can't.  See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273359/334566

Comment: Also take note of this: [Should "Edit:" in edits be discouraged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255644/should-edit-in-edits-be-discouraged) . off-topic, but when you have one problem you usually have multiple problems.

Comment: Indeed.  My post in question is full of **Update YYYY-MM-DD** I figured it out!  <followed by paragraphs of explanation>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Only if it's within 5 minutes

And even then you might have to make a minor change beyond that to make it stick. You don't really need to leave edit comments on your own posts. Nobody cares, and if they did, you'd just roll any bad edits back and leave a comment then.

Note: If you see someone else's edit summary is offensive, you can flag for moderator attention for them to change it. But that's something that's best left for the most extreme of cases.

Comment: To be extra explicit– you "edit" the summary by re-editing the post within the 5-minute grace period, where the submitted edit message will come up pre-filled in the summary box, which you can then change and resubmit (as long as you change something in the post itself). It's more like a "resubmission" than an "edit" in the strictest sense, but that's pretty pedantic, and the effect is the same (as long as you submit before the grace period expires!).