# I need assistance understanding the problem with my question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, post-ban

I got a question ban on Stack Overflow.

It is somewhat reasonable: it actually took me a long time to grasp how the community tends to respond to questions, and I had a few "please help me out questions" with an image on etc.

So as we know, Stack Overflow identifies the bad question by counting how many down votes it has. (Correct me if I'm wrong.)

The thing that's bothering me is two of my questions:

> [node js VS rust but node is faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76362036/node-js-vs-rust-but-node-is-faster)

This one got 5 down votes despite being clearly asked, a valid question, no duplicates, code formatted properly, had a full conversation in comment section, and got the answer. **Am I doing something wrong?**

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74187377/%d8%a2%d9%85%d9%88%d8%b2%d8%b4-%d8%af%d8%a7%d9%86%d9%84%d9%88%d8%af-%d8%a7%d8%b2-%da%a9%d8%a7%d9%88%db%8c%d9%85%d9%88-downloading-video-from-kavimo-based-systems

There is also this question:

Its link goes to a website where they encrypt their video streams and m3u8 files so that it's harder to download.

Keep in mind that the title didn't have any Persian letters before getting the dislikes. I then added them to attract the right audience to the question.

Comment: The download video question doesn't read like a programming problem. If it is, then you should clarify that and include the code that you are currently using. In addition, the arabic text makes it look very much like a spam post (not that it necessarily is one, but it looks like one). SO is English only; don't include any other languages.

Comment: Your second question tags a JavaScript library (and the [tag:web] tag, which explicitly says **do not use** in the tag description), but your self-answer is written in Python. What is the context of the programming problem you're trying to solve there?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery vis2 is the name of the product that's a browser video player written in JavaScript to handle the encrypted data that comes from server and show it as a video which also has the same name as vis.js library by coincidence you can watch a sample video from https://biomaze.ir/ if you are interested. I wanted to reverse engineer it so the final solution could be written in any language. I asked the question before realizing that the company "Kavimo" had wrote the whole thing themselves at the time I was looking for a simple ffmpeg command maybe

Comment: @BDL Non English letters where added only after question had an answer for easier access and google searches it already had 4 downvotes at the time

Comment: @X-_-FARZA_D-_-X - How did adding Persian characters make the question more accessible and easier to discover? Question bans are not a result of two poorly received questions but a continuous pattern. Such poorly received questions certainly didn’t help, and the rest of your questions not receiving a single vote, doesn’t help matters.

Comment: "I then added them to attract the right audience to the question" - this makes no sense, and [misunderstands policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676).

Comment: @X-_-FARZA_D-_-X The below answer explains what you've done wrong in detail, more detail than any comment could have.  Even then, you've gotten tips in comments explaining things done wrong.  The attitude that nothing was explained to you is thus, wrong, and is in fact likely to attract more downvotes when the opposite has happened.

Answer (score 13):

### First Q (performance):

Asking good performance question is hard. While your question is generally better than the most in that space as it actually shows code and plausible performance measurements, it definitely could show more effort/understanding of the code. Creating an [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is critical step for most questions, and performance once is not an exception.

In this particular case whole bunch of computation code is essentially skipped as you memoize the function and basically compare performance of accessing an element of a dictionary. It is quite possible that just that code alone actually would make good question (the answer actually answers that part), but at this point there is a lot of unrelated code that distracts from the problem and shows lack of effort on your side.

Note that "EDIT 2: Problem solved details are in comments" is completely inappropriate for the question - answers belong to answers (you could have provided one yourself) and "EDIT:" - [Should "Edit:" in edits be discouraged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255644/should-edit-in-edits-be-discouraged) . While it is unlikely on its own to trigger downvotes it definitely does not make the question better.

To improve this in this particular question you can rewrite most of the code to drop all computations and just keep the dictionary line for each. Note that in most cases such edit would be invalid as those tend to invalidate existing answers, but in this case answer actually focuses just on the dictionary access and thus letting you to drop unrelated part of the code. To make code more real (as some may say resulting MRE is to artificial) you can add sentence along "This is core part coming from memoization of function for a dynamic programming problem around a grid Traveler"). Obviously remove all "EDIT:" remarks and make sure the question reads as an article rather than change log.

### Second Q (download video):

- shows no attempt to solve
- does not look like a programming question (and potentially request for tools)
- missing language tag
- includes spam-like links and non-English text

As result it *should* be downvoted due to lack of demonstrated effort and potentially could be flagged as spam (with automatic downvotes) and/or closed as not focused/search for tools.

To fix - remove non-English content and show how it relates to coding/attempt to solve, if you can remove links (aslo those probably have to stay). Note that self-answer *is not* considered "demonstrates research" and the question must stand on its own (browse [self-answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/self-answer) tag for more info).

Comment: I'll keep those in mind. could you please also review the present question that got 2 down votes please

Comment: @X-_-FARZA_D-_-X - Act don’t just sit idle. Which questions have received 2 downvotes? The ones your asking about which have unresolved issues