# Why don't we get rid of reputation points?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation

This site sells itself as being strictly about questions and answers.  I'm willing to grant that it makes sense to vote answers up or down depending on how good they are.  I think voting *questions* up or down serves no purpose, but that's not what I'm talking about in this question. The reputation of the person asking a question or answering a question is utterly irrelevant.  The only purpose reputation points serve on this site is to create a table of cool kids who get to control everything.

I wouldn't care either way about reputation points if I were allowed to participate without them---and if having MORE didn't allow other users to have superuser powers over me.  For example, I am a GD professor of mathematics, and I have read some answers on this site that were mathematically incorrect.  But because of my low reputation points, I was not even allowed to comment on the fact that the answers were mathematically incorrect.

I think site-wide reputation points should be removed completely.  They are irrelevant.  Questions and answers are to be judged individually on their own merit and it doesn't matter who wrote them.

Comment: I am voting to reopen because I don't think it is off-topic. It is a clear request for a feature change. I will be surprised if the feature change happens, but that does not make asking for it off-topic.

Comment: You have to *earn* your respect here - anyone could say that they're a professor, but realistically, you are just another name on the screen, just like the rest of us.

Comment: I wish SO would get rid of badges and reputation. I get the "incentive" intent, but I think that people who actually care about the community would participate and "give back" without rep & badges. I think that having rep & badges steals attention away from the posts. Let people answer questions because they *want to*, not for bragging rights to show off a big number next to their name or some shiny piece of bling.

Comment: see also: [Contention: should points be completely eliminated on SO?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255366/contention-should-points-be-completely-eliminated-on-so)

Answer (score 24):

> I think site-wide reputation points should be removed completely.

I don't.

> They are irrelevant.

No they're not. They're a crucial moderation filter.

> Questions and answers are to be judged individually on their own merit and it doesn't matter who wrote them.

I agree. And you are *supposed* to vote with that in mind.

But that has nothing to do with whether reputation points should exist.

Answer (score 8):

I believe reputation is an incentive for users to strive to increase their knowledge, and to help others. I say to increase their own knowledge because when helping or trying to provide solutions to others, you might indeed learn something new about that specific language in the process.

This doesn't necessarily mean people only do this because of reputation, but I believe it's a great motor that drives people to do this and I think it should stay. Now, don't get me wrong, there are people who help truly out of the soul of their hearts.. but, I know some and others are infatuated by the reputation good or bad. It's a win win in my humble opinion.

Comment: That, and, as far as I know, it represents how much the community "trusts" you. Since a lot of moderation work is done by community members (close votes, review queues, edits to retag, etc), having a precise measure of that "trust" seems to be necessary.

Comment: Perhaps then I should more specifically oppose the fact that members with higher reputation get to control everything?  It's as if their opinions are more valuable.  Somebody here with 200k reputation might vote to close this question and it will probably happen.  Is she smarter than me? Has she earned more in this world than me?  Why does her opinion weigh so much?  This website is a relatively new thing compared to the world it lives in.  My expertise is not limited to what I've proven here.

Comment: @RudePeopleStepOff You're right. But, there is a catch... In real life, is a major league baseball Pitcher going to be drafted just because he can throw 99MPH? (Well this is a bad analogy lol, but you get my point).  No he's not, he's going to get drafted because of the people he knows, and his performance and personality. (His reputation), same thing applies on this board. The performance on this site how much they are willing to answer people's questions and help others. That is why reputation is such an important role here.

Comment: @RudePeopleStepOff: _"Has she earned more in this world than me?"_ Yes. FSVO "this world". _"Why does her opinion weigh so much?"_ Trust. _"This website is a relatively new thing compared to the world it lives in. My expertise is not limited to what I've proven here."_ No, but conversely you _haven't_ proven that _real_-world experience. What do you want us to do? Just arbitrarily trust everybody?

Comment: The only expertise I am seeing here is a tantrum/rant and realising that you are going to be treated the same as everyone else here and not put on a pedestal due to your alleged real world qualification (I say 'alleged' as there is no way to verify your claim).

Answer (score 4):

I will be pleasantly surprised if you get anywhere with this.

Fortunately, it does not take much reputation to do the really useful stuff, such as writing comments. My strategy was to sit for a couple of days on the "java" tag with the Java Language Specification and the API documentation open in other windows. I was often not the fastest to type an answer, but was the first with a well documented answer.

Is there some tag where there are a lot of questions you could answer easily?