# Feedback requested: New "recommended" homepage, phase 4 - filters

Tags: discussion, question-quality, homepage, se-quality-project

We've implemented the unpolished filters mockup from [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258699/the-stack-overflow-homepage-is-over-emphasizing-bad-questions-and-a-proposed-so) in an equally unpolished manner.

[image: homepage filter screenshot]

Currently, this is only on the "recommended" tab, found here:

> **https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=recommended**

A few notes:

- each option has a tooltip with more information (available on mouse over)
- some requests could take longer than normal, as we haven't tuned for performance yet
- filters are not saved, but deep-linking is available for bookmarking

Try it out and let us know what you think.

Comment: Looks pretty much like my usual incoming queue when filtered using (my preferred) c++ tag. I don't see much variance in the push-up of particular questions. A good feature though, welcome!

Comment: You can't leave out tags like you can in search `[c#] -[asp.net]`?

Comment: Would it be difficult to add a count of questions turned up by the filter?

Comment: @JonEricson yes, it'll be difficult, depending on the filter, as not all filters are applied at the same time. For example, if you filter by tags, score, and user rep, we'll grab the latest `N` questions by tags and score, then filter that `N` by reputation.  We currently have to do this because of performance: anything tag-related needs to come from the tag engine, which has no knowledge of user rep. Same with review.

Comment: The ability to hide questions with answers is awesome, thanks!

Comment: Why is the cap 200 on filtering question by the asker's rep?

Comment: The tooltip on the slider says "Removes *unanswered* questions from users with less than the specified reputation". Shouldn't it remove all questions from users with less than the specified reputation, especially when "Only show questions with no answers" is a choice?

Comment: When only "Prefer questions in my favorite tags" is checked, I only see yellow questions (those tagged with my favorite tags). When I also check "Hide questions with score less than 0", it also displays lots of white questions (containing tags I've definitely not favorited). So some something is off, but in theory, this seems like a nice improvement.

Comment: "Hide questions currently under review" is this cached right? BTW, I like the idea that at least someone had to click before I see the question.

Comment: So will Phase 5 be the implementation of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261343/534109 ?

Comment: Encouraging users to filter out questions from low-rep users seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Filtering low-rep user questions was heavily downvoted in the past, i.e. [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252607/ability-to-ignore-questions-from-low-rep-users). Why did you implement it anyway?

Comment: I think the "Hide questions from users with reputation < [n]" be detrimental to the site.

Comment: @juergend that "heavily downvoted" suggestion has 20+ upvotes hidden behind negative total score. Meaning, making this option available (off by default to reflect majority preference) has a potential to ["maximize the happiness and enjoyment"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/) of a substantial part of answerers

Comment: The low rep filter is not excluding questions that have been upvoted.  I can see doing that from the point of view of using the filter to remove bad questions, but it is not what the tooltip says.  I am very pleased with existence of the "no answers" filter.

Comment: @juergend we're still working on the ["filter by quality" option](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253351/allow-users-to-optionally-filter-out-low-quality-questions) that is linked from your linked question; in the meantime, this rep filter, while a worse proxy for quality, was very easy to implement, so we wanted to see how it would be used.

Comment: @rene I'll look at implementing `not` tags - good idea.

Comment: @JuJoDi that min rep tooltip was meant to tie rep filtering to only unanswered questions (found in the recent/needs answer tabs), not any hot questions that were being shown in the recent/hot tabs.

Comment: "Show questions with no answers" Well... I would hope that people would want to see questions with no answers... why wouldn't they? I can confirm that I don't have this checked and still see questions with no answers. I think you meant "_Only_ show questions with no answers". The same English flaw exist for the other "Show" options too.

Comment: And I do not know if it is really relevant, but I do a great difference between a question with answers and a question with an *accepted* answer. But it could give an over complicated UI ...

Comment: Will that tab replace the other ones?

Comment: @Joiner no, but we might group the "hot", "week", "month" tabs into one with subtabs to free up space for this new tab.

Comment: If you have the advanced filters shown and you click outside of it, it should be hidden back.

Comment: This feature is **awesome**. I wish there was a visible link on the main site already.

Answer (score 16):

Please remove the cap on the asker reputation filter (it can currently be set from 50 to 200). Maybe there won't be too many questions, but I'm dying to know what questions are asked by users having 1,000+, 10,000+ and 100,000+ reputation.

Or maybe limit the cap by the user's own reputation divided by some number. For example, if a user has 1,000 reputation, set the cap to 1,000 / 5 = 200. This will make sure low-rep users still receive attention (if there's any worry about that).

P.S. I know reputation filter isn't a very popular idea, but I'm happy to see it implemented. If it can encourage high-rep users to not leave Stack Overflow due to influx of low-quality questions, it's totally worth it. A tiny bit of elitism can be healthy and preserve valuable members of the community.

Comment: The reputation filter will decrease the view-count of low-rep users' questions. My concern is that that low-quality questions will not be downvoted, closed, deleted, or commented on, but simply ignored. To new users that don't understand our ways, getting a decent response will seem like a crapshoot. When the ante is free, why not keep playing? This is already a problem, but I think the rep filter will exacerbate it. I predict it will increase the influx of low-quality questions and ultimately cause more high-rep users -- especially those who perform essential moderation tasks -- to leave SO.

Comment: The constrained slider is now replaced with a number input with no max.

Comment: @RyneEverett New users tend to ask simple questions. There're enough rep-whores to not worry about getting answers to these questions. New users with complex questions are already often ignored, because very few bother spending their time if the asker is likely to not accept the answer, maybe even notice it. "If you have a complex question, give something to the community first" — there's nothing wrong with this, if users are warned in the tour. At least it **works**, unlike the current state when complex questions from newbies are ignored and high-rep users leave (it fixes **both**).

Comment: @Athari, I was careful not to include "answer" in my list of things that wont happen on low-rep users' questions. You've acknowledged two categories of questions: **(a)** complex/good/interesting and **(b)** simple/newbish/uninteresting. But there is a third category: **(c)** garbage that has no place on the internet. I agree that rep-whores should take care of *(b)* questions and that high-rep users should answer *(a)* questions, but it seems to me that we depend on luck-of-the-draw-question-clicking to handle *(c)* questions. Rep-whores are too selfish to deal with *(c)* questions.

Comment: @RyneEverett When I feel like rep-whoring (I've been doing it heavily to get from 9K to 10K), I deal with both (b) and (c). If I can answer a bad question, I answer it; if I can't, I downvote and vote to close. Maybe it's just me. :) / And I don't believe that forcing everyone to see low-quality questions helps. It discourages from visiting the website. Downvoted questions don't appear on the main page even now, it's nothing new. Dealing with garbage is a separate issue, I'd say.

Comment: @Athari, you may be correct that the rep-filter is a net benefit, but I don't see the issues as separable. SO has a limited capacity to deal with garbage. I don't see how a rep-filter could fail to decrease that capacity, and I see a lot of new user questions ignored already. Maybe it's worth the tradeoff, but I hope the downside is weighed in the balance.

Comment: @RyneEverett At least now, new users will know how to increase visibility of their complex questions and thus increase probabilty of getting an answer. They just need to earn some rep. It isn't perfect, obviously, but it's better than absolutely nothing that we have now (well, besides bounties, prices of which are kinda extreme for low-rep users, I think). / Garbage is a hot topic. Many would argue that this is what you get when you remove close reasons and enforce certain policies...

Comment: @Athari, my problem with questions getting ignored isn't based on some idea of equality for new users, it's that I think most new user questions need to be closed and it takes high-rep user views to make that happen. When it doesn't happen, the overall quality of the site declines. But I do agree that the SO team's systematic destruction of useful close reasons is more harmful than a rep filter would be.

Comment: I don't care any more about crap newbie questions being ignored. I really don't. I just want _my_ experience to improve.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I just want your experience to improve also. But I question whether that will be the long-term result of a rep-filter, which is yet another step (following "Summer of Love" and elimination of useful close reasons) from a paradigm of killing garbage at the front door to one of leaving the front door open and locking one's self in a room. The first strategy worked for a long time, and the second strategy is yet unproven. Allowing people into your house without respecting your rules is a losing game because they'll build up rep until it is is no longer a useful filter.

Comment: We're coming around to thinking that the best solution gives *everyone* what they want. If you let the best helpers *decide* what they see, and who they want to help, they'll be happier. Plus, they won't be frustrated if *others* choose to answer easy questions that bore them.  Put another way, letting power answers filter any old way they choose makes isn't just better for them, it makes the site more welcoming for others, too.

Comment: Exactly, the true purpose of the rep filter is in fact the same purpose served by eliminating good close reasons. If it were elitist, it would be counterproductive of its own ends because it contributes to a situation in which reputation is less meaningful.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder whether a solution that gives _everyone_ what they want is even feasible. Actually, I started to wonder this a few years ago :P

Comment: I think having no cap is a good idea. The reason is that high rep users do not ask questions very often, so filtering by that high rep will not yield many questions. It is likely that filtering with that will be a list already viewed and with nothing new, so it isn't like looking at it will prevent users from having the time for getting to lower rep questions.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ""I don't care any more about crap newbie questions being ignored" This is not how a "community" works, and if we *all* thought like that then we'd be in trouble! Still, as long as you're happy eh ;) *I just want my experience to improve*" Did you want your experience to improve when you were a newbie and had 1 rep? Had you just joined today with 1 rep would you be saying "Yes please block me out I only want others to see higher rep questions"?

Comment: @James: No, probably not, but I _didn't_ just join today with 1 rep. So I don't see your point, unless you're applying an assumption that I should only support features that keep literally _everyone_ happy (which is impossible).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry, you are correct, you didn't just join today with 1 rep, so you're ok then. Nothing to worry about

Comment: @James: You can't please everyone.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "you can't please everyone" No, you can't, but you can isolate and displease a great deal of users with a search function that leaves them out!

Comment: @James: And then you can turn around and smile because those were the users who were troubling you and all of your friends and causing a substantial reduction in the overall value and cohesion of the community, and the fact that they are now "isolated" and "displeased" is of no further consequence to you. (Note that I do not actually support these filters, in the main. Despite all of the above, I don't think they're the _right_ solution. I'm just saying that your assertions that the right solution is not allowed to piss off noobs is not backed up by anything.)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No, because I see the bigger picture beyond my own personal needs and wants. And I don't rule out "noobs" because I am no longer one of them. By "ignoring" them we're not resolving their being there. Flags and downvotes will be reduced, so those who remain to help them and try to keep it all clean have a harder job

Comment: @James: Yes, well done. Congratulations. I look at the bigger picture too. The bigger picture doesn't _automatically_ optimise/prefer/pander to/for new users, the way you seem to be suggesting.

Comment: No, you look at your own picture

Comment: @James: You are incorrect, and bordering on slanderous now. When you have a discussion with someone, try to argue the merits of your case instead of making baseless attacks on what you perceive to be their intentions. It also helps to actually _read_ the opposing argument.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "*bordering on slanderous now....making baseless attacks on what you perceive to be their intentions.....It also helps to actually read the opposing argument*" I did, it was based on when you stated "I don't care any more about crap newbie questions being ignored. I really don't. I just want my experience to improve". So no slander or baseless opinion. And you should look up the definition of "attack". You essentially stated you only care about the things you want, and not new users or their posting crap - someone else can deal with it. I meant nothing offensive

Comment: @James: There is a HUGE difference between "I don't care any more about crap newbie questions being ignored" (and the emotional observation "I just want my experience to improve") and suggesting that I would actually, in real life, in practice, support a feature or change solely on the basis of some material gain to myself. What you're apparently not comprehending is the underlying idea that the best thing for the site and community as a whole _is not automatically_ the same as the best thing for new users. Don't try to hide from that by drawing false conclusions about my intentions!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I can only go by what you said. If you did not mean what you said, then clarify, and/or don't say something you don't mean. And, what am I hiding from?? "*the best thing for the site and community as a whole is not automatically the same as the best thing for new users*" well, of course, we could say a million things like that which would be true. What has this got to do with you stating you don't care about noobs being ignored? Let's just leave it. As I said, I meant no offence, I just think what you seemed to be saying is not good for the site. NW

Comment: @James: I have been clarifying throughout this entire "conversation", but you're not listening.

Answer (score 11):

Why can I search for "difficult" questions, but not for easy questions?

Some users (and that's generally those with higher rep) are asking questions, that are simply beyond my knowledge. While it's nice to have such questions asked, I can't contribute to them in any way.

It would be awesome to allow me to filter out such questions that are presumably unanswerable to me.

There may be different possiblities to allow filtering such questions out:

1. Reputation:
   I have the feeling (but no evidence) that questions asked by high-rep users are statistically harder. It may be interesting to exclude questions where OP has a rep higher than {insert self-chosen value here}
2. Q:A Ratio:
   The more answers a user provides relative to his question-count, the harder his questions tend to be. Again this is just a feeling, but I think it may be a useful metric..
3. Tag Badges:
   It's highly unlikely a gold-badge holder for a tag will ask a really easy question in the tag that he's active in. The same may even apply to silver badges and to low-frequency tag bronze badges.
4. Viewcount:
   At some point a question accumulates views without end. If there's still no answer to that question it's highly unlikely I could provide an answer...

Comment: "People who answer more tend to have pretty hard problems." - or they could just as easily be people who answer a _lot_ (perhaps even answer obvious duplicates of what they've already answered). These could be ones of the easiest questions around, just in a different area than these guys usually rep-whore around.

Comment: @JanDvorak while that definitely is true, I still feel like there's a correlation between q:a ratio and q-difficulty. But maybe that's just me...

Comment: As a higher rep users, I still often ask easy question, as I asked questions about things I don't know about.

Comment: @IanRingrose you have some 20k rep and a rough 1:2 q:a ratio. I am talking about 50k+ rep and 1:10+ q:a ratios ;)

Comment: @Vogel612, I still don't think it is a good way to filter out hard questions.   Maybe something like "more then 30 views and no answers" would work better.

Answer (score 10):

I am getting questions in my ignored tags. I would not expect these to be recommended. In this screenshot the [laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel) and [laravel-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-5) should be ignored
[image]

Answer (score 7):

Any chance of filtering on accepted answers as well? I tend to assume once an answer is accepted, the question is a good approximation of closed.

Comment: You can do this now. Do not select the checkbox which states "show questions with no answers", filter, and then there is a button that you can click in the results pane which reads "needs answer".

Comment: If you are going to allow filtering out questions with accepted answers, it might be a good thing to add a "with a score < N" option to that.  Three reasons: 
1: I've seen some really good answers posted __after__ a really boneheaded answer was already accepted and the OP didn't subsequently update; 
2: Blanket filtering would skip some really great answers and clear explanations that are beneficial to many more readers than to the OP; and 
3: You'd miss all of those "I pretty much knew that, but I'm really glad I read that explanation." answers

Answer (score 6):

I really like what you're trying to do here. I've been floating around SO for a long time, and I've never found a way to come across questions I could actually answer, that won't also be answered by others in a few minutes.

That said:

- for me, I wanted all the options checked.
- the "prefer questions in my favorite tags" option doesn't seem to have a strong enough effect. My number #1 question (and lots of others) were Visual Studio related, and had nothing of interest for me. (And also seeing lots of Ruby, iOS, Haskell etc which again, are of no interest.)

Answer (score 5):

Would be great if you could close the advanced filter settings, when you just want to see the settings an not change anything.

This could be done by clicking outside it or via a button.

Comment: The Escape key currently works to close it, but being able to just click outside would be much simpler.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively to [DavidG's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277104/1529630), I propose renaming advanced filters to

```
Hide questions with answers
Hide questions from users with reputation < ...
Hide questions with score < ...
```

I prefer it because

- Current `Show` is extremely confusing.
- @DavidG's `Only show` is longer.
  And people don't like to read.
- There is already a `Hide` advanced filter.
  And it's more clear if all filters begin with the same words (`Hide`, `Show`, or `Only show`).

Comment: I totally agree that hide is better than `Show`. And it's also better than `Only Show`, because the latter would still be a little confusing. we are trying to filter the questions out, and `Hide` is the best way to describe this action

Comment: Happy for either my version or this one to be chosen. Possibly even leaning slightly towards this....

Answer (score 3):

Could the text on the advanced filters be changed? I think it would be clearer if they were all prefixed with "only". For example:

```
Show questions with no answers
Show questions from users with reputation...
Show questions with score...
```

Would be clearer as:

```
Only show questions with no answers
Only show questions from users with reputation...
Only show questions with score...
```

Comment: This is my main (only?) gripe!

Comment: It's still not clear enough and I've been bit by it in the minutes since. Only show _unanswered_ questions, and does this mean answered questions are not shown at all? (Doesn't seem so)

Comment: Alternatively, "*Hide questions with answers*", "*Hide questions from users with reputation < ...*", "*Hide questions with score < ...*". http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277177/1529630

Answer (score 2):

I would like the ability to filter out answered questions as well, because the Unanswered questions page currently shows all questions that don't have an *accepted* answer.

e.g. I want to be able to see only questions that have zero answers, accepted or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

#### Re: UX

Definitely should not be a z-indexed box. Do an expanded view of these options (ref: YouTube Search filtering), you can skip the jQuery animations mishmash, we'll all understand the rustic approach here.

Filters should not be saved, it's a mess and everyone is usually craving for they own approach to this.

Filter examples (ref: Asana Search, fb Graph Search) are very cool and educate people subtly on power-usage of these filters.

Answer (score 1):

I love it. https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=recommended&subtab=recent&minRep=100&minScore=1 shows me tags I prefer, and questions I really like. I see I should go back the current view to be fair to new users who do post good questions. But this is awesome. Only let the old view be there in some easy to get way. To be fair. Or tell us how we can use these filters to get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if it were possible to suppress questions newer than some configurable limit, to avoid all kinds of race conditions.

- questions that keep mutating while I'm typing an answer or comment
- questions that get locked or deleted while I'm typing
- a bunch of rapid-fire answers appearing, which I have to check before hitting 'post' (to avoid duplicate answers)

With very new questions on popular topics, such problems occur more often than not, even several times in a row. They almost never occur when the dust had time to settle and the question has stewed for half an hour or so.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The OP user rep filter seems buggy; [this should be C++ questions not under review posted by 10k+ rep users](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=recommended&subtab=recent&tags=c%2B%2B&hideReview=on&minRep=10000), but the first page alone contains of some questions posted by <1k rep users. That being said, these false positives are welcomed because the questions are high-scoring and the answers are excellent. So it may simply be that the filter option is mislabelled, because this filter is still doing something right.</strike>

Nope, never mind, it's the fact that "*unanswered*" is not shown in the filter option — only in the tooltip. Very misleading!

Answer (score -2):

Filtering by multiple tags seems to show any questions which have any one of the multiple tags you entered. I expected it to show questions which have all the tags together, for example I enter `java regex`, and see only questions which are tagged `java` **and** `regex`. Maybe this should be modifiable, maybe with a `+` between the tag names ?

When there is nothing to display (eg. enter some random gibberish in the tag-filter box), the space is empty. There should be some sort of '0 questions found' text.

If I type `regex java` in the filter box, it changes to `java regex` when pressing enter. Why ?

Otherwise, great !