# How do I default to the beta "Recommended Questions" tab?

Tags: support, homepage, recommended-tab

I *know* I saw this discussed months ago somewhere...

I love the new tab (as of today when someone pointed me to it). But it's a bit dead for me when it's:

1. hidden
2. it hides when I click the "StackOverflow" homepage icon, and
3. clicking the "StackOverflow" homepage icon doesn't return to it at all.

How do I fix 1, 2, or 3 of these problems?

Comment: [Here's the post introducing the tab](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276840/feedback-requested-new-recommended-homepage-phase-4-filters). While reading it though, Jarrod tells us to try it and let them what we think which leads me to believe it's still in beta and not meant for the general public yet.

Comment: Add a browser bookmark so you can always quickly navigate back with a single click.