# How to filter a question with OP score greater than 15 reputation points

Tags: discussion, support

I am aware of some of the filters like is:Q score:0. I want to go through the question with author reputation score > 15 reputation points as questions raised by less reputations points authors are not good most of the times. How to add user reputation points as criteria in question selection?

Comment: This isn't possible, and I don't think such a feature will ever be added. Filtering posts by author is... icky. If you absolutely must have this, then perhaps you could build it yourself using the [api](https://api.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: "How to filter questions with OP score > than 2226 rep", Who answer questions from beginners (Seems have similar questions before but I forgot where can find it)?

Comment: Unintentional elitism :/ News flash: there are legions of people with more than 15 rep that ask excruciatingly poor questions; in fact even people with more than 2226 reputation ask really poor questions. This filter only makes sense in a world where it wasn't easy to get imaginary reputation points by the bucket loads by answering any and all poor question that you can find.

Comment: I have joined this site 4-5 months back. Initially I have answered all the questions which I know irrespective of scores. Later I have found interesting patterns in the web site. Top reputation authors won't try to answer basic question even if they know. They are just leaving them and other guys are quickly picking up. It does not mean that I always select OP > 15. I will check OP =1 also with a less frequency than OP > 15

Comment: @ravindra *"Top reputation authors won't try to answer basic question even if they know"* - that's because the *"basic question"* have generally been asked and answered multiple times before and should therefore be closed, rather than wasting yet more time on them, and *"Top reputation authors"* get bored writing the same answers over and over again and tend to buy more into SO's overall goals (I speak for myself there, but suspect others feel similarly).

Comment: During this answering process of beginners questions, the questions are getting deleted even if answers have positive score of > 2.  I posted one more question in SE  : Do I have to stay away from answering  low quality posts and most of the guys told YES., When I answer the question with a score of 0 for low quality questions, I am getting down voted some times since even with right answer  & question is getting deleted after some time Or getting down voted with answers also getting down voted. You have to consider all these things and reason for posting this question

Comment: However none of this is a reason to filter out questions by authors with low reputation (who's to say a new user can't ask a worthwhile question?) - as this feature seems at odds with the purpose of SO, I can't see it getting much support. Focus on the quality of the question when deciding whether it's worth your time or that of others, not the reputation of the OP - that's the whole point of votes on the main site, by the way.

Comment: "Top reputation authors won't try to answer basic question even if they know." I do, if the question is asked well and isn't a duplicate.

Comment: It seems this [feature](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276840/189134) was removed. It existed in one of the beta versions of the home page redesign though.

Comment: *am aware of some of the filters like is:Q score:0.* Have you tried just increasing the score in your query like this: `is:question score:5...`? You can limit your query to questions that have at an overall score of at least 5 (or any number you want). The site already has a way of identifying good questions, the user's rep isn't relevant.

Comment: If you want week-old data, you could write a [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) query.

Answer (score 1):

As was said in comments, the site search does not support filtering in reputation. One of [prototypes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276840/feedback-requested-new-recommended-homepage-phase-4-filters) of the new navigation did have such a filter (this was back in the days of "SO quality project"), but the current iteration does not have it.

You can make your own filter, though. Use the [API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs) to scan incoming questions in batches of 100, considering the asker's reputation and tags of interest to you. If a question meets your criteria, add it to your to-read list.

It's up to you how to implement the to-read list. I have used two approaches:

- [Automatically favorite selected questions](https://stackapps.com/questions/6603/keep-track-of-questions-by-high-reputation-users-by-favoriting-them). Favoriting is a write method, so has to be called for each question individually. But the API quota of 10000 / day would still be sufficient (if your selection criteria match over a thousand of posts per day, you would not be reading them anyway).
- Post selected questions to a chatroom created for this purpose. Since the onebox includes the question summary, reading chat transcript is not much different from browsing the list of questions. With this approach, one can run against chat throttles, but those can be handled by keeping track of most recent message, etc.