# Why has my question disappeared from the main page after 3 minutes?

Tags: support, questions, front-page

It's still on Stack Overflow, but it's not on the main page anymore. I can see questions asked over 1 hour ago, but mine is gone. How am I supposed to get help if people won't see it?

The question link is still valid:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41222188/unable-to-load-font-awesome-with-webpack-2

Comment: "Top page"? What page do you mean? (link?)

Comment: People who are interested in the tags that are applied to a question will read it. The homepage refreshes entirely like every minute. Being on the homepage is no guarantee to getting an answer, and not being on the homepage is no guarantee to not getting an answer. That being said, your question does not contain a [mcve] (emphasis on minimal) nor does it show what you have tried. Just _"this doesn't work"_, which is not a kind of question that gets lots of response. Why don't you try a WebPack quickstart first, before trying to convert an entire application?

Comment: I mean the page with all the questions when you enter So website.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you curious about how the question list on the home page is composed, or do you want to know how you can pull attention to your question?

Comment: @CodeCaster - and what makes you think I haven't tried various webpack configuations. I cannot list them all, because there were simply too many of them. And I've spent a lot of time in documentation and various posts already to know how Webpack tests and loaders are supposed to work and it still didn't help me.

Comment: All I'm saying is that your question looks less perfect than it can be. Saying _"I've been trying to solve this on my own for the past 2 days"_ does not tell the reader anything. For all we know you've been F5ing the same page over and over again. Read the [tour] and [ask] if you need some guidance on asking good questions.

Comment: In addition to what CodeCaster said, also note that everyone's home page is different. It is customized for their tag preferences.

Answer (score 14):

The front page shows questions which were recently *active*, that means answers and modifications count as well. Even a five year old question can resurface on the front page, if somebody edits one of its answers.

Being on the front page doesn't guarantee answers, though. There are very few people who browse Stack Overflow's front page looking for questions to answer; they are more likely to concentrate on specific tags.

Comment: The front page is also highly personalised, so two persons don't necessarily see the same questions.

Comment: I understand, but all the questions visible on main SO page have 'answered', 'modified', 'asked' next to them and are appearing in reversed chronological order. Following this logic my question should be somewhere close to the top  with 'asked' and not disappear after 3-4 minutes.

Comment: @Glorfindel: The default tab is "Interesting": _"Questions that may be of interest to you based on your history and tag preference"_

Comment: @Glorfindel yes, I remember having read everyone gets their homepage rendered from the same ~1000 questions or so with recent activity, but the filtering of those questions is heavily personalized. Not only favorite tags but also tag history (questions with which tags you opened) and other heuristics (poor-quality questions aren't shown to everyone).

Comment: @Glorfindel I might be confusing some things yeah... Wasn't the ["recommended" homepage](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276840/feedback-requested-new-recommended-homepage-phase-4-filters) integrated into the "interesting" tab?

Comment: @CodeCaster & Stijn OK, thanks. It's just that I regularly see questions which don't make any sense at all, given my SO history.